# How to use Union on list of lists without sorting them first?

Tags: list-manipulation

If I do

```
ClearAll[a, d]
lsts = {{a, d}, {a, d}};
Union[lsts]
```

I get the expected answer

```
{{a, d}}
```

but if I do

```
lsts = {{a, d}, {d, a}};
Union[lsts]
```

I get

```
{{a, d}, {d, a}}
```

Since I am using `Union`, I thought the order of the lists would not matter. Hence to get around this, now I always add `Sort` first, like this

```
lsts = {{a, d}, {d, a}};
Union[Sort /@ lsts]
```

and now I get expected answer

```
{{a, d}}
```

**Question**: Is this the right way to approach this? or do you recommend a better way?

Comment: why is {{a,d}} the expected answer? I interpret *lsts* as a list of sets, which I want to join. So shouldn't it be {a,d}?

Comment: sorry but what is the difference between this and `Union @@ lsts`?

Comment: I see it. Agree with Leonid.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Sorting of sub-lists seems unavoidable since this is what brings them to a "canonical form" in this problem. If you don't care about the order of your resulting sub-lists, you could used `DeleteDuplicates` in place of `Union` though - this should be faster for large lists.

Comment: Good call, I didn't think of that. And in fact `DeleteDuplicates` allows a custom equality test, so you could only sort the list in the test if you wanted your results in unsorted form.

Comment: @David Be careful with these equality tests, they often lead to slowdowns which are not immediately obvious. For `Union` such custom-function-induced slowdowns will be much more severe though, see e.g. this discussion: http://www.mathprogramming-intro.org/book/node290.html

Comment: True, I should have mentioned that a custom equality test could make the command significantly slower.

Comment: Hmmm ... the example on mathprogramming-intro.org isn't even an equivalence relation. I'd expect all sorts of strange things to happen in such a case, and especially I'd not expect timings to be in any way representative for the timing you get with functions having the correct semantics.

Comment: @celtschk My bad - the first example doesn't hold water indeed. You are actually the first person to point it out - thanks. The other examples down that pages are ok though, I believe, and still illustrate my main point. I also discussed this problem here: http://forums.wolfram.com/mathgroup/archive/2009/Jul/msg00057.html, and in that thread there are other answers with good points.

Comment: Actually, the best example in that post is the one by J. Siehler where he uses `Equal`: Here as far as I can tell the *exact same* operation is done as without `SameTest`, using directly the built-in function, therefore the difference cannot be in any inefficiency of the test itself. But the run time is a factor of 200 larger. OK, thinking again, without the test it might infer equality by the ordering relation (i.e. consider elements equivalent if neither is smaller than the other), just like the C++ STL routines do.

Comment: @celtschk Whenever *any* user-defined function is supplied (even when it happens to be a built-in), `Union` switches to quadratic-time algorithm based on pairwise comparisons. This is because `Union` accepts *sameness* function, not a *comparison* function (the existence of the latter is a stronger requirement). Whenever it is not specified, it so happens that `SameQ` (default) has an accompanying comparison function based on canonical sort, so it uses `n*log n` sorting then. I actually explained this in considerable detail in my post in that thread.

Comment: Ah, thanks, I didn't yet have the time to read that post in detail.

Answer (score 12):

You can provide a custom `SameTest` to `Union` where you can take advantage of your knowledge what should qualify as equal, for example:

```
In[1] := Union[{{a,d},{d,a}}, SameTest -> (Complement[##] === {}&)]
Out[1] = {{a, d}}
```

Answer (score 11):

It might be that you're slightly misunderstanding what `Union` does. It finds the union of the elements of the list that is passed to it, but it doesn't dig into lists within that list. So when you write `Union[{{a,d},{a,d}}]`, the function sees a list with two elements, `{a,d}` (that's element 1) and `{a,d}` (that's element 2). They are the same, so it removes the duplicate and returns just `{a,d}`. But when you write `Union[{{a,d},{d,a}}]`, it sees a list with two *different* elements: `{a,d}` (that's element 1) and `{d,a}` (that's element 2). The fact that those two lists contain the same items is irrelevant; they're not equal, according to an ordered element-by-element comparison, so `Union` has no duplicates to remove.

Now, it seems like what you're trying to do is get all lists which are distinct in terms of their content, irrespective of order - in other words, you're treating the lists as mathematical sets. I think `Union[Sort/@lsts]` should be a fine way to go, because that's the standard method of comparing sets for equality when you don't have an actual unordered set type. (If Mathematica does, I don't know about it.)

Comment: If he wants to treat the lists as mathematical sets (i.e. also consider duplicates as irrelevant), then using `Union` also for sorting would be a better idea (because it removes duplicates). That is, for the list `lsts={{a, b}, {a, b, b}}`, `Union[Sort/@lsts]` will give `lsts` back, while `Union[Union/@lsts]` will give just `{{a,b}}`.

Answer (score 7):

You could do the following:

```
lists = {{c, b, a}, {c, a, b}};
Union[lists, SameTest -> (Sort[#1] == Sort[#2] &)]
```

Note that the result is `{c,a,b}`, which is unsorted.  The underlying algorithm can no longer take advantage of a linear comparison of the terms, however.  As a result the time complexity is quadratic and will slow down your code considerably for very long lists.  Thus, I'd advise against this approach.  Ordering the lists first, as you've done, is preferable.

Answer (score 4):

Your problem is reminiscent of the thing one has to do when dealing with noncommutative monomials.

To add to previous answers:

Depending on the typical content of your lists (especially if you have a lot of strictly identical elements), it might be beneficial to apply Union twice, in this way

`Union[ Sort/@(Union[ lst ]) ]`

or

`Union[ Union[ lst], SameTest -> (Equal[Sort[#1],Sort[#2]] &) ]`

if you want to retain some of the diversity of the original instead
of having everything mapped to a canonically sorted form.

The problem is more complex when you consider more deeply structured lists
of course. You might end up with a very costly comparator function.

An object oriented approach would be to define for each object symbol a comparator
function that would be called automatically as SameTest when a modified Union is
called with arguments of a given head.

Comment: In testing (which I admit was not comprehensive, but it did cover very small through very large lists), `Union[Sort /@ lst]` was consistently the fastest approach.  I tried various combinations of `DeleteDuplicates`, `Tally`, Orderless functions, sequences of tests (e.g., test on `Max` and then sort), and even `Hash`.

Answer (score 3):

To get rid of items that are duplicates under Sort you may use this:

```
GatherBy[lsts, Sort][[All, 1]]
```

Afterward you may sort or manipulate that list as you see fit.
Be warned that there is [apparently a bug in *Mathematica* 7](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/536/121) with this specific code.

New in *Mathematica* 10:

```
DeleteDuplicatesBy[lsts, Sort]
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure you are doing it right. `Union` expects a set per argument. As you only give it one argument, you are basically doing the union over one set `A`, which is incidentally `A`. What you want to do is `Union @@ lsts` which is `Apply[Union,lsts]`