# Unexpected behavior from GatherBy in version 7

Tags: list-manipulation, bugs, packed-arrays

**Bug introduced in 7.0 or earlier and fixed in 8.0.4 or earlier**

---

I have come across what appears to be a bug in `GatherBy`.  It appears similar to the problem of using `Table[Random[], {1000}]` in older versions in that the behavior changes depending on the size of the data.

- Has this problem been fixed in version 8?
- **Is there a system option that effects this, or another global work-around for version 7?**

Examples:

```
SeedRandom[1];
set = RandomInteger[4, {500, 3}];

DeleteDuplicates[Sort /@ set] ~Partition~ 5 // Column
```

> ```
> {{2,4,4},{0,0,1},{0,0,2},{0,2,3},{0,3,4}}
> {{1,3,4},{1,2,4},{1,4,4},{0,3,3},{1,1,3}}
> {{1,2,3},{0,1,4},{0,2,4},{2,2,3},{1,1,2}}
> {{1,3,3},{2,3,4},{2,2,2},{0,1,3},{0,2,2}}
> {{3,3,4},{2,2,4},{3,4,4},{0,1,2},{2,3,3}}
> {{0,0,3},{0,0,4},{3,3,3},{0,4,4},{1,2,2}}
> ```

But this does not agree:

```
GatherBy[set, Sort][[All, 1]]
```

> ```
> {{4, 2, 4}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 3, 2}, {4, 1, 3}, {3, 1, 1}}
> ```

If I change the gather function to something that apparently does not compile:

```
GatherBy[set, ("x"; Sort@#) &][[All, 1]] ~Partition~ 5 // Column
```

> ```
> {{4,2,4},{0,1,0},{0,2,0},{0,3,2},{0,3,4}}
> {{4,1,3},{4,2,1},{1,4,4},{0,3,3},{3,1,1}}
> {{3,2,1},{1,4,0},{0,2,4},{2,3,2},{1,2,1}}
> {{3,3,1},{2,4,3},{2,2,2},{0,3,1},{2,0,2}}
> {{4,3,3},{4,2,2},{3,4,4},{0,1,2},{2,3,3}}
> {{0,3,0},{0,4,0},{3,3,3},{4,0,4},{2,1,2}}
> ```

This problem does not appear to affect smaller sets:

```
SeedRandom[1];
set = RandomInteger[4, {60, 3}];

GatherBy[set, Sort][[All, 1]]~Partition~5 // Column
```

> ```
> {{4,2,4},{0,1,0},{0,2,0},{0,3,2},{0,3,4}}
> {{4,1,3},{4,2,1},{1,4,4},{0,3,3},{3,1,1}}
> {{3,2,1},{1,4,0},{0,2,4},{2,3,2},{1,2,1}}
> {{3,3,1},{2,4,3},{2,2,2},{0,3,1},{2,0,2}}
> {{4,3,3},{4,2,2},{3,4,4},{0,1,2},{2,3,3}}
> ```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem appears to be with packed arrays, and it affects both `Gather` and `GatherBy`.

```
SeedRandom[1]
dat = RandomInteger[2, {100, 2}];
sorted = Sort /@ dat;

Developer`PackedArrayQ[sorted]
```

> ```
> True
> ```

```
First /@ Gather[sorted]
DeleteDuplicates[sorted]
```

> ```
> {{0, 1}, {1, 1}, {1, 1}}
>
> {{0, 1}, {1, 1}, {0, 0}, {0, 2}, {1, 2}, {2, 2}}
> ```

```
unpacked = Developer`FromPackedArray@sorted;

First /@ Gather[unpacked]
DeleteDuplicates[unpacked]
```

> ```
> {{0, 1}, {1, 1}, {0, 0}, {0, 2}, {1, 2}, {2, 2}}
>
> {{0, 1}, {1, 1}, {0, 0}, {0, 2}, {1, 2}, {2, 2}}
> ```

This further affects `GatherBy` on lists of length >= `SystemOptions["CompileOptions" -> "MapCompileLength"]` because it turns unpacked arrays into packed arrays:

```
First /@ GatherBy[unpacked, Sort]
```

> ```
> {{0, 1}, {1, 1}, {1, 1}}
> ```

```
First /@ GatherBy[Most@unpacked, Sort]
```

> ```
> {{0, 1}, {1, 1}, {0, 0}, {0, 2}, {1, 2}, {2, 2}}
> ```

Answer (score 7):

We can compare the results of the two forms of `GatherBy` for varying data set sizes:

```
RandomSeed[1];
ListPlot @ Table[
  RandomInteger[4,{n,3}] /.
  set_ :> { n
         , Boole @ SameQ[
             GatherBy[set, Sort]
           , GatherBy[set, ("x";Sort@#)&]
           ]
       }
, {n, 1, 300}
]
```

The x-axis shows the set size and the y-axis shows `1` where the `GatherBy` results match and `0` where they do not.  The chart shows the set size on the x-axis and The results for Mathematica 7 show a problem when there are 100 or more elements:

[image: Mathematica 7 chart]

Mathematica 8 does not show this problem:

[image: Mathematica 8 chart]

Following @ruebenko's suggestion, let's take a look for a compiler option with the magic number 100:

```
Cases["CompileOptions" /. SystemOptions[], HoldPattern[_ -> 100]]
```

> {FoldCompileLength->100, MapCompileLength->100, NestCompileLength->100}

Some experimentation demonstrates that `MapCompileLength` is the culprit:

```
SetSystemOptions["CompileOptions" -> "FoldCompileLength" -> 100];
SetSystemOptions["CompileOptions" -> "MapCompileLength" -> 50];
SetSystemOptions["CompileOptions" -> "NestCompileLength" -> 100];
```

Recreating the chart after reducing `MapCompileLength` to 50 produces:

[image: Mathematica 7 chart revisited]

It appears we have a compiler bug involving the compilation of an internal use of `Map` -- a bug that seems to be fixed in Mathematica 8.

Increasing `MapCompileLength` to `Infinity` appears to correct the problem.

Comment: +1 for the plots, but out of curiosity did you see my own answer to this question before posting?

Comment: @Spartacus I did, and upvoted it.  I thought my answer would be useful as a "consolidation answer", showing the experiments directly and suggesting a workaround.  I'm happy to delete my answer if you would prefer just to add the workaround to your answer.

Comment: No, it's fine, but it was not clear to me that you were drawing on previous answers.  I believe the problem is with packed arrays rather than Map specifically, as evidenced by `Gather`.  An acceptable work-around that does not require a global change to MapCompileLength is to change any function given to `GatherBy` into something that won't compile, like `("x"; Sort@#) &`.

Answer (score 6):

In V 8.0.4 Both `GatherBy[set, Sort][[All, 1]]` and `GatherBy[set, ("x"; Sort@#) &][[All, 1]]` give the same result. As for options, here is a wild guess (no V7 here): try tweaking the

```
"CompileOptions" /. SystemOptions[]
```

XYCompileLength ones and see what happens.

Answer (score 5):

**warning: not an answer**, just showing you what I get on 8.04, as too long to fit in a comment. Will delete later.

```
RandomSeed[1];
set = RandomInteger[4, {500, 3}];

DeleteDuplicates[Sort /@ set]~Partition~5 // Column
```

gives

```
{{0,0,2},{3,4,4},{0,1,1},{0,0,1},{0,4,4}}
{{0,2,3},{1,2,2},{0,3,3},{0,0,3},{2,2,2}}
{{2,2,4},{0,2,4},{1,2,4},{1,1,3},{2,3,4}}
{{1,1,4},{0,1,2},{1,2,3},{0,1,4},{0,3,4}}
{{0,0,4},{0,2,2},{2,2,3},{0,1,3},{1,1,2}}
{{3,3,4},{0,0,0},{2,3,3},{1,3,3},{1,3,4}}
```

and

```
  GatherBy[set, Sort][[All, 1]]
```

gives

```
{{0,0,2},{4,3,4},{1,1,0},{0,0,1},{0,4,4},{0,2,3},
{2,2,1},{0,3,3},{0,0,3},{2,2,2},{2,2,4},{0,4,2},{4,2,1},
{1,3,1},{3,2,4},{1,1,4},{0,2,1},{2,1,3},{0,1,4},{4,0,3},
{0,4,0},{0,2,2},{2,3,2},{1,3,0},{1,2,1},{4,3,3},{0,0,0},
{3,3,2},{1,3,3},{4,3,1},{1,1,1},{4,4,2},{4,1,4},{3,3,3}}
```

**edit(1)**
removed extra un-needed output

Comment: This indicates that it has been fixed.  I prefer that you do not delete your answer, but IMO all you need to include in it is the output for `GatherBy[set, Sort][[All, 1]]` as the rest is predictable.