# A few tuples at a time?

Tags: matrix, memory, permutation

I want to generate $n$ by $n$ binary arrays, and then reduce the output from those arrays by performing a number of permutations and eliminating duplicates. The problem is that the number of arrays increases as $2^{n^2}$, so storing every tuple in memory and comparing each permutation is impractical for $n>4$.

A working solution when $n<4$ is given here: [Reduce the output from tuples by including symmetry?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/20970/reduce-the-output-from-tuples-by-including-symmetry).

**My questions is: how can I generate $n$ by $n$ binary arrays and eliminate duplicates (as defined by certain permutations) in a memory efficient manner?**

For instance, is it possible to generate a few tuples at a time, run the permutations, check for duplicates, and then continue generating the remaining tuples?

P.S. I asked a different version of this question here: [Constructing and Reducing Tuples in a Memory Efficient Manner](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/81378/constructing-and-reducing-tuples-in-a-memory-efficient-manner), and have been unable to implement the solution given here: [Memory efficient generation and selection of tuples](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/28214/memory-efficient-generation-and-selection-of-tuples).

Answer (score 4):

I think you can do something with these identities:

```
Table[Partition[IntegerDigits[i, 2, 4], 2, 2], {i, 0, 2^4 - 1}] === Tuples[{0, 1}, {2, 2}]

Table[Partition[IntegerDigits[i, 2, 9], 3, 3], {i, 0, 2^9 - 1}] === Tuples[{0, 1}, {3, 3}]
```

So in general, you can say that this is `True`:

```
Table[Partition[IntegerDigits[i, 2, (n*n)], n, n], {i, 0, 2^(n*n) - 1}] === Tuples[{0, 1}, {n, n}]
```

(I checked this up to `5`).

But this then gives you a way to just get any individual one:

```
f[n_, i_] := Partition[IntegerDigits[i, 2, (n*n)], n, n]
```

E.g.

```
f[10, 4938742893] //MatrixForm
```

Gives:

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: `f[start_Integer, howMany_Integer, n_Integer] := 
  Partition[#, n] & /@ 
    Table[IntegerDigits[i, 2, n^2], {i, start, start + howMany - 1}] /;
    start >= 0 && howMany >= 1 && n > 0 && 
    0 < start + howMany - 1 <= 2^n^2 - 1;

MatrixForm /@ f[0, 13, 2]`