# GroupBy twice gives different results

Tags: bugs, numerics, numerical-value, gathering, caching

**Bug introduced in 7.0 or earlier and persisting through 11.1**

---

It took me quite a lot of time to finally trace down to this strange output. I really don't know why.

First, I create a list

```
rot1 = RotationTransform[{{1, 0, 1}, {0, 0, -1}}, {0, 0, 0}];
tmp = rot1@Tuples[Range[0, 10, 1], 3];
```

Then run

```
grouptmp1 = GroupBy[tmp, N[Last[#], 8] &];
grouptmp2 = GroupBy[tmp, N[Last[#], 8] &];
grouptmp1 === grouptmp2
```

The first time you run the above code, it will give "False", the second time and after, it will give true. So strange, what is wrong here?

BTW, I use `N[Last[#], 8] &` to add some tolerance to the GroupBy operation. If there is better method, welcome to leave a comment or write an answer

**Updata***

New discovery!! GatherBy also suffers, Try

```
gathertmp1 = GatherBy[tmp, N[Last[#], 8] &];
gathertmp2 = GatherBy[tmp, N[Last[#], 8] &];
gathertmp1 === gathertmp2
```

Maybe all `By` suffers

**Update2**

Temporary workaround I figured out at this moment:

```
    test1 = KeySort@KeyMap[(#[[1]]*N[FromDigits[#[[2]]]]) &, 
  GroupBy[tmp, {Sign[Last@#], RealDigits[N@Last@#, 10, 8]} &]]
    test2 = KeySort@KeyMap[(#[[1]]*N[FromDigits[#[[2]]]]) &, 
  GroupBy[tmp, {Sign[Last@#], RealDigits[N@Last@#, 10, 8]} &]]
    test1 === test2
```

This gives true no matter how many times of evaluating

**Update3**

Simon Woods provide a simple example to reproduce the bug

```
ClearSystemCache[]; a = 3/Sqrt[2] + 2 Sqrt[2]; Table[ GroupBy[{a, a}, N[#, 3] &], {2}]
```

I tested it in mma version 7, since ver 7 doesn't have `GroupBy`, I use `GatherBy` instead, this is the result

```
{{{3/Sqrt[2] + 2 Sqrt[2]}, {3/Sqrt[2] + 2 Sqrt[2]}}, {{3/Sqrt[2] + 
    2 Sqrt[2], 3/Sqrt[2] + 2 Sqrt[2]}}}
```

So this bug lurking since version 7 !

Comment: Same with we (V 10.0) - very strange

Comment: Same if you use `Range[3, 6]` - makes it a lot easier to analyse. Investigating.

Comment: Using `GatherBy` in version 9 (what I have access to at the moment) I notice that the problematic result is the first one, not the second one (the first has repeats that are numerically the same to 8 digits). That is to say, the operation appears to improve with use of cached numeric values. Needs further investigation though.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau I also thought so, but check my answer. After disbling the cache you get the *second* (correct) result twice.

Comment: I can't reproduce the bug on my computer. I'm using mma 10.1 on linux.

Comment: @alephalpha Are you sure? I can reproduce it on 10.3 linux. Wait someone else to confirm this.

Comment: I can reproduce the bug with versions 8.0.4, 9.0.1, 10.2 and 10.3 on Windows 7 x64.

Comment: @ybeltukov I see what you mea.. Thanks for the note and very simple example. This seriously warrants further investigation.

Comment: Filing a bug report on this.

Comment: A possibly related bug that affected v7 but not v8: [(536)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/536/121)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard It is hard to see your comment these days : )

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Yes it is possible I guess, but I don't think they are related.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau This still happens in 12.0. Is there any news on this one?  Perhaps it's particularly difficult to fix due to some reason that is not obvious to those of us who don't know how the implementation works?

Comment: @Szabolcs No news. I filed a detailed report indicating where the problem is. As best i can tell it has progressed further, at least in terms of any update to the report.

Answer (score 21):

Quit the kernel before each test. This is on MMA 10.3 on Mac OS X.

## Simplify the problem

We can simplify so that `tmp` is much much smaller and easier to analyse:

```
rot1 = RotationTransform[{{1, 0, 1}, {0, 0, -1}}, {0, 0, 0}];
tmp = rot1@Tuples[Range[3, 6], 3];

grouptmp1 = GroupBy[tmp, N[Last[#], 8] &];
grouptmp2 = GroupBy[tmp, N[Last[#], 8] &];
grouptmp1 === grouptmp2
```

This still returns `False`.

## Where is the problem?

The `Keys` of each association are the same:

```
Keys[grouptmp1] === Keys[grouptmp2] (* outputs True *)
```

Subsequent evaluations of `grouptmp1 === grouptmp2` remain `False`.

The only `Key` where the values in `grouptmp1` are different is:

```
Select[Keys[grouptmp1], grouptmp2[#] =!= grouptmp1[#] &]
```

Output is `{-6.3639610}`.

How can this possibly be? How can we group a list in two "different" ways and have the output differ in only one place?

## What is the problem?

What is different about `grouptmp1` and `grouptmp2` in this position? If we `Sort` we still get different lists, so it's not an ordering problem:

```
Sort@grouptmp1[-6.36396103067892753155009157319037478428`8.] === Sort@grouptmp2[-6.36396103067892753155009157319037478428`8.]
```

returns `False`.

It turns out that `grouptmp2` has the extra element `{-(3/Sqrt[2]) + 3 Sqrt[2], 3, -(3/Sqrt[2]) - 3 Sqrt[2]}` relative to `grouptmp1` in this position. (Use `Complement[grouptmp1[key], grouptmp2[key]]`, and the same with the arguments reversed, to work this out.)

```
Flatten[Values[grouptmp1], 1] // Length
```

This returns 63. That is, `grouptmp1` has mysteriously lost the element `{-(3/Sqrt[2]) + 3 Sqrt[2], 3, -(3/Sqrt[2]) - 3 Sqrt[2]}` from `tmp`.

This very definitely looks like a bug. `GroupBy` has lost an element of the first thing we ran it on. (It's not to do with the variable names `grouptmp1` and `grouptmp2`, it seems, because I swapped the order in which they were assigned and it's the first one which has the error.)

Comment: So, a bug? I have to say this bug is especially strange.

Comment: Looks like some kind of bug relating to the caching of numerical values. A simplified example: `ClearSystemCache[]; a = 3/Sqrt[2] + 2 Sqrt[2]; Table[
 GroupBy[{a, a}, N[#, 3] &], {2}]`

Comment: @SimonWoods So you mean this seems a more fundamental bug? Oh, my god! How many kind of situation can this bug affect? I may have already "written" some other bugs in my code :(

Answer (score 19):

It looks like a problem of numeric cache:

```
SetSystemOptions["CacheOptions" -> {"Numeric" -> {"Cache" -> False}}];
tmp = {3/Sqrt[2] + 3 Sqrt[2], 3/Sqrt[2] + 3 Sqrt[2]};

grouptmp1 = GroupBy[tmp, N[#, 8] &];
grouptmp2 = GroupBy[tmp, N[#, 8] &];
grouptmp1 === grouptmp2
(* True *)
```

With caching I get `False`. See also Simon Woods's [comment](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/100139#comment271820_100142).

There is a more global problem even without caching. Let us consider a list with almost equal values

```
list = Rationalize[RandomReal[{1.0006, 1.00062}, 1000], 0];
```

However, `GroupBy` splits it to 2 groups:

```
keys = Keys@GroupBy[list, N[#, 4] &]
(* {1.001, 1.001} *)

keys // InputForm
(* {1.00060319124101772085572137934965342771`4., 
    1.00061484060574776948630746611773121172`4.} *)

Equal @@ keys
(* True *)
```

It looks like that `GroupBy` performs some sort of rounding and hashing

```
Hash /@ N[list, 4] // Tally
(* {{7485563185340423637, 516}, {3244483472298741377, 484}} *)
```

Finally, I propose to use robust grouping by pairwise comparison:

```
Length@Gather[list, Abs[# - #2] < 0.001 &]
(* 1 *)
```

Comment: Thank you, see my recent update. Version 7 also suffers

Comment: You propose what?!

Comment: @SimonWoods Thanks, I corrected the typo.

Comment: I think `GroupBy` uses a comparison equivalent to `MatchQ` instead of `Equal`.  Consider `MatchQ[#, First@keys] & /@ N[list, 4] // Tally`.