# Delete duplicate elements from a list

Tags: list-manipulation

If a list contains duplicate elements, for example

```
 list = {a, 1, 5, 3, 5, x^2, x^2},
```

how can the duplicate elements be removed? The result would be

```
 uniqueElements = {a, 1, 5, 3, x^2}
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can use `DeleteDuplicates` to remove the duplicate elements while preserving the original order:

```
DeleteDuplicates[{a, 1, 5, 3, 5, x^2, x^2}]
(* {a, 1, 5, 3, x^2} *)
```

Answer (score 41):

In version 7 or later, use the [`DeleteDuplicates`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/DeleteDuplicates.html) function.  (See also [`DeleteDuplicatesBy`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DeleteDuplicatesBy.html), introduced in version 10, but be aware of [performance considerations](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/55294/121).)

For versions of Mathematica before 7, when `DeleteDuplicates` was introduced, and for general interest, here are several ways of implementing the `UnsortedUnion` (i.e. DeleteDuplicates) function.  These are collected from the help docs and MathGroup.  They have been adjusted to accept multiple lists which are then joined, in analogy to `Union`.  Unlike `Union`, these functions do not sort the list in the process of removing duplicates.

These methods may be obsolete for the specific function of `DeleteDuplicates` but they demonstrate methods that continue to be useful in more general problems.

- Derivatives of the [first method](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/2676/121) below using `Sequence[]`:

  1. [DeleteDuplicates while retaining sublist structure](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9319999/618728)
  2. [Selecting minimal subsets](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/8160/121)
- The `Sow`/`Reap` method demonstrates sowing one object to multiple tags, the reverse of its most common use, to powerful effect.
- The `Tally` method can be [generalized to `GatherBy`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/540/121).

#### For Mathematica 4 or earlier [[ref]](https://reference.wolfram.com/legacy/v4/RefGuide/Union_ex.html)

```
UnsortedUnion = Module[{f}, f[y_] := (f[y] = Sequence[]; y); f /@ Join@##] &
```

---

#### For Mathematica 5 [[ref]](https://reference.wolfram.com/legacy/v5/Built-inFunctions/ListsAndMatrices/ListConstruction/FurtherExamples/Reap.html)

```
UnsortedUnion[x__List] := Reap[Sow[1, Join@x], _, # &][[2]]
```

---

#### For Mathematica 6

```
UnsortedUnion[x__List] := Tally[Join@x][[All, 1]]
```

---

#### From Leonid Shifrin for Mathematica 3+

```
unsortedUnion[x_List] := 
  Extract[x, Sort[Union[x] /. Dispatch[MapIndexed[Rule, x]]]]
```

Comment: Wizard I like the Leonid's solution for the old versions of Mathematica. Not too relevant anymore, but still cool.

Comment: +1. Actually, I had an impression that `Dispatch` first appeared only in 4.1, but I may be mistaken. Also, IIRC, the first solution is a version of the solution first published by Carl Woll.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin The first two solutions are also found in the documentations of the respective versions.  That is where I learned about them. The docs say Dispatch is from v2, but I start using Mma only at v4, and at that time I didn't even know about Dispatch, so I don't know if it changed.

Comment: @Szabolcs Interesting. I knew that the `Reap`-`Sow` one is in the docs, but not about the one by Carl. You may be right about `Dispatch`.

Comment: Being a fan of `Reap` and `Sow`, I like the v.5 code as it is most likely a single pass operation. Similarly, the v.6 code is likely to be single pass, also.

Answer (score 12):

If you don't care about the original order (or if you want it sorted), use `Union`:

```
Union@{a, 1, 5, 3, 5, x^2, x^2}
(* {1, 3, 5, a, x^2} *)
```

Comment: Since `DeleteDuplicates` is faster than `Union` I would say this is if you *do* care about sorting, specifically that you want it.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: Fair enough, but then I should mention that with `Union` you have to type less :)

Comment: Haha, true, but if you don't feel like typing the best advice is to not use Mathematica... `NotebookSetupLayoutInformationPacket`, `MultivariateHypergeometricDistribution`, `NormalizedSquaredEuclideanDistance` or the ironic `VerboseConvertToPostScriptPacket`

Comment: @Rojo reminds me of generic programming in c++.

Answer (score 9):

I use v5.2 regularly. The fastest way I've found to simulate `DeleteDuplicates` is

```
DD[data_] := Part[data,Sort@Part[Range[Length@data][[#]],
   Most@FoldList[Plus,1,Length/@Split@data[[#]]]]]& @ Ordering@data
```

Here are some comparative times. `RS` is from the `Reap` Help, `UU` is Carl Woll's `UnsortedUnion`, and `VV` is Leonid Shifrin's suggestion for v3+; all three have been mentioned earlier. `WW`, `XX`, and `YY` are my attempts to speed up `VV`.

```
RS[data_] := Reap[Sow[1, data], _, # &][[2]]

VV[data_] := Extract[data, Sort[Union[data] /. Dispatch[MapIndexed[Rule,data]]]]

WW[data_] := Part[data, Sort[Union[data] /. Dispatch[MapIndexed[#1->#2[[1]]&,data]]]]

XX[data_] := Part[data, Sort[Union[data] /. Dispatch[Thread@Rule[data,Range@Length@data]]]]

YY[data_] := Part[data, Sort[Union[data] /. Dispatch[MapThread[Rule,{data,Range@Length@data}]]]]

UU[data_] := Block[{f}, f[x_] := (f[x] = Sequence[]; x); f /@ data]

Length[data = Table[Random[Integer,1*^5],{1*^5}]]
Timing[rs = RS@data; "RS"]
Timing[vv = VV@data; "VV"]
Timing[ww = WW@data; "WW"]
Timing[xx = XX@data; "XX"]
Timing[yy = YY@data; "YY"]
Timing[uu = UU@data; "UU"]
Timing[dd = DD@data; "DD"]
{Length@dd, SameQ[dd,rs,uu,vv,ww,xx,yy]}
```

> 100000
>
> {3.89 Second, RS}
>
> {2.43 Second, VV}
>
> {1.79 Second, WW}
>
> {1.59 Second, XX}
>
> {1.58 Second, YY}
>
> {1.54 Second, UU}
>
> {0.47 Second, DD}
>
> {63070, True}

Comment: Very interesting.  I don't think I've seen your method before, though it has common features with other code I've seen and used.  I wonder if this can be improved further?

Comment: I expect it will be eventually, but it doesn’t seem to be a hot topic so it may take a while.

Comment: To give credit where it's due, [your recent comment](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/116160) drew my attention to [Leonid's answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/21352), which I am pretty sure my `DD` above is just an adaptation of.

Comment: `Range[Length@data][[#]]` in `DD` can be simplified as `#`.