# Combining lists

Tags: list-manipulation

How can I combine

```
list1={{x1,y1},{x2,y2},{x3,y3}}
```

and

```
list2={{x4,y4},{x5,y5}}
```

to

```
list={{x1,y1},{x2,y2},{x3,y3},{x4,y4},{x5,y5}}
```

?

Comment: Harald, did you have a look at the documentation? Your question is very close to the RTFM category, so pressing F1 or googling first is usually recommended.

Comment: In particular, you should look at the [List Manipulation](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/guide/ListManipulation.html) section of the documentation, the tutorials near the bottom, in particular.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need `Join` :

```
list = Join[list1, list2]
```

sometimes you would choose :

```
listU = Union[list1, list2]
```

The latter doesn't include duplicates, as the first approach could, if some of elements in `list1` and `list2` were common.

**Edit**

It should be emphasized that since for small lists different approaches (pointed out in the other answers)  are elegant and quite satisfactory, however for big lists `Join` is much superior. We compare their efficiency in a few different cases :

1. ```
   lA1 = RandomReal[1, {500000, 2}];
   lA2 = RandomReal[1, {500000, 2}];

   Join[lA1, lA2]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
   ## & @@@ {lA1, lA2}; // AbsoluteTiming // First
   {lA1, lA2}~Flatten~1; // AbsoluteTiming // First
   ```

   > ```
   > 0.0210000
   > 0.8090000
   > 0.4620000
   > ```
2. ```
   lB1 = RandomReal[1, {2500000, 2}];
   lB2 = RandomReal[1, {1500000, 2}];

   Join[lB1, lB2]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
   ## & @@@ {lB1, lB2}; // AbsoluteTiming // First
   {lB1, lB2}~Flatten~1; // AbsoluteTiming // First
   ```

   > ```
   > 0.0820000
   > 3.1500000
   > 1.9000000
   > ```
3. ```
   lC1 = RandomReal[1, {300000, 2}];
   lC2 = RandomReal[1, {900000, 2}];

   Join[lC1, lC2]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
   ## & @@@ {lC1, lC2}; // AbsoluteTiming // First
   {lC1, lC2}~Flatten~1; // AbsoluteTiming // First
   ```

   > ```
   > 0.0220000
   > 0.9320000
   > 0.6640000
   > ```

We can see that `Join` is roughly about `20-30` times faster than `{list1, list2}~Flatten~1;` and the latter is about `1.5-2` times faster than  `## & @@@`.

Comment: One issue with `Union` is that it sorts the list, and if you don't wish to do that, other ways must be [found](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5246330/198315) (see [Mr.Wizard's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5248866/198315), in particular).

Comment: @rcollyer FWIW there is a slighter richer copy of that answer [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/2423/121).

Comment: @Mr.Wizard couldn't find that when I was looking for it.

Comment: rcollyer and Mr.Wizard Thanks for links.

Answer (score 13):

And another:

```
## & @@@ {list1, list2}
```

Comment: Neat trick, turning each sub-list into a `Sequence` that is then embedded in the outer list. +1

Comment: Another way to do this (by literally doing what @rcollyer described) is `Sequence @@@ {list1, list2}`.

Comment: @rcollyer One problem with this is that it will unpack both lists if they were packed.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin does celtschk do that, also?

Comment: @rcollyer Yep, he does. Anything that uses `Apply` on packed arrays, will unpack.

Answer (score 10):

Since there's always more than one way to do things in Mathematica, here's another alternative:

```
{list1, list2} ~Flatten~ 1
```

The above uses [infix](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Infix.html) notation, which might be a little hard to grok at first, but can make the code very readable for functions that take 2 arguments and have descriptive names.

For comparison, here is the same expression written in 3 other forms:

```
Flatten[{list1, list2}, 1]           (* Matchfix *)
Flatten[#, 1] &@{list1, list2}       (*  Prefix  *)
{list1, list2} // Flatten[#, 1] &    (* Postfix  *)
```

Comment: Why not add the other equivalent notations as well to show their relations?

Comment: @YvesKlett You mean prefix and postfix and matchfix?

Comment: Yup - you might gain some infix disciples once they realize the superior readability of the very same ;-)

Comment: @YvesKlett I'm a worshiper at the post-fix temple; it allows me to think of each subsequent function as a sequence of transformations. It isn't necessarily the most readable; however, it is easier to conceptualize.

Comment: Of course consequent use of Infix syntax would lead to `list1 ~List~ list2 ~Flatten~ 1`

Comment: @celtschk Nooooo. You don't want Mr.Wizard to read this conversation!

Comment: @R.M you brought that one unto yourself [donning flak gear].

Comment: @celtschk while, yes, it can lead there, even Mr.W wouldn't do that: it requires to many extra key-strokes. And, while I think he's definitely along the s&m (sadism and masochism) spectrum as far as infix is concerned, he's not interested in wasting effort.

Comment: If y'all are *trying* to amuse me you're doing a good job. :^)