# List Manipulation : {{{a,b},{c,d}},{{e,f},{g,h}}} into {{a,b},{c,d},{e,f},{g,h}}

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix

Hi I'd like to transform the matrix :

```
{{{184.586, 1.02758*10^8}, {139.94, 4.07249*10^7}, {117.72, 
   2.26123*10^7}, {109.528, 1.51412*10^7}, {95.7636, 
   8.68593*10^6}, {78.125, 5.16118*10^6}, {66.6777, 
   3.1014*10^6}}, {{183.505, 1.01147*10^8}, {138.25, 
   4.02021*10^7}, {115.814, 2.24641*10^7}, {108.22, 
   1.50985*10^7}, {91.3082, 9.28241*10^6}, {78.1087, 
   6.03119*10^6}, {65.9855, 3.56718*10^6}}}
```

with the same transformation as

```
{{{a,b},{c,d}},{{e,f},{g,h}}}
```

into

```
{{a,b},{c,d},{e,f},{g,h}}
```

How can I do plz ?

Comment: At least closely related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/5233/5478

Comment: I guess `gh` is a typo and should be `g, h`. Anyway, it's a bit uncertain what you actually are trying to do. One way to achieve the structural change seen here is `Join @@ {{{a,b},{c,d}},{{e,f},{g,h}}}`... (This can be also defined as a function `Apply[Join]`. Another, probably more understandable way is `Flatten[{{{a,b},{c,d}},{{e,f},{g,h}}}, 1]`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`Flatten` might be something you need:

```
listNested = {{{a, b}, {c, d}}, {{e, f}, {g, h}}};
Flatten[listNested, {1, 2}]
```

output:

```
{{a, b}, {c, d}, {e, f}, {g, h}}
```

Answer (score 9):

```
Catenate@list
```

where

```
list = {{{a,b},{c,d}},{{e,f},{g,h}}}
```

> {{a, b}, {c, d}, {e, f}, {g, h}}

Answer (score 6):

You can also use [`Join`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Join.html):

```
Apply[Join] @ {{{a, b}, {c, d}}, {{e, f}, {g, h}}}
```

> {{a, b}, {c, d}, {e, f}, {g, h}}

Alternative/equivalent form: `Join @@ {{{a, b}, {c, d}}, {{e, f}, {g, h}}}`