# How do you check if there are any equal arguments(even sublist) in a list?

Tags: list-manipulation, function-construction, expression-test

I would like to set up a function which has to return True if at least two arguments of a given List are equal.

So if I give `{1,4,6,2}` to the function it has to return `False` (since none of his arguments are equal) and the same would happen if I gave `{{1,2,3},{2,3,4}}`, while if I gave `{1,2,3,1,4}` or `{{1,2,3},{2,0,0},{1,2,3},{2,1,2}}` it has to return `True`.

I know this is a very simple problem and i think you can easily tell me a convenient way to achieve that.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If there are repeated elements in the list, then calling `Union[]` on it will shorten it so that this element only appears once, so a simple implementation would be to test these lengths:

```
 test[list_] := Length[Union[list]] != Length[list]
```

If you wanted to know which elements where repeated, you this could be accomplished by using `Gather[]` to collect identical elements, and picking out which groups have more then one element.

```
 repeats[list_] := Select[Gather[list], Length[#] > 1 &][[1 ;;, 1]]
```

Note, I'm using Union rather then `DeleteDuplicates[]` since (as Mr. Wizard corrected me) it is faster. I can't say why except that `DeleteDuplicates[]` retains the order of elements which may require slightly more bookkeeping. And in this case we don't care about the book keeping. Naturally if you really needed something really speedy, a better solution exists which doesn't search through the entire list, but stops if just a single duplicate is found, Mr. Wizards Answer is just such an function, since `Signature` exits early if duplicates exist, though it becomes slower if no duplicates are present, it's a trade off.

Comment: This is really great,jVincent and it totally wprks! Anyway i was wondering if you could save information about the argument repeated:i mean from your approach i can't tell which was the argument repeated,isn't it? Anyway,thanks again.

Comment: Any reason why you prefer `Union` over `DeleteDuplicates`?

Comment: @Ajasja Not really, I just use Union to join list far more often then I use DeleteDuplicates, and knew that it removes duplicates when called with only one list, so it was the first function to come to mind. Though just running a couple of Timing's I see that union is slightly slower, so I'm updating my answer. Thank you for the question.

Comment: You might want to restore this to `Union`.  Compare these timings: `a = RandomInteger[10, {100000, 50}];` then 
`Timing[Union@a;]` and 
`Timing[DeleteDuplicates@a;]`

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I did almost the exact same test and found DeleteDuplicates to be the faster one, though running this again, Union wins out. I think I might have just misread which line was which.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard that is a surprising difference. I'd expect `Union` to be slower as it also sorts. It makes me wonder what sorting algorithm it uses.

Answer (score 29):

As it happens there is a built-in function that already does this: [`Signature`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Signature.html).

> If any two elements of `list` are the same, `Signature[list]` gives 0.

```
dupeQ = 0 === Signature@# &;
```

I believe this is the "canonical" answer.  It is fast on both packed arrays and unpacked lists.

Comment: +1 for `Signature` which has been there since v1 but which I've never noticed. Your claim of speed, though, is incorrect. It's only true for lists that actually contain a duplicate. Try  `l = RandomInteger[100000, {1000000, 3}];` and your `dupeQ` is almost 10 times slower than kguler's `duplicatesQ`. I vote against this being a canonical answer.

Comment: There's more. It's very critically dependent on the dimensions of the test array. Use this one `l = RandomInteger[10, {1000000, 50}];` and the timings are totally different. `duplicatesQ` totally can't handle this and yours is extremely much faster. It takes 5 secs for yours and `duplicatesQ` is still running for a couple of minutes without finishing. Interesting behaviour...

Comment: So, perhaps canonical after all.

Comment: @Sjoerd I like this arrangement: I quickly slap some code on the wall and you give it a full analysis. :o)

Comment: We share the rep points. Deal?

Comment: @Sjoerd I honestly wish that were an option; as I think you know I would like to see a collaborative-answer feature added.

Comment: I know that's on @@LeonidShifrin's wish list as well.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries Anyone better sub  1 second for `RandomInteger[10, {1000000, 50}];` ?

Comment: Going From; SeedRandom[243324];a = RandomInteger[100000, {1000000, 3}];b = RandomInteger[10, {1000000, 50}];
I get `test[]` (defined in my answer) to be faster both on a and b. On my machine the timings are 4 and 12 for Signature based, and 1.4 on both for `Union[]` based.

Also, it seems like the first time I run Signature on a large dataset, the timing is always lower then repeating the exact same code. If I rerun the tests, both tests on signature give 12 seconds.

Comment: @jVincent just so you know I voted for your answer.  Also, I'm using version 7 so performance may vary.  What do you get using this data? `a = Range[1*^7]; a[[{1, 50}]] = 3.14159;`

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Of cause, I included the seed for the random numbers to allow for direct comparison. But lets be fair here, If we have `a = Range[1*^7]; a[[{1, 50}]] = 3.14159;` and `b = Range[1*^7]; a[[{1, 1*^6}]] = 3.14159;` Then on my Machine dupeQ wins on a with 0.063 against 0.984 for test and test wins b with 1.891 vs. 2.344 for dupeQ. 
To sum up, if there are duplicates then dupeQ wins because it can exit early, and if there are not any duplicates Union wins, most likely because Signatur has to suddenly figure out the actual signature, though oddly still slower if the duplicate is at the end

Answer (score 13):

```
duplicatesQ = # != DeleteDuplicates[#] &
```

Usage:

```
duplicatesQ[{1, 4, 6, 1}]
(* ===> True   *)
duplicatesQ@{1, 4, 6, 2}
(* ==> False *)
duplicatesQ@{{1, 2, 3}, {2, 0, 0}, {1, 2, 3}, {2, 1, 2}}
(* ==> True  *)
duplicatesQ /@ {{1, 2, 3}, {2, 0, 0}, {1, 2, 3}, {2, 1, 2}}
(* ==> {False, True, False, True} )
```

or (to also get the duplicate elements and their count when there are duplicate elements)

```
dups = (Select[Tally[#], Last[#] > 1 &] /. {} -> "None") &
```

Usage:

```
dups /@ {{1, 2, 3}, {2, 0, 0}, {1, 2, 3}, {2, 1, 2}}
(* ==> {"None", {{0, 2}}, "None", {{2, 2}}}  *)
dups[{{1, 2, 3}, {2, 0, 0}, {1, 2, 3}, {2, 1, 2}}]
(* ==> {{{1, 2, 3}, 2}}  *)
```

Answer (score 10):

You could also let the pattern matcher do all the work:

```
DuplicatesQ[l_] := MatchQ[l, {___,x_,___,x_,___}]
```

Or:

```
DuplicatesQ[{___,x_,___,x_,___}] := True
DuplicatesQ[_] := False
```

Comment: +1 for elegance, but be warned this is quite slow.

Answer (score 9):

Since you are looking for duplicates you could adapt any of the methods shown in [this answer.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/2423/121)

Using the first one for example:

```
dupeQ =
  Module[{f},
    f[y_] := (f[y] := Return[True, Module]; y);
    Scan[f, #]; False
  ] &;
```

This particular one has an advantage on long lists in that it will "short-circuit" on the first duplicate found rather than proceeding through the end of the list as `Union` or `DeleteDuplicates` will.  Example:

```
a = Range[1*^7];
a[[{1, 50}]] = 3.14159;

dupeQ[a] // Timing
```

> ```
> {0., True}
> ```

```
a != DeleteDuplicates[a] // Timing
```

> ```
> {5.944, True}
> ```

For this example I stacked the deck in my favor; by replacing elements in an Integer list with Reals I force the list to unpack.  In this situation and with an early duplicate (positions 1 and 50) my method is about 65,000 times faster.  For a case with a packed array `dupeQ` is slower than `DeleteDuplicates` but not as dramatically:

```
a = Range[1*^7];
a[[50]] = 7;

dupeQ[a] // Timing
```

> ```
> {0.359, True}
> ```

```
a != DeleteDuplicates[a] // Timing
```

> ```
> {0.031, True}
> ```

---

Following up on this comment of yours:

> Anyway I was wondering if you could save information about the argument repeated: I mean from your approach I can't tell which was the argument repeated.

One could return the duplicate value if one is found and `False` otherwise:

```
dupe =
  Module[{f},
    f[y_] := (f[y] := Return[y, Module]; y);
    Scan[f, #]; False
  ] &;
```

This function has the same advantage of short-circuiting that the first one does.

Comment: In http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Return.html there's no mention of a second argument of `Return`. From the use above, I guess it's something about from which construct you want to return, right? Is that documented somewhere?

Comment: @celtschk yes; I also used it [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1447/121); the only documentation is [`Break::nofunc`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/message/Break/nofunc.html): "The second argument in Break, Continue, or Return is a label that specifies the enclosing function or loop that will be affected. If this label is omitted, the affected function or loop is determined using built-in heuristics."

Comment: Seems that WRI is great at hiding useful information in obscure places :-) Thank you for the information.

Comment: BTW, it just occurred to me that that page speaks about the *second* parameter of `Return`, *`Break` and `Continue`*. Actually for `Break` and `Continue` there is not even a *first* parameter documented. A quick test shows that for `Break` the first parameter gives a return value for the construct, just like `Return`, while for `Continue` I couldn't see any effect.

Comment: @celtschk good catch; I need to look into that.

Answer (score 7):

A frivolous implementation using patterns:

```
duplicateQ[list_]:=MemberQ[Tally[list],{_,_?(#>1&)}]
```

This function uses `Tally` to arrange the elements of `list` in bins.  For example,

```
In[2]:= Tally[{1,2,3,1,2}]
Out[2]= {{1,2},{2,2},{3,1}}
```

Then we look for an element in the output of `Tally` which looks like `{_,n}` with $n>1$.

```
In[3]:= duplicateQ[{{1,2,3},{2,3,4}}]
Out[3]= False

In[4]:= duplicateQ@{{1,2,3},{2,0,0},{1,2,3},{2,1,2}}
Out[4]= True
```

If we want to keep track of repeated elements, we can use

```
duplicates[list_] := Cases[Tally[list], {_, _?(# > 1 &)}]

In[6]:= duplicates[{1,4,6,1}]
Out[6]= {{1,2}}

In[7]:= duplicates@{{1,2,3},{2,0,0},{1,2,3},{2,1,2}}
Out[7]= {{{1,2,3},2}}
```

Comment: Thanks for this solution:it really helps me since is the nearest to my attempts of implementation.

Answer (score 7):

You could use `Gather` and then check the length of each group :

```
Gather[{{1, 2, 3}, {2, 0, 0}, {1, 2, 3}, {2, 1, 2}}]

(* {{{1, 2, 3}, {1, 2, 3}}, {{2, 0, 0}}, {{2, 1, 2}}} *)

Length[#] & /@ Gather[{{1, 2, 3}, {2, 0, 0}, {1, 2, 3}, {2, 1, 2}}]

(* {2, 1, 1} *)
```

Comment: Another great solution...thanks!

Answer (score 5):

In Version 9, there is a new function `DuplicateFreeQ` which returns `True` is there is any duplicate elements in a list. This function is currently not documented, but it is there.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Examples:

```
snake = {{0, 1}, {0, 0}, {1, 0}, {2, 0}, {3, 0}}
DuplicateFreeQ[snake]
(*True*)

a = {1, 2, 3, 3};
DuplicateFreeQ[a]
(* False *)

a = {1, 2, 3};
DuplicateFreeQ[a]
(* True *)

a = {{1, 1}, {1, 0}, {1, 0}};
DuplicateFreeQ[a]
(*False*)

a = {{1, 1}, {1, 0}, {1, 9}};
DuplicateFreeQ[a]
(*True*)
```

**Update**

Answering comment below.

```
Table[a = Range@n; a[[n/2]] = 1; Signature[a] // Timing // First, {n, 10^Range@8}]
(* {0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.015600, 0.156001} *)

Table[a = Range@n; a[[n/2]] = 1; DuplicateFreeQ[a] // Timing // First, {n, 10^Range@8}]
(* {0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.046800, 0.483603} *)
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Nasser, could tell me how this compares to `Signature` in performance, e.g. `Table[
 a = Range@n; a[[n/2]] = 1;
 Signature[a] // Timing // First,
 {n, 10^Range@8}
 ]`? (This uses about 800 MB memory).

Comment: Yes, thanks.  It appears `Signature` still has value for this application, at least in some cases.

Comment: Now (in version 10) `DuplicateFreeQ` is documented.

Answer (score 4):

Using `UnsameQ`:

```
MultiSetQ[lst_List]:=Not[UnsameQ@@lst]
```

Usage:

```
In[2]:= MultiSetQ[{1, 2, 2, 3}]
Out[2]= True
In[3]:= MultiSetQ[{1, 2, 4, 3}]
Out[3]= False
```

Comment: Nice answer, though not as fast as others.  You can make it even more concise:  `! UnsameQ @@ lst`

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I ran the tests you mention in the comments above and you're right. This is very slow (I had to kill the kernel!). And I thought it would be faster (by the rule of thumb that smaller code in Mathematica -> faster). Why is `Union` faster? I mean, it returns a **sorted** version of the list, while `UnsameQ` will stop comparing (I think) when it finds the first pair of equal elements. How can `Union` be faster??

Comment: I don't have an answer to that.  It's a good question though, and I'll be thinking about it.

Comment: I think the short answer is this: `UnsameQ` is designed for handling a low number of arguments.  Testing shows that `Union` and `DeleteDuplicates` have O(n) time complexity, whereas `UnsameQ` has O(n^2).  `UnsameQ` is actually faster on tests with a limited number of arguments (it is about even with `DeleteDuplicates` by 45), so I suppose that it was optimized for that kind of use.