# What can I use as the second argument to Return in my own functions?

Tags: programming

Having found out about the [second argument to `Return`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/6745/how-do-you-check-if-there-are-any-equal-argumentseven-sublist-in-a-list/6757#comment19366_6757) I played a bit with it, and the following tests all resulted in `Return::nofunc`:

```
f[x_]:=x
f[Return[3,f]]

SetAttributes[g,HoldAll];g[x_]:=x
g[Return[3,g]]

h[x_]:=f[x]
h[Return[3,f]]

SetAttributes[i,HoldAll];i[x_]:=f[x]
i[Return[3,f]]
```

On the other hand, the following works fine:

```
Module[{i},Return[3,Module]]
```

Does that mean the second argument of `Return` can only be used with a predefined list of symbols? If so, is there an easy way to find out that list? Otherwise, what am I doing wrong (and how would I do it right)?

Comment: Try this `f[x_] := g[Return[x, f]];
f[3]`

Comment: Versus this `f[x_] := g[Return[x]]; f[3]` of course

Comment: That (the version of your first comment) also gives `Return::nofunc` — which is no surprise given that that's equivalent to the case specifically mentioned as error in http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/message/Break/nofunc.html

Comment: @ celtschk Not in my machine ... it returns `3`

Comment: @belisarius: Hmmm ... maybe it depends on the Version. I'm using 8.0.0.0 on Linux.

Comment: Me too (8.0.0.0), 32 bits under Win XP

Comment: Ah, I found out the reason: I typed it in my notebook with the function `g` still defined as in my question (giving back its argument, and being `HoldAll`). After replacing `g` with `gg` (not defined in my session), it indeed gives `3` for me, too.

Comment: Related: [(29353)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/29353/121)

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Ok, my view on this is consistent with all of the cases presented so far...

**The symbols allowed in `Return` are those which are responsible for a transformation in the partial evaluation of the expression so far**. Of course, I'm referring only to the evaluation of the branch that includes the `Return`. There's a subtlety but I'll mention it later

Let's clarify this with your examples:

```
f[x_]:=x
f[Return[3,f]]
```

`f` has no attributes so, `Return` is run before any transformation is made. Doesn't work

```
h[x_]:=f[x]
h[Return[3,f]]
```

Again, `Return[3, f]` is executed first.

```
SetAttributes[i,HoldAll];
i[x_]:=f[x]
i[Return[3,f]]
```

Here, `i` is `HoldAll` so now we start talking. 
The `i[Return[3,f]]`->`f[Return[3, f]]` is first made. `i` was the symbol responsible. Now, we run `f[Return[3, f]]`, but `f` has no attributes, so the `Return[3, f]` is run, and again, can't find `f`. Could have found `i` however.

Last one (actually second on your list, but I thought I'd leave it for last). Here comes the subtlety:
Actually, not all symbols responsible for transformations are available. When there's a transformation associated with a symbol, say, `s1`, and then there's another one AT THE SAME LEVEL, associated with the symbol `s2`, then `s1` is shadowed by `s2` and no longer available

```
SetAttributes[g,HoldAll];
g[x_]:=x
g[Return[3,g]]
```

`g` is `HoldAll`, so that's a good start. First step: `g[Return[3, g]]`->`Return[3, g]` and `g` is responsible for the transformation... So, it would seem that we are succeeding.
HOWEVER, the very last transformation from `Return[3, g]` to whatever, makes the symbol `Return` shadow `g`. So, this could be fixed by just making the `Return` work at a lower level

```
SetAttributes[g,HoldAll];
g[x_]:=# &[x]
g[Return[3,g]]
```

It is interesting to note that `Return[2, Return]` works, and would have worked in the previous example too.

Ok, now let's go to the cases where it actually works

```
Module[{i},Return[3,Module]]
```

`Module` is `HoldAll`. First, there's a transformation associated to `Module`. If that transformation returned `Return[3, Module]`, then this wouldn't work. But this works. So, I choose to believe that despite what `Trace` shows, `Module` evaluated the `Return` expression internally before returning, just like our `g[x_]:=# &[x]` example.

@belisarius on the comments:

```
f[x_] := g[Return[x, f]];
f[3]
```

`f[3]`->`g[Return[3, f]]`. `f` was responsible. Now, `Return[3, f]` is evaluated (at a lower level in the expression tree) and success.

Bonus example:

```
SetAttributes[f, HoldAll];
g /: f[i_, g] := {i}
```

Now

```
f[Return[2, g], g]
```

This actually works! Why?

`f[Return[2,g], g]` is turned into `{Return[2, g]}` BECAUSE OF `g`. Now, `Return` is evaluated (at a lower level) and that's the way the cookie crumbles

**Summary**

Imagine the expressions as trees, and the evaluation procedure as a succession of trees, and in each transformation, draw a sign pointing at the new sub-tree, with the symbol responsible written on it. If you ever have to transform that same subtree again, the previous sign is lost. When it's time for `Return` to evaluate, you go up the tree and see the signs in the path to the top. Those are the ones you can use.

Comment: Will have to experiment with this more, but a big +1 in any case.