# FoldWhile and FoldWhileList

Tags: functional-style

Mathematica has had `NestWhile` and `NestWhileList` for some time.  But, to date, it has not implemented a built-in `FoldWhile` or a `FoldWhileList`.  So, since these constructs seem useful to me, I have tried to brew my own.  Here are my current implementations.  Anyone have suggestions on how either of these might be improved.  I'd be particularly interested in a variant of `FoldWhile` that did not require as much memory as `FoldWhileList`.

```
 FoldWhileList[f_, init_, list_, test_, m_, max_] := 
 Block[{i = 0}, 
    NestWhileList[(i = i + 1; f[#, Part[list, i]]) &, init, test, m, max]]
```

and

```
 FoldWhile[f_, init_, list_, test_, m_, max_] := 
    Last[FoldWhileList[f, init, list, test, m, max]]
```

**Note: These functions were introduced as built-ins in Version 12.2**

Comment: Seth, regarding your comments: indeed, I did not implement the capability to use `m` most recent results. I this is really necessary, then your implementation is likely a way to go, since `Fold` can not be used to implement this. As to the complexity - I don't think most users have to reimplement it themselves - they could as well come to this page and pick whichever implementation they like the most :).

Comment: These seem still to be missing.  Is there a ready explanation of why?

Answer (score 27):

#### Implementation

Here are my versions. I will start with `FoldWhile`:

```
Clear[dressInCtr];
dressInCtr[test_, max_] := 
   Module[{ctr = 0}, (++ctr <= max ) && test[##] &]

Clear[FoldWhile];
FoldWhile[f_, test_, start_, secargs_List, max_Integer] :=
   FoldWhile[f, dressInCtr[test, max], start, secargs];

FoldWhile[f_, test_, start_, secargs_List] :=
  Module[{last = start},
    Fold[
      If[test[##], last = f[##], Return[last, Fold]] &, 
      start, 
      secargs]];
```

The `FoldWhileList` is a bit more involved:

```
Clear[FoldWhileList];
FoldWhileList[f_, test_, start_, secargs_List, max_Integer] :=
   FoldWhileList[f, dressInCtr[test, max], start, secargs];
FoldWhileList[f_, test_, start_, secargs_List] :=
Module[{tag},
   If[# === {}, {start}, Prepend[First@#, start]] &@
    Reap[
      Fold[
        If[test[##], Sow[f[##],tag], Return[Null, Fold]] &, 
        start, 
        secargs], 
      _, #2 &][[2]]]
```

#### Examples

Here are some examples:

```
FoldWhileList[Plus,#2<5&,0,Range[30]]

(* {0,1,3,6,10}  *)

FoldWhileList[Plus,#2<5&,0,Range[30],3]

(* {0,1,3,6} *)

FoldWhile[Plus,#2<5&,0,Range[30]]

(* 10  *)

FoldWhile[Plus,#2<5&,0,Range[30],3]

(* 6 *)
```

#### Remarks

I chose to use `Fold` itself as an economical way to implement `FoldWhile` and `FoldWhileList`. It helped that the two-argument version of `Return` (undocumented) could be used here. I also found it simplest to implement the extended form with a fifth parameter giving maximal number of iterations, by dressing the test criteria in a closure, which is done via a closure generator function `dressInCtr`. This also seems to be a good illustration of the usefulness of closures.

Comment: Didn't know `Return` had a second argument, odd thing to leave out of the documentation.

Comment: @ssch Agree. This second argument business is explained very well in [this excellent answer by Rojo](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/6815/what-can-be-used-as-the-second-argument-to-return-on-your-own-functions/7090#7090). That answer deserves many more upvotes IMO.

Comment: Got 6 upvotes on that answer today. Thanks ;)

Comment: Btw, making `FoldWhileList` using `FoldList` with a modified function that sows the result would be as efficient?

Comment: @Rojo Welcome :-). Re: as efficient: memory-wise, no, since `Sow` will have to store those intermediate results internally. This, plus the fact that I can make the code simpler, was my motivation to implement it separately. As for run-time efficiency, a bit less efficient too, but probably not much so.

Comment: I actually meant to ask using `FoldWhile` and not `FoldList`, my bad

Comment: @Rojo That's a cool idea! It won't be as efficient alas, due to assignments to `last` (main part) and extra function invocation. So, while I like this from the design perspective, I would probably still keep my version unchanged, for efficiency. Of course, for computationally-intensive functions this should not matter much.

Comment: @Rojo I see that the two of you implemented a more advanced syntax than I did.  I'll have to return to that later.  I'm curious to know how my stripped down version performs compared to each of yours, if you've tested it.  (That too will have to wait to later for me.)

Comment: @LeonidShifrin Is `dressInCtr` really a closure (in the sense that variables are bound to the block of executing code) or is it more the case that `ctr$nnn` is accessible as a global variable outside of module? Also, if I do `Names["ctr*"]` after the examples I get `{"ctr", "ctr$"}` so the `Temporary` attribute of `ctr$nnn` seems to be working (to some extent). (+1 of course:)

Comment: @Ajasja It is a closure.The fact that in principle one can access variables like `ctr$nnn` from the top-level is due to the imperfect emulation of lexical scoping by Mathematica's symbol renaming mechanism. Normally, one would not use such variable names, so for all practical purposes this should be ok. Also, if you consider other languages (e.g. javascript), the variables from enclosing environment remain accessible / modifyable from within a returned function (closure) - they are just not available at the top-level. As for `Names` - yes, `Temporary` works, because the variables are ...

Comment: @Ajasja ... enclosed in pure functions, so as soon as the main function (the one using that closure) executes, the garbage collector comes to those variables.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin Thanks I think I understand! Any idea why `{"ctr", "ctr$"}` leak into the global contest? Even if I do `Names["test*"];
Module[{test = 1}, test + 1];
Names["test*"];` I get `{}; 2; {test}` (new lines have to be used instead of ; )

Comment: @Ajasja I think this (leaking) is an artifact of parsing, since the code is parsed and symbols like `ctr` created before the binding / variable renaming takes place. As for `$ctr`, this one is probably created at some intermediate stage in the implementation of `Module` - perhaps part of this implementation is done in Mathematica code (but not the top-level code). I would actually consider the leaking of `ctr$` as a borderline bug, albeit not a very important one.

Comment: One could use `Catch[]`/`Throw[]` for implementing `FoldWhile[]` as well, I suppose. I mean, [the docs do hint on this construction...](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Fold.html#29645)

Comment: @LeonidShifrin Please make a note of Seth's (now deleted) post down. He had a few comments for you.

Comment: @J.M. Sure, this is a possibility. I usually prefer to not use `Catch`-`Throw` when softer methods (such as `Return`) are sufficient.

Answer (score 8):

These are the first methods that came to mind.  I'll have to leave comparing them to the other answers for later.

```
FoldWhile[f_, start_, rest_, test_] :=
 Module[{g},
   g[_, x_?test] := x;
   g[last_, _] := Return[last, Fold];
   Fold[# ~g~ f@## &, start, rest]
 ]

FoldWhile[Plus, 0, Range@100, # < 30 &]
```

> ```
> 28
> ```

```
FoldWhileList[f_, start_, rest_, test_] :=
 Module[{bag = Internal`Bag[start], g},
  g[x_?test] := (Internal`StuffBag[bag, x]; x);
  g[else_] := Return[Null, Fold];
  Fold[g @ f @ ## &, start, rest];
  Internal`BagPart[bag, All]
 ]

FoldWhileList[Plus, 0, Range@100, # < 30 &]
```

> ```
> {0, 1, 3, 6, 10, 15, 21, 28}
> ```

Comment: I'm curious too as to how they all perform, but don't take my answer too seriously

Answer (score 7):

Just FYI, Mathematica 12.2 introduces [`FoldWhile`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FoldWhile.html) and [`FoldWhileList`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FoldWhileList.html) with the intended usages.

Answer (score 6):

```
foldWhile[function_, check_, x_, list_, m_: Infinity] :=
 Module[{counter = 0, out, restart, newValue, result = x, 
   max = Min[m, Length@list]},
  Label[restart];
  ++counter;
  newValue = list[[counter]];
  If[! check[result, newValue] || counter >= max, Goto[out]];
  result = function[result, newValue];
  Goto[restart];
  Label[out];
  result
  ]
```

Another one

```
foldWhile[function_, check_, x_, list_, m_: Infinity] :=
 Module[{max = Min[m, Length@list]},
  (Composition @@ list~Take~max)[#][x] //. {
    res_[Except[#, next_][rest_]][val_] /; check[res, next] :> 
     function[val, res][rest][next],
    res_[_][val_] :> function[val, res]
    }
  ]
```

For both

```
foldWhileList[f_, test_, start_, rest___] := Module[{tag}, Reap[
    foldWhile[
     Sow[f@##, tag] &, test, Sow[start, tag], rest], tag][[-1, 1]]]
```

Comment: @Leonid, ironically, this beats yours for long lists that test out early. Probably you are making a copy of the list in your solution?

Comment: No time to benchmark now, but no, I don't make a copy, at least I don't see any obvious place where I do. Will look into that later.

Comment: Please take a look at Seth's now deleted post further down. He had a comment for you.

Comment: @rm-rf does it work for you? I just tried it with the 2 examples in Leonid's answer and it worked

Comment: Sorry, I haven't tried it yet... been a bit occupied with other things (I haven't fixed my zero rows removal answer either!)