# How to find first list element that differs from average of N previous elements by more than a given amount?

Tags: list-manipulation, programming, functions, functional-style

Given a list of real numbers, I need to write a function that returns the value of the first element in the list that differs from the mean of the previous $N$ elements by greater than $P$ standard deviations of those same elements. (I use mean and standard deviation as sample functions, I may decide to use something else.)

Clearly, I can write a loop to do this, but I'd like to use functional programming techniques to do this, and continue to learn better Mathematica programming style. `Select[ ]` looked promising, but I see no way to involve the previous list elements in the selection criterion.

Thanks in advance for your help!
Tom

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's an attempt (without select)

```
lst = {1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 5, 2, 4};
n = 4;
p = 1;
Flatten[If[Abs[Take[#, -1] - Mean[Drop[#, -1]]][[1]] > p *StandardDeviation[Drop[#, -1]],
 Take[#, -1], {}] & /@ Partition[lst, n + 1, 1, 1]] // First
```

Alternatively with Select.

```
Select[Partition[lst, n + 1, 1, 1], 
    Abs[Take[#, -1] - Mean[Drop[#, -1]]][[1]] > p*StandardDeviation[Drop[#, -1]] &] 
    // First // Last
```

For a more efficient implementation - see Mr Wizard's answer

Comment: Your 2 samples give different answer…

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out @xzczd, I copied the wrong select version. It's fixed now.

Comment: In fact you can also use the 3rd argument of `Select` to take the first matched sublist.

Comment: Thanks to all for the excellent answers. Too bad I can't accept all of them!

Comment: @Tom with my sincere apologies to Jonie, this is really not the best method to use.  Far better would at least be `PartitionMap` so as not to waste massive amounts of memory.  Have you seen the performance metrics in my answer?  Have you taken the time to run your own?

Comment: @TomDickens, if you could kindly change the acceptance to Mr Wizard's answer for future visitors, that'd be great.
Mr Wizard - no worries. I did learn that partition construct off another answer you made afterall.

Comment: @Jonie Thanks, I appreciate that.  `Partition` certainly has many good uses.  I'll add a new section to my (already too long, apparently) answer showing how you can use `PartitionMap` efficiently.

Answer (score 8):

Here is a functional programming style implementation based on `Fold`, using `Throw` and `Catch` to mimic the non-existent `FoldWhile` construct. You might be interested in [some earlier attempts to build a `FoldWhile` function](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/19102/8).

```
firstOutlier[data : {__?NumericQ}, p_?Positive, k_Integer?Positive] /;
   k < Length[data] := 
 Catch[Fold[
   If[Abs[#2 - Mean[#1]] > p*StandardDeviation[#1], Throw[#2], 
     Join[Rest[#1], {#2}]] &, Take[data, k], Drop[data, k]] ]
```

Using Jonie's test data:

```
 firstOutlier[{1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 5, 2, 4}, 1, 4]

 (* 5 *)
```

Answer (score 6):

Here's a way using [`NestWhile`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/NestWhile.html):

```
f[lst_?(VectorQ[#, NumericQ] &), n_Integer?Positive, p_?Positive] := 
 If[Length @ # > n, #[[n + 1]], None] &@
  NestWhile[Rest, lst, 
   Length @ # > n && 
     Abs[Mean @ #[[;; n]] - #[[n + 1]]] <= p StandardDeviation @ #[[;; n]] &]

f[{1, 3, 2, 0, 2, 2, 1, 2}, 4, 1]
(* None *)

f[{1, 3, 2, 0, 2, 5, 1, 2}, 4, 1]
(* 5 *)
```

Comment: I wrote my answer before reading any of the others but the body of this certainly looks similar to my `test`.  I guess that's the natural way to approach this however.  Now for timings.

Answer (score 6):

#### Considerations

This question reminds me of [Iterate until condition is met](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/21584/121) in a way.  You would probably find my answer there applicable as you will likely face similar considerations, e.g. block-based processing comes with a certain overhead but allows for vector optimizations in many cases.

Things like [`Mean`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Mean.html) will be more efficiently calculated in an incremental fashion using e.g. [`MovingAverage`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/MovingAverage.html) or [`ListCorreclate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ListCorreclate.html).  Therefore there is a trade-off between pre-processing the data in a faster way and processing only as much as is needed until the first result is found, with the average length of your data and the position of the first match determining which is best.  I don't know how to (efficiently at least) calculate an incremental standard deviation but that is likely my own ignorance.

### Basic proposal

For generic functions without the incremental approach I propose using `Select` on list of indexes with a test function that extracts elements from the input list and performs the requested comparison.  This has considerable memory advantage over using `Partition` and will also be faster when the match occurs early in the input list.

(One could use an incrementing position variable rather than a list of indexes, which would conserve memory further.  I chose to use the indexes because of the flexibility it provides such as easily returning the first *m* matches.)

Here is a partially generalized function that implements this proposal:

```
find[list_, n_, p_, m_: 1, f1_: Mean, f2_: StandardDeviation] :=
  Module[{test},
    test[x_] := Abs[list[[x]] - f1@#] > p * f2@# & @ list[[x - n ;; x - 1]];
    list[[ Select[Range[n + 1, Length@list], test, m] ]]
  ]
```

- The three required parameters are `list`, `n`, and `p`.
- `m` is the maximum number of matches to return, defaulting to one.
- `f1` and `f2` default to `Mean` and `StandardDeviation` but could be replaced with any other vector functions.

To make `find` more general it would probably be best to make `p` part of the `f2` function but I wanted to respect your defined parameters.

Example:

```
SeedRandom[1]
list = RandomReal[{-9, 9}, 50];

find[list, 5, 1.5]
```

> ```
> {3.60853}
> ```

```
find[list, 5, 1.5, 3]
```

> ```
> {3.60853, 4.47582, 8.58909}
> ```

#### Tuning

For maximum speed but less flexibility one can `Compile` a simple `Do` loop.  It is several times faster and has the same computational complexity as the method above.

Limitations:

- You lose the on-the-fly ability to change functions (`f1`, `f2`), at least without meta-programming to generate a new compiled function.
- It returns only the first match rather than a specified number (`m`), though that could be added with more code and e.g. `Sow` and `Reap`.
- It will only work on lists of machine-size numbers.

Code:

```
findC =
 With[{f1 = Mean, f2 = StandardDeviation},
  Compile[{{list, _Real, 1}, {n, _Integer}, {p, _Real}},
   Do[
    If[#, Return @ list[[x]]] &[
     Abs[list[[x]] - f1@#] > p*f2@# &@list[[x - n ;; x - 1]]
    ],
    {x, n + 1, Length@list} ]]];
```

#### Alternative using `PartitionMap`

I favor my `find` because of the ease of specifying the number of matches to return *while still preserving the short-circuit behavior*, however it may be easier to think of this problem in terms of `Partition`.

But there are two major drawbacks to using `Partition`:

- you will expand the array to $N$ times its original size
- the entire vector is partitioned in advance of testing, causing a fixed overhead even on very early matches

Both these problems can be solved by using [`PartitionMap`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/PartitionMap.html) and [`Return`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Return.html), as I shall illustrate.  Note that I will be using [a second argument in `Return`.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/18524/121)

With the test function from Jonie's `Select` method, refined, and some data:

```
test = Abs[Last[#] - Mean[Most @ #]][[1]] > p*StandardDeviation[Most @ #] &;

SeedRandom[1]
lst = RandomReal[{-9, 9}, 150000];
{n, p} = {20, 3.0};
```

This is equivalent to Jonie's second method (with the refined test):

```
Select[Partition[lst, n + 1, 1, 1], test] // First // Last // Timing
```

> ```
> {0.827, -8.73536}
> ```

This match occurs only 864 places into the list; the slow speed is due partly to the `Partition` overhead but primarily to the fact that *all* places were tested, because the third parameter of `Select` was not used.  (The memory consumption would remain high either way.)

Now here is the improved method:

```
Needs["Developer`"]

PartitionMap[If[test@#, Return[#, PartitionMap]] &, lst, n + 1, 1, 1] // Last // Timing
```

> ```
> {0.005488, -8.73536}
> ```

This is faster than the flexible `find` but not as fast as `findC` (`timeAvg` code below):

```
find[lst, n, p]  // timeAvg
findC[lst, n, p] // timeAvg
```

> ```
> 0.01436
>
> 0.001872
> ```

Finally, as a function:

```
findP[list_, n_, p_, f1_: Mean, f2_: StandardDeviation] :=
  Module[{toss, PMap = Developer`PartitionMap},
    toss = If[Abs[Last[#] - f1[Most@#]] > p*f2[Most@#], Return[#, PMap]] &;
    PMap[toss, list, n + 1, 1, 1] // Last
  ]
```

---

### Timings

I wrote this answer before looking at others so as not to be influenced.  I see now that Michael used code very similar to my `test` function but he did not an indexed-based `Select`, choosing instead repeated shortening of the list with `Rest`.  The `Rest` approach will slow down proportionally to the length of the input list because of the reallocation that occurs with *Mathematica* lists while the index approach will not.  Jonie's code pre-partitions the entire list an will use *n* times the memory of the input list so I did not attempt to use it on the long lists below.

*Correction:* Contrary to what I stated before, Verbeia's code *does not* suffer from the reallocation problem.

On short lists the functions are in the same magnitude, but on long lists:

```
SeedRandom[1]
list = RandomReal[{-9, 9}, 500000];

f[list, 5, 9]    // Timing  (* Michael's function *)
find[list, 5, 9] // Timing
```

> ```
> {2.668, -4.43862}
>
> {0.047, {-4.43862}}
> ```

The performance gap increases as the list gets longer:

```
SeedRandom[1]
list = RandomReal[{-9, 9}, 1500000];

f[list, 5, 20]    // Timing
find[list, 5, 20] // Timing
```

> ```
> {46.379, -4.75616}
>
> {0.203, {-4.75616}}
> ```

Now `fincC` and `findP` on the same data:

```
findC[list, 5, 20] // Timing

findP[list, 5, 20] // Timing
```

> ```
> {0.058, -4.75616}
>
> {0.156, -4.75616}
> ```

#### Timings, part 2

Correcting myself, Verbeia's code does not suffer from the reallocation problem described above.  Here are some comparative timings against my code (`timeAvg` posted many times before).

On a test that results in early termination `find` is and order of magnitude faster than `firstOutlier`, and `findC` is another three orders faster than that:

```
SetAttributes[timeAvg, HoldFirst]

timeAvg[func_] := Do[If[# > 0.3, Return[#/5^i]] & @@ Timing@Do[func, {5^i}], {i, 0, 15}]

{size, n, p} = {1000000, 100, 1.7};

SeedRandom[1];
list = RandomReal[{-9, 9}, size];

firstOutlier[list, p, n] // timeAvg
find[list, n, p]         // timeAvg
findP[list, n, p]        // timeAvg
findC[list, n, p]        // timeAvg
```

> ```
> 0.327
>
> 0.02496
>
> 0.003864
>
> 0.000023936
> ```

However, with late termination `find` falls behind `firstOutlier`.

```
{size, n, p} = {1000000, 100, 2.4};

SeedRandom[1];
list = RandomReal[{-9, 9}, size];

firstOutlier[list, p, n] // Timing
find[list, n, p]         // Timing
findP[list, n, p]        // Timing
findC[list, n, p]        // Timing
```

> ```
> {5.055, 8.71491}
>
> {5.569, {8.71491}}
>
> {4.929, 8.71491}
>
> {2.09, 8.71491}
> ```

#### Memory

Here is an illustration of the problem with `Partition` that I mentioned.  Jonie's second method tested a bit better than the first so I will use that:

```
jonie2[lst_, n_, p_] := 
 Select[Partition[lst, n + 1, 1, 1], 
    Abs[Take[#, -1] - Mean[Drop[#, -1]]][[1]] > p*StandardDeviation[Drop[#, -1]] &] // 
   First // Last
```

Now, each time in in a fresh kernel and starting with:

```
{size, n, p} = {500000, 100, 2.2};
SeedRandom[1];
list = RandomReal[{-9, 9}, size];
```

Mine:

```
find[list, n, p] // Timing
MaxMemoryUsed[]
```

> ```
> {0.281, {-8.59958}}
>
> 37412144
> ```

Jonie's:

```
jonie2[list, n, p] // Timing
MaxMemoryUsed[]
```

> ```
> {4.212, -8.59958}
>
> 923440192
> ```

`findP` corrects this, taking even less memory than `find`:

```
findP[list, n, p] // Timing
MaxMemoryUsed[]
```

> ```
> {0.25, -8.59958}
>
> 27769328
> ```

Comment: Thanks for the remark on `Rest` - I hadn't realized the memory issue.  Your `find` beats my `f` hands down, but the timing complexity depends on the position of the first outlier.  With a relatively small list of 150000, `find` was between 8.4 and 1.7 times faster (used `SeedRandom[i]` for `i` from 1 to 100).

Comment: +1. I always learn something new from your answers.

Comment: @RunnyKine Thanks; I try!  (A bit too hard in this case perhaps; I think my verbosity put off Tom.)

Answer (score 3):

Fun little question. It seems to be getting a lot of good answers, but in any case I'll throw in my 2 cents. My immediate though is that this sort of fits the loop construct `LengthWhile`, since we really just want to keep on counting until we get a hit, but it doesn't naturally work on trailing lists, so we'll just add this to it. In that regard here's my suggesting:

```
countWhileList[list_, n_, criteria_] :=
   LengthWhile[
     Range[n + 1, Length@list],
     criteria[list[[# - n ;; #]]] &
   ] + 1 + n
```

Which can then be used as:

```
normalDeviation[list_] := Abs[(Mean[list] - list[[-1]])/StandardDeviation[list]]
countWhileList[testData, 40, normalDeviation[#] < 1 &]
```

Which will count trailing lists of 40 elements and return the number of the first hit that fails the criteria. Depending on preference, it could instead be made to count the number of successes by removing the `+1`.

Naturally if you then want the value, you can use `Part` as in

```
Part[testData,countWhileList[testData, 40, normalDeviation[#] < 1 &]]
```

Keeping in this style but allowing for multiple returns you could use instead

```
selectWhereList[list_, n_, criteria_, m_] :=
Select[Range[n + 1, Length@list], criteria[list[[# - n ;; #]]] &, m]

Part[test, First@selectWhereList[test, 40, normalDeviation[#] > 3 &, 1]]
```

Which is essentially just the inner part of Mr. Wizards solution. Personally I prefer my first, if only because I so rarely get to use `LengthWhile` for anything constructive.

Comment: This appears to be the same approach I took but rephrased to use `LengthWhile` instead of `Select`.  I prefer `Select` because of the ability to return multiple matches.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Thanks for the correction. My notion was that getting the value of an element in a list when you have the index is trivial, but it doesn't hurt to add.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Also, while I understand a preference for `Select` in cases where you want all matches, it seems detrimental to this case which is specifically targeted at a first find, and therefore benefits from a short circuit and therefore a loop construct.

Comment: `Select` *has* the short-circuit behavior.  That's the nice thing about it: you can easily go either way.