# Working with calculations that depend on the previous value in a list

Tags: list-manipulation, functional-style

I'm trying to make calculations on a list that depend on the previous value.
In my case I'm doing event detection - detecting the point where a value rises above some threshold for the first time

e.g.

```
list[t]=SomeFunction[list[t-1] ];
```

A perfect general example would be calculating a fibonacci number non-recursively.

```
fib[0]=0
fib[1]=1
fib[n]= fib[n-1]+fib[n-2]
```

If my function just took the value at `t` I could simply use `Map`. But I need
to work with the value at `t-1`.

What's the right (functional/mathematica) way to do this? I'm sure there's a way built into mathematica
for this, I'm just not finding it in the documentation.

```
stream = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1};
stream[[6]] > 5 &&  stream[[5]] <= 5
```

Update: Expanding from my concrete example a bit. There are many algorithms
and formula, which rely on e.g. the previous or n-1 values in their calculation.

Map is a very simple way to transform a list by a function. Is there an equivalent, elegant, method to do the same where the function may need previous (or n-1, neighbouring) values?

A perfect general example would be calculating a fibonacci number non-recursively.

```
fib[0]=0
fib[1]=1
fib[n]= fib[n-1]+fib[n-2]
```

Answer (score 3):

Many ways (for example `MapIndexed[]`) but you may have some fun using for example  @Leonid's implementation of `FoldWhile[]` [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/19105/193)

```
stream = {0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1}; 
FoldWhile[#2 &, ! (#1 <= 5 && #2 > 5) &, 0, stream]
(* 5 *)
```

Here is how it works:

```
Grid @@@ Reap@
  FoldWhile[(Sow[{"Current", #2, " ", "Previous", #1}]; #2) &, ! (#1 <= 5 && #2 > 5) &, 18, stream]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps

```
stream = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1};

LengthWhile[stream, # <= 5 &]
(* 5 *)
TakeWhile[stream, # <= 5 &]
(* {1,2,3,4,5} *)
```

or

```
First[Split[stream , #1 < 5 &]]
(* {1,2,3,4,5} *)
Length@First@Split[stream , #1 < 5 &]
(* 5 *)
```

or

```
i = 1; While[stream[[i]] < 5, i++]; i
(* 5 *)
i = 1; While[stream[[i]] < 5, i++]; stream[[;; i]]
(* {1,2,3,4,5} *)
```

or

```
(* foo @@@ Transpose[{Most@stream , Rest@stream}] *)
Boole[# <= 5 < #2] & @@@ Transpose[{Most@stream , Rest@stream}]
(* {0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0} *)
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what it is you are trying to do, but presumably
    list = foo /@ RotateRight[list]
is something like what you want?!

The most general solution involves the function `ListConvolve[]` which you should look up (the documentation gives you better examples than the ones I can come up with without knowing what it is you want to do). You want the second last usage (replacing `Plus` and `Times` with functions of your own).

Comment: Aside from a serious typo that's rather a comment than an answer. Why don't you show the output of your construction?

Comment: That's essentially the same as Map. Another way to phrase what I'm looking for would be Mapping a list, which allows my function to look up other values in the list, rather than just the value it's working on.

Comment: `RotateRight` has the effect of looking up an adjacent value. `RotateLeft` would look up the value from the other side. Do you want more general lookup?