# Nested If statement with unevaluated arguments

Tags: evaluation, hold, expression-test

I have a list of boolean functions `{f1, f2, f3, ...}` that take a value and return `True` or
    `False`. They are used to check whether the value meets certain conditions.

I need to run construct a nested `If` statement that for an arbitrary value sequentially evaluates the boolean functions above and returns `True` if all functions return `True`, and `False` otherwise :

```
If[f1[#],
  If[f2[#],
    If[f3[#],
      True,
      False],
    False],
  False]
```

It is important that this evaluation is *sequetial*, so that `f1` is evaluated before `f2`, `f2` before `f3` etc.; and that as soon as any of the functions returns `False`, the entire evaluation stops. This is necessary because each evaluation is time-consuming, and I don't want to evaluate any other functions once one of them returns `False`.

I wrote the following function to generate the nested if statement:

```
 NestedIf[conds_] := Function[d, Fold[If[#2[d], #1, False] &, True, Reverse@conds]];
```

And use it within `Select` statement to pick out the values from my dataset that meet *all* of the conditions `f1`,`f2`,`f3`, etc.:

```
Select[data, NestedIf[{f1, f2, f3}]]
```

However, the problem with this function is that once I pass it a value, it *first* evaluates all conditions and only *then* inserts them into the nested `If` structure. So I get no time savings.

I tried using `SetAttributes[NestedIf,HoldAll]`, but that did not help because the arguments are still evaluated first.

How can I prevent the arguments from being evaluated prematurely?

P.S. `AllTrue` command does something very similar to what I want, by sequentially checking if all values in a list satisfies one test. What I need is to test whether one value satisfies a list of tests.

P.P.S. Several people have suggested using `And` for sequential evaluation. Unfortunately the problem is that all the arguments ends up being evaluated *before* `And` begins sequential evaluation. For example, try running this:

```
 f1[x_] := (Print["First"]; x > 10);
 f2[x_] := (Print["Second"]; x > 20);

 And[Through[{f1, f2}[#]]] & @ 5
```

The output will be:

```
 First
 Second
 {False, False}
```

So *both* arguments are evaluated *before* they are passed to `And`, and I'm trying to find a way to prevent that.

Comment: See `Which[]` and `AllTrue[]` and `And[]`.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork, I know about `AllTrue`, but it solves a somewhat different problem (one test for a list of values, instead of a list of tests for one value). `Which` doesn't seem to allow for sequential evaluation of tests based on the results of previous tests, and `And` evaluates all tests at the same time rather than sequentially.

Comment: [FoldWhile](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/19102/193)?

Comment: `And` will evaluate its arguments sequentially, returning `False` as soon as any argument is `False`.

Comment: `And[# > 5 & @ #, # < 7 & @ #] & @ 6` *True* and `And[# > 5 & @ #, # < 7 & @ #, # < 4 & @ #] & @ 6` *False*.

Comment: `niF[conds__] := Function[x, And @@ Through@{conds}@x, Listable]`?

Comment: "And evaluates all tests at the same time rather than sequentially" <-- This is not correct.  There's no parallel evaluation.  Arguments are checked one by one until one returns False or until all are done.

Comment: @SimonWoods, @Szabolcs, @kguler To clarify what I mean, the problem is not that `And` itself doesn't evaluate arguments sequentially, but that by the time it starts sequential evaluation, all arguments have already been evaluated. `Through@{conds}@x` evaluates all arguments before passing them to `And`

Comment: Re your update: the correct way to use `And` is `And[arg1, arg2, arg3]` and not `And[{arg1, arg2, arg2}]`.  Observe:  `And[Print[1]; False,  Print[2]; False]`, more conveniently written as `(Print[1]; False) && (Print[2]; False)`.  The second argument never gets evaluated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to construct your desired expression without unwanted evaluation of its constituent parts.  Here is one approach to do that:

```
makeTest[{tests__}] := Replace[And[tests] &, fn_ :> fn[#], {2}]
```

This works because the surrounding [`Function`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Function.html) prevents evaluation before and after the [`Replace`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Replace.html) operation.

Example:

```
f1[x_] := (Print["First"]; x > 10);
f2[x_] := (Print["Second"]; x > 20);

myTest = makeTest[{f1, f2}]
```

> ```
> f1[#1] && f2[#1] &
> ```

Use `myTest` as needed.

---

Another method alluded to in the comments is to use `Fold` primarily.  I shall combine this with a SubValues definition (see: [Define parameterized function](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7999/121)):

```
testMulti[tests_List][expr_] := Fold[# && #2[expr] &, True, tests]

testMulti[{f1, f2}][7]
```

> First
>
> ```
> False
> ```

Also:

```
Block[{Print},
  Range[15, 25] ~Select~ testMulti[{f1, f2}]
]
```

> ```
> {21, 22, 23, 24, 25}
> ```

The [`Block`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Block.html) is just to keep `Print` from firing in this example.

Comment: This is incredible!

Comment: @verse  Thanks, and I'm glad I could help.