# Recursive "InverseFactorial" Function

Tags: recursion, functional-style

I am attempting to write a general function that can take any number and back calculate to see if it is the factorial of a smaller number. The easiest and quickest way to do this is to take the initial, larger number and divide by consecutive integers starting at `2`, until the dividend is equal to the divisor (so the quotient is `1`). E.g.

```
120/2 = 60;
60/3 = 20;
20/4 = 5;
5/5 = 1;
```

Therefore, `5! = 120`

I attempted to use `Table`, but then realized `Table` will just iterate thru without altering the value of the dividend. I need both my divisor and dividend to change: I need the dividend to take the value of the previous quotient, and I need the divisor to increase by one after each evaluation. I am not really sure how to fix this, here's my most recent attempt:

```
Clear@inverseFactorial
inverseFactorial[num_Integer, c_] := Block[{list},

list = NestWhileList[(#/c) &, num, {# == c} &];

Length@list+1(*since we started at 2 the length of the list will be one off the actual value to be 'factorialized'*)]
```

However, it's not working the way I want to, but it's also not showing me any errors when it evaluates. Like most *Mathematica* users, I do functional programming and these problems which clearly involve some kind of loop are particularly difficult when doing things like this. I'm just interested if there is in fact a way, because this is the way I actually think about the problem.

Comment: This might not be the best approach if the number is large. See [this usenet post](http://mathforum.org/kb/message.jspa?messageID=4688516) for some code and links.

Comment: This is a job for FoldWhile https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/19102/foldwhile-and-foldwhilelist

Answer (score 3):

Try to use

> InverseFunction[Gamma]
>
> (Gamma^(-1))[24]
>
> 5

Remembering that $n!=\Gamma[n+1]$ you have inverse factorial of $24$ as $5-1=4$

Comment: Yes, I thought about using the Gamma function, but felt like that would've been cheating in some sense, based on what I was looking to get out of this exercise

Answer (score 3):

You can use `` Reduce`FactorialInverse ``:

```
Reduce`FactorialInverse[6001!]
```

> {6001}

Comment: I've never used these context tick marks before. What is its purpose? The documentation isn't clear

Comment: @Lame, these are *undocumented* functions. Because of that, there are no guarantees that they will keep on working in future versions.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is what you want

```
n = 5;
FoldList[Divide, n!, Range[2, n - 1]]
```

> {120, 60, 20, 5}

```
 n = 6;
 FoldList[Divide, n!, Range[2, n - 1]]
```

> {720, 360, 120, 30, 6}

Answer (score 0):

You are not incrementing your `c` and the condition `# == c` is wrong for two reasons, `NestWhile` loops while the conditions is true, so it would stop immediately, and if you change it on `# != c` it would loop infinetely at non factorial numbers. And actually it wouldn't be off by one if you start with `c = 2`, quite the opposite. Hear:

```
inverseFactorial[num_Integer,c_:2]:=
 Length@NestWhileList[Apply[{#1/#2,#2+1}&],{num,c},Apply[GreaterEqual]]
```

Comment: Nice, except I think `inverseFactorial[123]` should return an error. Perhaps `With[{res = NestWhile[Apply[{#1/#2, #2 + 1} &], {num, c}, Apply[GreaterEqual]]}, res[[2]] - 1 /; res[[1]] == 1]`?

Answer (score 0):

With what's available, I would do the following one-liner:

```
inverseFactorial[n_] :=
 Module[{i = 1, res}, res = NestWhile[#/++i &, n, # > 1 &]; 
  If[res == 1, i, False]]
```