# When will $1^2+2^2+3^2+5^2+7^2+11^2+\cdots\cdots + p^2$ (where $p$ is prime) be greater than $10^{10}$?

Tags: functional-style

How to solve the problem:

> When will $1^2+2^2+3^2+5^2+7^2+11^2+13^2+\cdots\cdots + p^2$ (where every base and $p$ are prime, except the base of the first term $1$) be greater than $10^{10}$? (Namely, solve for such smallest $p$)

I can come up with several ugly solutions which are not quite satisfying for me. And also this can be easily written by an explicit loop, but I think it should be the last strategy to use. Hmm... I think if there's a `Fold`-family function that similar to `TakeWhile`, called `FoldWhile`, which can iteratively `Fold` until some condition is satisfied/unsatisfied at the moment, then it may probably be the most ideal solution. However, there's no such function.

Comment: By "over", do you mean "be greater than"?

Comment: @MichaelE2 Oh yes, greater than. i.e., $>$

Comment: Is this a question from the Euler Project?

Comment: @halirutan I don't remember... It is a question from my self notes of MMA 2 years ago.. But I did solve some Project Euler problems in the past, so I guess the problem is less or more motivated by PE problems but suggested by me.

Comment: @Kuba As Micheal E2 pointed out, a $2^2$ appears so I was wrong and your were right!

Comment: Just to clarify, the sum is over $1$ plus the primes up to some prime $p$, yes?  Or is it over odd integers, plus $2$, up to some odd prime $p$?

Comment: @MichaelE2 Oh gosh.. I didn't make clear mention at this crucial detail.. See my edit.

Comment: Update: I just found a post discussing [FoldWhile](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/19102/foldwhile-and-foldwhilelist)

Comment: A bit off topic, but one can get a decent approximation from `int[k_?NumberQ] := 
 NIntegrate[n^2*(Log[n] + Log[Log[n]] - 1)^2, {n, 1, k}]
FindRoot[int[k] == 10^10, {k, 100}]`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you mentioned `TakeWhile` and `FoldWhile`, let me first give you a one-line with `NestWhile`:

```
NestWhile[With[{c=First[#]+1,s=Last[#]},{c,s+Prime[c]^2}]&,{1,1},#[[2]]<10^10&]
(* {823, 10025552438} *)
```

What follows is my original answer that shows binary search which is not the most appropriate thing in this situation but still very fast.
Consider the vector `{a,b,c}` and note that the dot-product of it with itself is `a^2+b^2+c^2`. This naturally leads to a simple function that calculates your sum of prime squares:

```
f[n_] := #.# &[Prime[Range[n]]]
```

A quick check shows that an upper bound is `n=1000`. Now, implement a quick binary search which will converge fast:

```
search[_, _, lo_, hi_] := {lo + 1, Prime[lo + 1]} /; hi - lo <= 1;
search[f_, goal_, lo_, hi_] := With[{cent = Round[(hi + lo)/2]},
  If[f[cent] > goal,
   search[f, goal, lo, cent],
   search[f, goal, cent, hi]
   ]
  ]
```

It starts with a lower and upper bound and always divides this range.

```
search[f, 10^10, 10, 1000] // AbsoluteTiming
(* {0.00287, {823, 6323}} *)
```

So the answer is $2^2+3^2\ldots+p_{823}^2$. **Note**, that I violated your definition since I'm only summing real primes and don't include the 1. The answer is still correct though :) 
Quick check

```
f[823]
(* 10025552442 *)
```

and

```
f[822]
(* 9985572113 *)
```

seems correct. You should note that it only took exactly 10 steps. You can show this by introducing a step-variable that is incremented.

Comment: The recursion method is pedagogical!

Answer (score 4):

Is that it or did I make a silly mistake?

```
n = 0;
sum = 1; (*for 1^1*)
While[
 sum < 10^10,
 sum += Prime[++n]^2
]

sum          (*10025552443*)
n            (*823*)
Prime[n]     (*6323*)
```

Comment: Kuba, since $1^2$ appears in the sum I think it is only about summing all squares of _odd_ numbers up to the $n$th prime. However, the question is rather ambiguous...

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher ah, that makes more sense

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher after Michael's comment I undeleted it :)

Comment: @Kuba Thanks. Is using `While` the almost most proper way in this case? In MMA literature, it seems that to use explicit loop is not so preferred in most cases.

Answer (score 3):

you can try this:

```
For[{s = 1, n = 1}, s < 10^10, n++, s = s + Prime[n]^2]; {Prime[n - 1],s}
```

Answer (score 2):

A [`Lazy`](https://github.com/sblom/mathematica-lazy) approach,

```
sqPrimesLazy = Map[{1, Prime[#]^2} &, Lazy[Integers]];
sqPrimesSumLazy = FoldList[Plus, {0, 1}, sqPrimesLazy];
Select[sqPrimesSumLazy, #[[2]] > 10^10 &] // First
```

> {823, 10025552443}

Subsequently, the value of `p` can be obtained as `Prime[823] = 6323`

Check [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/838/functional-style-using-lazy-lists) post for more on Lazy evaluation in MMA.

Answer (score 1):

```
NestWhile[{#[[1]] + Prime[#[[2]]]^2, ++(#[[2]]), Prime[#[[2]]]} &, {1,
     1, 1}, #[[1]] < 10^10 &]

(*   {10025552443, 824, 6323}   *)
```

Comment: This `Sum[Prime[i]^2, {i, 823}]` tells me that you have not found the smallest p.

Comment: 824 summands, but Prime[i] up to i== 823, p==6323, 1+Sum... ==10025552443

Comment: Why don't you add a line of text then that says so instead of simply posting a line of code? Furthermore and more importantly, you should get rid of the `++#[[2]]` because this is semantically wrong. It is the reason why your code throws so many error messages. You cannot do `++4` because the operand of `++` needs to be a variable.

Comment: Is collecting information within a multiple list (e.g., your `{1,1,1}`) a commonly seen way used by people? I feel that long times later we would have chance forget the meanings (and order) of what `{1,1,1}` represents.

Comment: With MMA Version 8.0  `++u[[2]]` works fine and does not produce any error messages. `++4`of course does not work.