# Survival Probability for Random Walks

Tags: functions, probability-or-statistics, random, distributions, random-process

The Survival Probability for a walker starting at the origin is defined as the probability that the walker stays positive through n steps. Thanks to the Sparre-Andersen Theorem I know this PDF is given by

```
Plot[Binomial[2 n, n]*2^(-2 n), {n, 0, 100}]
```

However, I want to validate this empirically.

My attempt to validate this for `n=100`:

```
FoldList[
  If[#2 < 0, 0, #1 + #2] &, 
  Prepend[Accumulate[RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 1], 100]], 0]]
```

I want`FoldList` to stop if `#2 < 0` evaluates to `True`, not just substitute in 0.

Comment: Will, are you attempting to empirically show that the probability for survival when `n=100` is `Binomial[2 (100), (100)]*2^(-2 (100))`? So repeatedly run, and count the times you survive through 100 steps? If so, are you trying to "While" out of the FoldList to save CPU cycles? Not clear to me...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Something seems odd to me about your code.  You are summing twice, once with [`Accumulate`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Accumulate.html) and once with [`FoldList`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FoldList.html).  If this is really what you want then you could use:

```
SeedRandom[26]
sum = Prepend[Accumulate[RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 1], 100]], 0];

TakeWhile[sum, NonNegative] // Accumulate
```

> ```
> 8
>
> {0, 1.10708, 1.23211, 2.28173, 3.30295, 4.05759, 5.26123, 6.62964}
> ```

This is equivalent to your [`FoldList`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FoldList.html) construct up to the appropriate point:

```
FoldList[If[#2 < 0, 0, #1 + #2] &, sum]
```

> ```
> {0, 1.10708, 1.23211, 2.28173, 3.30295, 4.05759, 5.26123, 6.62964, 0, ...
> ```

Perhaps you meant to only sum once.  In that case `TakeWhile[sum, NonNegative]` is a direct solution but also sub-optimal as it does not provide early exit behavior, which I suspect is what you're actually after here.  It is not clear to me if you need the cumulative sum (walk) itself or only its length; if the latter consider this:

```
SeedRandom[26]
dist = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 1], 100];

Module[{i = 0},
  Fold[If[# < 0, Return[i, Fold], i++; # + #2] &, 0, dist]
]
```

> ```
> 8
> ```

Comment: The `ListLinePlot` of your bottom answer is much closer to the binomial than the one in mine. I think you have it right :)

Answer (score 7):

We can do this using an implementation of `FoldWhileList`.

First, implement `FoldWhileList` using [this great answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/19105/57593).

```
FoldWhileList[f_, test_, start_, secargs_List] := 
 Module[{tag}, 
  If[# === {}, {start}, Prepend[First@#, start]] &@
   Reap[Fold[If[test[##], Sow[f[##], tag], Return[Null, Fold]] &, 
      start, secargs], _, #2 &][[2]]]
```

Now we simply run this using the test `#2 >= 0` (note that the implementation of `NestWhile` breaks when `test` stops evaluating `True` - our implementation of `FoldWhileList` also does this, therefore we invert the test you originally used.

```
FoldWhileList[Plus, #2 >= 0 &, 0, 
 Prepend[Accumulate[RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 1], 100]], 0]]
```

We can now estimate your PDF:

[image: pdf estimate]

and overlay it over the original plot also:

[image: overlaid plots]

which doesn't seem like a great match - perhaps there's an issue with your original code, as [this answer surmises](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/189088/57593).

Answer (score 5):

It seems to me that this is a problem to which `Catch` and `Throw` can be usefully applied.

```
SeedRandom[1];
Module[{result = {0}, s},
  Catch[
    Fold[
      If[#2 < 0, Throw[Null], result = {result, s = #1 + #2}; s] &,
      0,
      Accumulate[RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 1], 100]]]];
  result // Flatten]
```

[image: result]

Answer (score 3):

How about the following brute force approach:

```
n = 100;
SeedRandom[12345];
nsim = 1000000;
Total[Table[If[Min[Accumulate[RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 1], n]]] <= 0, 0, 1],
    {i, nsim}]]/nsim // N
(* 0.056092 *)
Binomial[2 n, n] 2^(-2 n) // N
(* 0.0563485 *)
```

To get all of the values from 1 to 100 "simultaneously"...

```
SeedRandom[12345];
nsim = 100000;
n = 100;
z = ConstantArray[0, n];
Do[
 x = Accumulate[RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 1], n]];
 i = Flatten[Position[x, _?NonPositive]];
 If[Length[i] > 0, If[i[[1]] > 1, z[[1 ;; i[[1]] - 1]] = z[[1 ;; i[[1]] - 1]] + 1], z = z + 1],
 {j, nsim}]
z = z/nsim;
ListPlot[{z, Table[Binomial[2 j, j] 2^(-2 j), {j, n}]}, PlotRange -> All, ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image: Simulation and exact formula]

Answer (score 2):

Count number of steps before random walk value either goes negative or over $m$ steps are already taken, for $n$ walks. Then count amount of last successful steps on each integer bin, reverse it, accumulate these values (essentially extend last nonnegative value backwards to every value before it), reverse it again to get the original order, drop the extra value that counted paths that continued over $m$ steps and calculate probabilities:

```
With[{n = 5000, m = 100}, 
 Table[First@
         NestWhile[# + {1, RandomVariate@NormalDistribution[]} &,
                   {-1, 0}, Last@# >= 0 && First@# <= m &], n] // 
       BinCounts[#, {1, Max@# + 1, 1}] & // Reverse // Accumulate // 
    Reverse // Most@#/n & // 
  ListPlot[{#, Table[Binomial[2 j, j] 2^(-2 j), {j, m}]}, 
    PlotRange -> All] &]
```

[image]