# How does Return work?

Tags: function-construction, evaluation, core-language, faq

It is not completely clear to me how `Return[]` works.

The documentation says:

> `Return[expr]` returns the value expr from a function.

But in *Mathematica* it is not clear where are the boundaries of a "function" defined using patterns and `Set(Delayed)`.  The system simply applies replacement rules until there's nothing to change anymore.

Consider these examples:

```
a := (Module[{}, Return[0]; 1]; 2)    
a
(* 0 *)
```

It is not completely clear to me why `Return` breaks out from `a`, and not from `Module` or one of the `CompoundExpression`.

The following doesn't work, and simply returns the `Return` expression. It reminds me a bit of how `Unevaluated` is handled.

```
(Module[{}, Return[0]; 1]; 2)
(* Return[0] *)
```

If we add another layer of definitions, the effect of `Return` will stop there:

```
b := (a; 3)
(* 3 *)
```

Why do these three inputs give different results?  What is the general rule for deciding where `Return` breaks out to precisely?

The answer lies somewhere in fully understanding the evaluation process.

Would someone care to elucidate this point, perhaps with pointers to the parts of the documentation which make this clear?

Comment: Be aware that the behavior of `Return` has [changed from one version to another.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7934354/618728) I usually try to avoid using it myself.

Comment: @Mr.W Wow, if its behaviour changes even between minor versions, than indeed it's better avoided!

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, Szabolcs Personally I don't consider this particular observation as a strong evidence against using `Return`, since it is just the *addition* of new functionality (`Fold`), and no old code is broken (see also my commens below my answer).

Comment: @Leonid I seem to recall at least one other case, on Mathgroup I suppose, where Return behaved differently per version.  Does that sound unfamiliar to you?  Also, I haven't given this a lot of thought but couldn't the change re: Fold break existing v7 code?  It would probably be an odd use of Return, but not as odd a mutable PatternTest functions... ;-)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Well I guess one *can* construct an example of code that would be "broken" in a new version, but I have a hard time imagining that it would be less perverse than the method you mentioned (which, actually, I *did* use constructively several times).

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The exhaustive answer to this has been given in [this](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/browse_thread/thread/12419727c096caad) thread (if you combine several answers there. The mentioned thread is also a generally recommended read for more information on this - at least one I am aware of). I will first reproduce here those bits of my answer from there which were correct.

There are two possible outcomes for any expression wrapped in `Return`: either it is inside some lexical  (or dynamic) scoping construct for which the action of `Return` is defined - and then the presence of `Return` will lead to  breaking-out-of-the-scoping-construct procedure, or it is not and then it is just a symbolic expression like any other.  After breaking out of the scoping costruct (or just evaluation if it was not inside any scoping construct), `Return` gets discarded only if it was called from within the r.h.s. of a user-defined rule. Here is an example:

```
In[1]:= 
Clear[a,b,c]; 
c=(Return[a];3) 

Out[1]= Return[a] 

In[2]:= b:=(Return[a];3) 
In[3]:= b 
Out[3]= a
```

This behavior can be explained by consulting the exact rules of the evaluation procedure. Lacking a more up-to-date account, I cite here David Withoff's "Mathematica internals" of 1992: The very last step of the evaluation loop is (Chapter 3 - evaluation, p. 7, on the bottom): "Discard the head `Return`, if present, for expressions generated through application of user-defined rules."

Thus, when you use `SetDelayed`, you create a user-defined delayed rule and then `Return` is discarded, while for "direct" evaluation like

```
In[4]:= Return[a] 
Out[4]= Return[a]
```

it is not. But, in

```
In[5]:= 
ClearAll[a,c];
a:=Return[c];
a

Out[7]= c
```

it is, and `Return` is discarded, even though there was no scoping construct to break out of. The same happens in your example where `Module` is wrapped around - `Return` breaks out of `Module` all right, but is not discarded since `Module` was not the r.h.s of any user-defined rule.

Here are the best descriptions of how `Return` works that I am aware of, due to Alan Hayes (can be found in [this](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/browse_thread/thread/e8ff8ba75a88f547) MathGroup thread) :

"In view of the recent thread on Holding Arguments in a Second Argument List 
the following notes on `Return` may be of interest:

- If `Return[x]` is generated as a value in  `Do` or `Scan` then  x is immediately 
  returned;
- If  `Return[x]` is generated as an entry in `CompoundExpression` or as a value 
  of the body of a `While` or `For` loop then  `Return[x]` (not `x`) is immediately 
  returned;
- If  `Return[x]`  is generated as the value of a user-defined function then the 
  function returns  `x` (not `Return[x]`)
- Otherwise `Return[x]` behaves as a ordinary expression. 
  "

These "empirical" rules agree with the statement found in the Withoff's report, the latter making the former sound somewhat less magical.

It is also good to remember that `Return` has a second optional argument, which tells it from which surrounding scoping construct to break out:

```
In[242]:= (Module[{}, Return[0, CompoundExpression]]; 2)
Out[242]= 0
```

but

```
In[243]:= (Module[{}, (Return[0, CompoundExpression]; 0)]; 2)
Out[243]= 2
```

In your last example, the outer `CompoundExpression` defined in `b` in dynamically rather than lexically scoped (relative to the stuff defined in `a`), and therefore this won't work (in other words, your last result is also as expected).

Comment: Note that I edited my original answer quite a bit. My answer from the Mathgroup thread was partially misleading, so I modified some parts of it.

Comment: Let me see if I got it right: 1. `Module`/`Block`/etc. do *not* modify the handling of `Return` (i.e. they're just the same as `CompoundExpression`: the rest of the `CompoundExpression` is ignored and `Return[value]` is returned immediately).  2. `Do` and `Scan` do behave specially, as they return `value` and not `Return[value]`.  3. `Return[value]` is always replaced by `value` if it is the result of the application of a delayed-type replacement rule (`:=`), but not in the case of a normal replacement rule (`=`) ...

Comment: ... Another interesting point that I didn't expect is the difference between `:=` and `=`.  Try `a := Return[0]` and `b = Return[0]`.  The two behave differently, but their `OwnValues` look *exactly* the same (both use `:>`).  `Information` does show us if `:=` or `=` was used in the definition though.  I was not aware that there existed a difference in the handling of `:=` and `=` even *after* the definition was made ...

Comment: ... finally, is [this part of your book](http://www.mathprogramming-intro.org/book/node120.html) correct?  It says: "If we use Return[] however, we will also break from the entire localizing construct which encloses the loop (if there are nested localizing constructs, we break *from the innermost one only*)." (emphasis by me).  It doesn't appear to be the case that `Return` breaks from the innermost only.  Instead where it breaks to seems to be determined by the user-defined delayed rules (`:=`).  Is this correct?

Comment: @Szabolcs Your comments do indicate that I did not put enough effort in my answer, which is true - I mostly compiled it the sources I knew :). Ok, for your first comment: all correct, but the reason for direct assignment is not that this is *not* a replacement rule, but that its r.h.s. was evaluated immediately and *that* evaluation was not caused by an existing replacement rule. Consider, for example: `ClearAll[a, b, c];a = b;b = Return[c];a` - you get plain `c` at the end, even though all rules were immediate - but here `Return[c]` from `b` *was* a result of evaluation of the rule for `a`

Comment: @Szabolcs as for my book, the statement was correct I think (although admittedly I was not aware of all this stuff yet when writing it): as I mentioned in this answer, there are 2 distinct stages (or at least this is my picture of it): 1. Breaking out of a scoping construct (and this is what my book statement was about), and 2: deciding whether or not to discard `Return` head - this is where the presence or absence of user-defined rules matters.

Comment: Yes, you are right.  For some reason I thought that after `a = Return[0]` evaluating `a` would return `Return[0]` which is not the case.  It return `0`.  So there's no difference between `:=` and `=` after the definition has been made after all.  Some more comments on `Return`: 1. `f[Return[0,f]]` does not behave the same way as `Module[{}, Return[0,Module]]` (or `Fold` or apparently any other builtin from where it might make sense to break out).  The second argument of `Return` is not documented in M8 though, so perhaps it deprecated. 2. Just a note that `Return` will return from a `Dialog[]`

Comment: To clarify: Based on the [description](http://www.mathprogramming-intro.org/book/node120.html) in your book, I constructed `x = Module[{}, Module[{}, While[True, Return[0]]; 1]; 2]`  It returns 0, not 2, i.e. it breaks from both `Module`s, not only the innermost one, as the book states.  `Do`, however, is different from `While`: it breaks from the `Module` and not only from `Do`, and it breaks from the innermost `Module` only: `x = Module[{}, Module[{}, Do[Return[0], {10}]; 1]; 2]`.  `For` behaves like `While`, not like `Do` (i.e. it's not special).  Can you verify again please?

Comment: See Mr.Wizard's comment above, `Return` seems to be unreliable, and it sbehaviour has changed even between minor versions.  Most likely it was different at the time you wrote the book than in 8.0.4.

Comment: @Szabolcs Ok, so: First, it seems that `Return` with a second argument only works for certain enclosing functions, not just any arbitrary `f`. Second, while `Return` with two arguments isn't documented, it is unlikely to go away and is "semi-officially" endorsed (see e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7446032/searching-from-the-end-of-a-list-in-mathematica/7446843#7446843), so I'd consider it safe to use. Next: the case you constructed:  `x = Module[{}, Module[{}, While[True, Return[0]]; 1]; 2]` - here it *appears* that `Return` breaks from both `Module` (it does), but the mechanism is ..

Comment: @Szabolcs ...different from what it may look. It first only breaks from the innermost one. But then, `Return` appears inside the `CompoundExpression` in the outer (since `Return` is not discarded at that stage), then it quits the outer `Module` too. Consider e.g. this:`Module[{}, q@Module[{}, While[True, Return[0]]; 1]; 2]`, which only breaks from the inner-most one, since the content of outer `Module` now is `(q[Return[0]];2)`, and since `Return` is not the top-level element of `CompoundExpression`, it is ignored by it (it does not even come to `Module`). Regardless of the explanation, ...

Comment: @Szabolcs this looks like a wrong behavior to me, but this sheds some light on how the breaking-out mechanism is implemented: any of the constructs (such as `CompoundExpression`, `Module`, etc) will stop upon hitting `Return`, and return this `Return` - very simple idea. As for `Do`, it does not break from anything except itself (because `Do` is a dynamic scoping construct), just as `Scan` (because `Scan` has a special semantics regarding `Return`, which is intended). As to the version differences, it looks like `Fold` was added to a list of "`Return`-aware" constructs recently, but this ...

Comment: @Szabolcs does not make `Return` generally unreliable IMO (I don't have any other evidence of version inconsistencies regarding `Return`, and in any case the addition of `Fold` does not break any old code, just adds new possibilities). Your observation about the `Dialog` is nice.

Comment: @Szabolcs Upon some reflection - you were right that my statement in the book regarding nested `Module`-s wasn't correct - `Return` does break from all of them (as we discussed). For example, this `f[x_] := Module[{y = x}, Module[{}, Return[y]; 1]; 2]; f[3]` returns `3`, not `2`. I actually think that this behavior is erratic. And the fix is rather unexpected (to me anyways): `f[x_] := Module[{y = x}, Module[{}, Return[y, Module]; 1]; 2]; f[3]` returns `2`. But you know what - I don't feel particularly guilty - the rules for `Return` are very peculiar (to say the least), and barely documented.

Comment: An alternative fix here would be `catchReturn[x_] := x; f[x_] := Module[{y = x}, catchReturn@Module[{}, Return[y]; 1]; 2];`. Here `f[3]` also evaluates to 2

Comment: We can also use the anonymous function `If[Head[#] === Return, #[[1]], #] &` (of course?).

Comment: @JacobAkkerboom Sure, this will work, but the whole point is that one shouldn't be bothered to use such extra things, since it is quite easy to forget using them.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin that makes sense. I just wanted to give an alternative to `Return` with 2 arguments :).