# How to exit from the innermost enclosing pure function?

Tags: programming, functions, function-construction, evaluation

Here is what I tried to do:

```
Scan[Function[x,
  Scan[Function[y,
    If[y == 2, Return[]];
    (* Do something useful *) Print[y]],
   x]],
 {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}}]
```

My intention was that the `Return[]` exited from the innermost enclosing pure function (having the parameter `y`). Instead, it terminated execution of the innermost enclosing `Scan` and proceeded to the next iteration of the outermost `Scan`.

```
1 4 5 6
```

The documentation for [`Return`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Return.html) says:

> `Return` exits only the innermost construct in which it is invoked

I do not see why the innermost `Scan` is considered the innermost enclosing construct here. `If`, `CompoundExpression` and `Function` look like more inner constructs.

---

*Question 1:* Could you give a more clear explanation of what precisely `Return` does?

---

After I realized that `Return` does not do what I want here, I looked for workaround, and found several ones:

**(a)** I can restructure the body of the innermost pure function:

```
Scan[Function[x,
  Scan[Function[y,
    If[y != 2,
     (* Do something useful *) Print[y]]
    ],
   x]],
 {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}}]
```

In this case it looks straighforward, but becomes messy if I have more nested control flow operators and multiple points where I might need to exit.

**(b)** I can use infamous `Label` and `Goto` constructs:

```
Scan[Function[x,
  Scan[Function[y,
    Module[{exit},
     If[y == 2, Goto[exit]];
     (* Do something useful *) Print[y];
     Label[exit];
     ]], 
    x]],
 {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}}]
```

**(c)** I can use `Throw` and `Catch` constructs:

```
Scan[Function[x,
  Scan[Function[y,
    Module[{exit},
     Catch[
      If[y == 2, Throw[Null, exit]];
      (* Do something useful *) Print[y],
      exit]]],
   x]],
 {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}}]
```

---

*Question 2:* Which of them would you prefer? Or can you suggest a better way to do this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can specify the evaluation of which construct should be stopped by `Return` by providing the second argument (*undocumented?*). For example,

```
Scan[Function[x,
  Module[{},
   Print[x];
   Return[$Failed, Module];
   Print[-x]]],
 {1, 2, 3}]
```

or

```
Scan[Function[x,
  Print[x];
  Return[$Failed, CompoundExpression];
  Print[-x]],
 {1, 2, 3}]
```

Comment: It isn't documented under [`Return`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Return.html) but it is here: [`Return::nofunc`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/message/Break/nofunc.html)

Answer (score 7):

It's hard to reply without larger context, but if you are not restricted to use pure functions, then one option would be to use the pattern-defined overloaded function instead:

```
ClearAll[fun];
fun[2] := Null;
fun[x_] := ((*Do something useful*)Print[x])
```

Then, you just write:

```
Scan[Function[x, Scan[fun, x]], {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}}]
```

In fact, you can as well define `fun` at run-time, if you need.

As to `Return`, I can recommend [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/29353/how-does-return-work), and particularly [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/6815/what-can-be-used-as-the-second-argument-to-return-on-your-own-functions) discussions for more details on how it works.

Answer (score 2):

I would use `Catch` and `Throw` if pressed to choose, without the 'exit' :

```
Scan[Function[x,
  Scan[Function[y,
    Catch[If[y == 2, Throw[Null]];
     (*Do something useful*) Print[y]]
    ],
   x]],
 {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}}]
```

or simply,

```
Scan[Function[x,
  Scan[Function[y,
    If[y == 2, Null,
     (*Do something useful*) Print[y]]
    ],
   x]],
 {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}}]
```