# Unexpected behavior from Return called in a Block

Tags: function-construction, core-language

I like to write functions that dispose of failure cases early, before they do the main calculation, but I don't like to write cascading `If` statements. Here is a toy example of the sort of function I mean:

```
f[x_] :=
  Block[{$TooBig},
    If[! NumericQ[x], Return[$Failed]];
    If[x > 10, Return[$TooBig]];
    x!]
f /@ {5, 11, "x"}
```

> ```
>  {120, $TooBig, $Failed}
> ```

Now suppose rather than define `f`, I would like to use a pure function, so I write

```
Block[{$TooBig},
  If[! NumericQ[#], Return[$Failed]];
  If[# > 10, Return[$TooBig]];
  #!] & /@ {5, 11, "x"}
```

> ```
> {120, Return[$TooBig], Return[$Failed]}
> ```

The pure function returns at the appropriate points for all three arguments, but in the cases where `Return` should be called, it is returned unevaluated. I did not expect this behavior. Is it a bug or have missed a something I should be aware of?

I will point out that I do know how to work around this difficulty.

```
Block[{$TooBig},
  If[! NumericQ[#], Return[$Failed, Block]];
  If[# > 10, Return[$TooBig, Block]];
  #!] & /@ {5, 11, "x"}
```

> ```
>  {120, $TooBig, $Failed}
> ```

I'm running V.10.2 on my system and don't have access to any older versions of *Mathematica*, so I don't know if this a version specific problem.

Comment: Duplicate? http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/29353/12

Comment: @Szabolcs. Sure looks like one.

Comment: Some might argue that this is bad style, or that one should really use `Throw`/`Catch`, but the behaviour you observe can actually be exploited:  `check = If[Not@NumericQ[#], Return[$Failed]] &;` then `fun[x_] :=
 Block[{},
  check[x];
  x^2
  ]`.  Suppose you have lots of functions like `fun` ([I do](https://github.com/szhorvat/IGraphM)) and you want to avoid re-typing the same sorts of argument checks.

Comment: Since it is not explicitly mentioned, Return[value, Block] solves the problem: Block[{\$TooBig}, If[! NumericQ[#], Return[\$Failed, Block]];
   If[# > 10, Return[\$TooBig, Block]];
   #!] & /@ {5, 11, "x"}

Comment: @user8074. It is most certainly explicitly mentioned.

Comment: @m_goldberg  I cannot find Return[...,Block] either in  mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/29353/12  or in MMA9 help. Where is it explicitly mentioned?

Comment: @user8074 In this question itself

Comment: @Szabolcs I'd argue that the opposite is true: using `Throw / Catch` is a bad style when `Return` (with 2 args, may be) can be used. Of course, one must know how to use it correctly, and it is not very intuitive at first.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin  Right! Now I saw it: temporary blindness :).  But it is not a duplicate: this solution is not reported elsewhere and works also on previous versions (9, for example).

Comment: @user8074 The way question is currently posed, it *is* a duplicate, because the OP was interested in the explanation of the behavior, rather than a solution (of which he was aware). But I'd agree with you that it would be more useful for the site in general, if the question was "how would I use `Return` in this case ...", and then it would not be a direct duplicate.

Comment: @user8074 Actually the answer to the other question also mentions the two-argument form of `Return`.

Comment: @Szabolcs, premitting that I fully understood Leonid's reply and agree, the two-argument form of the previous answers mentions only CompoundExpression, which is not normally used explicitly, while Block is a common language costruct. Consequently Return[..., Block] deserves an explict mention in my opinion.

Comment: @user8074 Why don't you post a question and answer it yourself? It would be quite useful.

Comment: @user8074 If you go on and ask the question  / self-answer, keep in mind that this is not specific to `Block` - the same happens also in the case of  `With` or `Module`. So, I'd rather formulate it as "how would one return from some place of the  pure function's body, using `Return`". In fact, when there is no scoping construct but one wants to return from p.f. using `Return`, a useful trick is to wrap the body of p.f. in an idle `Module[{}, ...]` or similar - which would then allow to use `Return[..., Module]`. I've been using this trick many times.