# BUG - Different Cloud vs. Desktop Return behavior in V13.1

Tags: evaluation, core-language

After install V13.1 one of my scripts get broke in my Mac. Here is the bug:

```
Module[{}, Return[1]; 2]
```

> ```
> Return[1]
> ```

When I tested in Wolfram Cloud I get the expected/old result that was `1` instead of `Return[1]`

I see it as a serious BUG, as It breaks compatibility with V13.0 and has inconsistent result between Cloud and Desktop.

It's a BUG? Should I change my code to the ugly/safe form: `Return[arg, Module]`?

[Cross post in Wolfram Community](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/2561271)

PS: This was what I call a `Pseudo Version Update Bug`, It's a bug that you believe was the version update, but It was not. The code break was not generated by the `Return`, but the inconsistence between Cloud and Desktop exists.

Comment: The same problem is happening on 13.0.0 for Linux (64-bit).

Screenshot: https://community.wolfram.com//c/portal/getImageAttachment?filename=Screenshotfrom2022-06-3023-37-25.png&userId=1682328

Comment: With versions 8.0.4 and 12.3.1 I also get `Return[1]`...

Comment: This seemingly is not a bug, see [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/171040/280).

Comment: [Related](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/127428/understanding-the-behavior-of-return-inside-function#comment344760_127434).

Comment: No @AlexeyPopkov. As you can check, Cloud and Desktop have distinct behaviors. So I still think this is a Bug.

Comment: @Murta Since in the previous questions it wasn't considered a bug, I think we may assume that it is a bug in the Cloud version.

Comment: `Module[{}, Return[1, Module]; 2]` will return 1 on 13.1 desktop.

Comment: The same behavior with `Block[{}, Return[1]; 2]` on MMA 13.0.1.

Comment: I think this question is answered exactly by the post linked above (tldr: Return is weird and should be avoided in favor of catch/throw). The question of why the cloud is not behaving the same way as desktop is a different question.  Seriously though, Return should be avoided

Comment: @JasonB. I changed the question a little bit. At the moment I don't agree that It's not a bug (and that it's a Duplicate). As you can check, the Wolfram Cloud works in the old (expected?) way.

Comment: This behavior is not new in Desktop Mathematica.

Answer (score 6):

With versions 5.2, 8.0.4 and 12.3.1 on Windows 10 x64 I get the same result:

[image: screenshot1]

[image: screenshot2]

Exactly this aspect of `Return` behavior was earlier discussed in the following thread:

- [How does Return work?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/29353/280)

In [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/171040/280) answer (from another thread) [Chris Degnen](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/363/chris-degnen) provides a link to [this](http://forums.wolfram.com/mathgroup/archive/2009/Dec/msg00329.html) 2009 year MathGroup post by Leonid Shifrin where he argues that this behavior isn't a bug:

```
My feeling is that this is not a bug.

There are two possible outcomes for any expression wrapped in Return: either
it is inside some lexical  (or dynamic) scoping construct for which the
action of Return is defined - and then Return disappears as a part of
breaking-out-of-the-scoping-construct procedure, or it is not and then it is
just a symbolic expression like any other.  It seems like neither Function
nor CompoundExpression  are  considered  by Mathematica as the scoping
constructs for which the action of Return is defined as for example for
Module, Block, With, etc.

Under this assumption, your puzzle can be reduced to a simpler one:

In[1]:=
Clear[a,b,c];
c=(Return[a];3)

Out[1]= Return[a]

In[2]:=
b:=(Return[a];3)

In[3]:= b

Out[3]= a

The latter discrepancy can be explained by consulting the exact rules of the
evaluation procedure. Lacking a more up-to-date account, I cite here David
Withoff's "Mathematica internals" of 1992:

The very last step of the evaluation loop is (Chapter 3 - evaluation, p. 7,
on the bottom):

"Discard the head Return, if present, for expressions generated through
application of user-defined rules."

Thus, when you use SetDelayed, you create user-defined delayed rule and then
Return is discarded, while for "direct" evaluation like

In[4]:= Return[a]

Out[4]= Return[a]

it is not.

At least, things seem to work as documented in Withoff's technical report.
One thing that would be nice to have is a complete list of scoping
constructs for which Return is discarded when whatever it is wrapped around
is returned from that scoping construct.

Regards,
Leonid
```

Also, a telling [comment](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/127428/understanding-the-behavior-of-return-inside-function#comment344760_127434) by Daniel Lichtblau:

> I know at least one developer who would require psychoanalysis,
> possibly forensic in nature, were he to ever again try to carefully
> consider the inner workings of `Return`. –  Daniel Lichtblau  Sep 28,
> 2016 at 19:09