# Returning a value from a Module

Tags: scoping, return-value

In the following simple example

```
MyMod := Module[{i},
  Do[
    Return[1],
    {i, 3}
  ];
  Print["test"]
]
```

I expected the module to exit on `Return` and never reach the `Print`, instead I have

```
In[1]:= a = MyMod
       test
```

I am sure I always used the former expected logic in the past.
I lost my memory or is it changed something in the way `Return` works?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You need to use `Module` option on return

```
myMod := Module[{i},
  Do[
   Return[1, Module],
   {i, 3}
   ];
  Print["test"]
  ]
```

and now

```
 myMod
 (* 1 *)
```

This is because `Return` only returns from nearest enclosure, which was `Do` in your case and not from the whole `Module` unless you use the `Module` second option to `Return`. This is different from other languages that you might be familiar with.

See possible options here https://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Return.html for more information.

**update**

To answer the question in comment below `if Return has always worked this way?`

Using V 2.2 of Mathematica, the `Module` option was not supported since I get an error. So this option was added sometime after version 2.2. May be someone else knows when it was added.

ps. looking at bottom of the `Return` help page, it says it was updated in 1996 (version 3.0), so I would assume this is when the option `Module` was added.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thank you, can I ask if you know if `Return` has always worked this way?

Comment: @enzotib Let me reboot my version 2.2 of Mathematica and see. I can't answer this question right now. I would think it always worked this way in Mathematica, but I do not know. May be someone else would. But I will check 2.2 to see.

Comment: Also, I cannot find any reference to a possible second parameter to `Return` in that document.

Comment: @enzotib it a secret option :) I am sure it is there somewhere, but need more time to find it now.

Comment: @enzotib The documentation is [well hidden](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/message/Break/nofunc.html).  Also see the discussion [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/6815/142).