# Why is Return not forcing an exit from my function?

Tags: function-construction, core-language

Here is simplified version of my code that exhibits the behavior troubling me:

```
testFn[] := (
  Do[
   Print[i];
   If[i > 3, Print["triggering result for true"]; Return [100]]
   , {i, 1, 5}];
  Return[200];
  )

testFn[]
1
2
3
4
triggering result for true
200
```

Intuitively, once `i` is bigger than 3, it should evaluate the 2nd argument of the `If` and exit `testFn`, returning 100. However, although the 2nd argument of the If statement is getting evaluated, the function does not exit until it hits the `Return[200]`.

I kind of guessed what might be the problem. The Return[100] is just exiting the `Do`, which seems to be confirmed by doing:

```
testFn[] := (
  a = Do[
    Print[i];
    If[i > 3, Print["triggering result for true"]; Return [100]]
    , {i, 1, 5}];
  Print["a=" <> ToString[a]];
  Return[200];
  )

1
2
3
4
a=100
triggering result for true
200
```

If this is indeed what's happening, how can I make my code actually return from and exit `testFn`?

Comment: Do `Return[100, Module]` Not just `Return[100]` see http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/44585/returning-a-value-from-a-module for more information

Comment: Take a look here: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/29353/how-does-return-work