# Implementing custom return functions for easier error handling

Tags: warning-messages

I was writing a package that retrieved data from various sources in order to use it in computations when I realized it would be practical to have a simple method of error handling.

Ideally, I would like to be able to write

```
error["Message"]
```

instead of

```
Print["Message"];
Return[<|"Success" -> False|>]
```

and

```
success[return]
```

instead of

```
Return[<|"Success" -> True, "Return" -> return|>]
```

However, I am struggling as how to implement this in Mathematica. Clearly, one can't make use of `SetDelayed` because then `Return` would relate to the wrong function. Is there a way around?

Comment: Have a look at [Returning a value from a Module](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/44585/45431).

Comment: @CarlWoll Thank you. The suggested solution turned out to work. I am surprised that such a great feature doesn't get much attention in the documentation, since I specifically looked up `Return` function before posting.

Answer (score 1):

The solution suggested by Carl Woll seems to work. For the reference, I will post an example.

Using the option on `Module`, function `error` can be implemented as follows:

```
error[message_] := (
  Print[message];
  Return[<|"Success" -> False|>, Module]
)
```

To test the behaivour, lets assume the following function `f`:

```
f[x_] := Module[{},
  If[x > 0, x, error["Invalid number"]]
]
```

As expected, supplying non-negative number works

```
f[1]
1
```

while negative number yields an error

```
f[-1]
Invalid number
<|"Success" -> False|>
```

However, note that this solutions assumes the use of `Module` in the enclosing function.