# Trouble returning value from a function

Tags: function-construction

I have three versions to with Module and a simpler one without to compute the sum of primes.  However it will only return a value of 1.  Not sure what to do? I thought Return[j,Module] would do the trick. see [Returning a value from a Module](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/44585/returning-a-value-from-a-module)

using

```
SumPrime[8]
```

to call them.

```
SumPrime[n_] :=  Module[{x = n}, 
  For[{i = 1, j = 1}, {i <= PrimePi[n], Return[j, Module]}, {Set[j, j + Prime[i]], i++}] 
]

SumPrime[n_] :=  Module[{x = n}, 
  For[{i = 1, j = 1}, {i <= PrimePi[n], Return[j, Module]}, {j = j + Prime[i], i++}] 
]

SumPrime[n_] :=  For[{i = 1, j = 1}, {i <= PrimePi[n], Return[j]}, {j = j + Prime[i], i++}]
```

Comment: check the syntax for [`For`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/For.html)

Comment: Mathematica is not python. You don't need an explicit `Return`. And `For` is not your friend (just search on this site about `For` to learn why). Your code can be written in a much cleaner way with `Do`, if it can't be written with functional programming. If you want a chunk of code that does exactly what you want here, but is faster and more readable, this will do it (assuming I got the gist of what you wanted to do): `sumPrime[n_] := Total[Table[Prime[i], {i, PrimePi[n]}]]`

Comment: @ b3m2a1 thanks, I need to develop it further so I also want to subtract off each prime number and take the log so I need to manipulate each prime...Looking up Table[].

Comment: @b3m2a1 yes seems that will work thanks again.

Comment: mathematica is not `c` either.  Curly brackets are list delimiters (only). I can't make sense of why you are using them here.  Also disagree with first comment, dont even waster your time learning `For` syntax.

Comment: to group things. like {i = 1, j = 1}.

Comment: if you just want to evaluate things as a group use semicolons and no parenthesis.  `i=1;j=1`  This is called a Compound Expression http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CompoundExpression.html.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You For-loop is ill-formed; it does not follow the syntax rules for Mathematica's `For`.

This will work.

```
sumPrime[n_] :=
  Module[{i, j},
    For[i = 1; j = 0, i <= PrimePi[n], i++, j += Prime[i]];
    j]
```

> `10`

Note that there is no need to use `Return` because `Module` automatically returns the result of evaluation its `body` (its 2nd argument), which is `j`. However, I recommend

```
sumPrime[n_] := Total @ Table[Prime[i], {i, PrimePi[n]}]
```

which is both simpler and quicker.

```
sumPrime[5]
```

> `10`

Answer (score 4):

Rather than iterative looping you can take advantage of the [`Listable`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Listable.html) attribute of many built-in functions:

```
sumPrime[n_] :=Total@Prime[Range[PrimePi[n]]]
```

Comment: I think you need `PrimePi` in there: `Total@Prime@Range@PrimePi@n`

Comment: @george2079 correct. thanks. rushed it. was wanting to show listability rather than looping

Comment: Good on showing the listability. Might be good to make a quick note of it though in the body text. The OP seems like they know very little about how Mathematica works as a language.