# Best practice with Return in Module or Block

Tags: functions, scoping, return-value

I am a bit confused on the use of `Return` in either `Block` or `Module` when defining a custom function that is used a lot. For instance, The two simple functions (not using initialisation to examplify)

```
f1[x_] := Module[{y},y=x+1; Return[y];];
f2[x_] := Module[{y},y=x+1; y];
```

I am familiar with the differences between `Module` and `Block`---see e.g. [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/559/what-are-the-use-cases-for-different-scoping-constructs)---but I don't really understand what the difference between `f1` and `f2` are in the present case. As someone familiar with other languages, the first seems more natural than the second, especially with respect to the absence of a final semi-colon in the module.

I have noticed that with `Return` I get a bunch of variables `y$1`, `y$2`, ... that get out of scope and not in the other case, but I haven't used it enough to see if it happens also in that case.

Is there a fundamental difference between those two functions, and what is considered best practice?

Comment: Best practice is the 2nd (no `Return`). `Return` is a bit foreign to how Mathematica works, and also redundant here. There is absolutely no reason to add it (it doesn't improve readability for someone comfortable with Mathematica—quite the opposite). Note that `Return` returns from the function, not from the `Module`. If you had something wrapping the `Module`, the behaviour would be different.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The use case for `Return` is not to return a value at the end of a scoping construct like `Module` or `Block`, but to return something from the *middle* of the construct:

```
func[x_] := Module[
    {answer1,answer2},
    <code>
    If[isValid[answer1],
        Return[answer1, Module]
    ];
    <more code>
    answer2
]
```

Here I check a whether some condition is satisfied, and if so I exit the `Module` early.  This could be achieved with a `Catch` and `Throw`, but I tend to reserve that more for errors and exceptions.  Here I view the `Return` as a normal operation, and not exceptional.

The caveat here is that the 2-argument form of `Return`, where the second argument says what to return *from*, is severely under-documented.

Comment: `where the second argument says what to return from, is not documented.` actually it is documented, just hidden :)  From [returning-a-value-from-a-module](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/44585/returning-a-value-from-a-module)  in the comments there below the answer, WReach gave the link which is [here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/message/Break/nofunc.html)  Where it says on that WRI page the following:  `The second argument is used here to specify that the return should be from the enclosing Module`

Comment: That is hilarious, that we document the error message and not the usage.