# Error for Returning the multiple output of a function, error code: Return::nofunc

Tags: functions

I have the following piece of code, and when I call it with "BulirschStoer[Range[0, 1, 10], 0, 10^-2]" in Mathematica 11 I receive the error message as shown in the picture.

I was wondering if anyone could guide me how to overcome this issue?
Thanks in advance for your reply.

[image]

$

```
BulirschStoer[t_, zInitial_, tol_] := 
 Module[{z, info, nStepRefine, nz, nt, i, tSpan, zF, stepInfo, time, 
   zTmp, infoTmp},
  nStepRefine = 3; (*number of sub-
  steps to be created if a step fails*)

  nz = Length[zInitial];(*number of grid points to be solved for ODE*)

    nt = Length[t];(*number of time-steps to be solved for ODE*)

  z = Array[0, {nz, nt}];
  z[[All, 1]] = 
   zInitial;(*the first column of solution estmate is equal to the \
initial value*)

  info <|"error" -> Array[0, {nz, nt}], 
    "funEval" -> Array[0, {1, nt}] |>;

Return[z, 
    info <|"error" -> Array[0, {nz, nt}], 
      "funEval" -> Array[0, {1, nt}] |>];
  ];
```

$

I have also tried Return[z,info]; and got the same error message.

Comment: `Return` is almost certainly not appropriate here (in fact `Return` is extremely rarely used at all in mathematica.  Just end your module with `{z,info..} ]` ( no semicolon)

Comment: ..however since `info` is an unassigned module scope symbol that's not likely doing what you expect either..

Comment: There are errors in your code. The argument `t` is set to `Range[0, 1, 10]` which returns `{0}`. Did you mean `Range[0, 1, 1/10]` or `Range[0, 10]`? The value of `zInitial` is zero. In code you set `nz = Length[zInitial]`. This becomes 0 which propagates into causing `z` to be an empty list, `{}`.

Answer (score 1):

Return[] only accepts one entry and gives back the same entry, i.e. Return[a,b] is not acceptable. Instead try this

```
Return[{expr1,expr2,...}]
```

which takes a vector and gives back the vector.

Comment: `Return` actually accepts a second undocumented argument.  see https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/6815/2079  . That's why we get that incomprehensible error message.

Comment: Yes, it is true and you are right, but it is undocumented argument. our friend here, wants to return 2 different numbers or variables with numeric values.