# How to use Mathematica to return value from for-loop

Tags: procedural-programming, assignment, return-value

I tried to use Mathematica to implement random generator. The pseudo code I use is as following:

```
r = RandomReal[]
s = 0
loop j = 0 ... 2^n - 1
s += p_j
if r <= s then
output[j] and exit
End if
End Loop
```

I tried following code, which didn't return anything.

```
  f[x0_] := 
 Module[{r = RandomReal[], s = 0}, 
  For[i = 0, i < 3, i++; s += x0[[i]]; 
    If[r <= s, Return[i], Continue[] ];];
  ]
f[{1, 2, 3}]
```

May I ask what's wrong with my code? Any suggestions would be appreciated very much.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. I missed ']' at the end. Please see the edited code. I called it using f[{1, 2, 3}]. However, it still didn't return anything.

Comment: Try `Return[i, Module]`. See also https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/134609/why-should-i-avoid-the-for-loop-in-mathematica and https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/6815/what-can-i-use-as-the-second-argument-to-return-in-my-own-functions and here in the docs, http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/message/Break/nofunc.html

Comment: It works now! Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: You're welcome. :)

Comment: It is better to avoid `For`. You can always replace it by `Do`, like this `f[x0_] := Module[{r = RandomReal[], s = 0},
   Do[s += x0[[i]];
    If[r <= s, Return[i, Module]],
    {i, 3}
    ]
   ];` then call as `f[{.1, .3, .4}]`

Comment: @ Nasser, thank you so much for your help. I replaced the for loop with Do. The efficiency is super improved.