# In 10.1.0 BenchmarkPlot doesn't work?

Tags: functions, bugs, packages, undocumented

**Bug introduced in 10.1**

 *This bug was resolved in 10.2.0, but another bug was introduced in 10.3.0 persisting through 10.3.1 and finally resolved in 10.4*

---

In *Mathematica* 10.1.0 and 10.3.0 `BenchmarkPlot` from the GeneralUtilities package doesn't work and we shall focus on the situation of 10.1.0 here. Copying Taliesin Beynon's [initial use](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/54865/121) of the function on this site:

```
Needs["GeneralUtilities`"]

myPosIdx[x_] := <|Thread[x[[#[[All, 1]]]] -> #]|> &@GatherBy[Range@Length@x, x[[#]] &];
```

This evaluates as follows in 10.1.0

```
BenchmarkPlot[{PositionIndex, myPosIdx}, RandomInteger[100, #] &, 16, 
 "IncludeFits" -> True]
```

> SymbolName::sym: Argument
>   {37,31,57,40,5,78,99,97,78,49,82,60,98,80,68,62} at position 1 is
>   expected to be a symbol. >>
>
> SymbolName::sym: Argument
>   {37,31,57,40,5,78,99,97,78,49,82,60,98,80,68,62} at position 1 is
>   expected to be a symbol. >>
>
> SymbolName::sym: Argument
>   {37,31,57,40,5,78,99,97,78,49,82,60,98,80,68,62} at position 1 is
>   expected to be a symbol. >>
>
> General::stop: Further output of SymbolName::sym will be suppressed
>   during this calculation. >>

What went wrong and how do I fix it?

Comment: See the same in Ubuntu (consider this a confirmation!)

Comment: This also no longer works on 10.1.0 for OSX.

Comment: I have reported this as "[CASE:3460529] PrintDefinitions from package GeneralUtilities` bug"

Comment: @Sjoerd Has a solution for the new bug been identified?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Not that I know of. I just tested it on 10.3.1 and it still gave these error messages.

Comment: This bug seems to be fixed in 10.4

Answer (score 22, accepted):

In addition to the error messages quoted in the question the line returns:

```
GeneralUtilities`Benchmarking`PackagePrivate`plot[
 IndexBy[{{{16, 9.37132*10^-6}, . . .
```

IndexBy was removed from 10.1.0:

> Note that IndexBy will be removed in a future version of Mathematica. It was something that was considered for 10.0.0 but didn't make the cut. –  Stefan R [Feb 26 at 17:37](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/75487/what-does-indexby-do-and-how-exactly-does-it-work/75514#comment206525_75487)

We can therefore fix the problem by restoring the function IndexBy.  I provided an improved definition for this function here:

- [What does IndexBy do and how exactly does it work?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/75487/what-does-indexby-do-and-how-exactly-does-it-work/75514#75514)

We can either:

- Load this definition into the System context, e.g. `` System`IndexBy = indexBy ``, or
- Redefine the `BenchmarkPlot` subfuction that uses `IndexBy`:

  ```
  Get["GeneralUtilities`"];

  With[
    {dv := DownValues[GeneralUtilities`Benchmarking`PackagePrivate`addlabels]},
    dv = dv /. System`IndexBy -> indexBy;
  ]
  ```

Comment: Hmm, so they removed `IndexBy`, but forgot to update `BenchmarkPlot`? And actually it looks very strange to remove a function in a minor update...

Comment: @Ruslan `IndexBy` was an undocumented internal function so there was no obligation to keep it but it seems that there was a lack of communication or at least coordination within WRI regarding its existence.

Comment: Thanks for tracking this down.  It was on my to-do list, as I ran into this [a couple of days ago](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/82948/difference-between-sort-and-sortby/83006#83006). (+1 on both Q&A)

Comment: Looks like `BenchmarkPlot` has already been fixed in our latest development builds, but this is a great workaround until the next release!

Comment: @Stefan Thanks for the notice.

Comment: It now fails in 10.3 with a different error: First argument {{16.,{0.124288,<|9->{10000.},11->{20000.},6->{30000.},99->{40000.},57->{50000.},35->{60000.},88->{70000.},78->{80000.},61->{90000.},93->{100000.},76->{110000.,120000.},51->{130000.},23->{140000.},44->{150000.},74->{160000.}|>}},{24.,{<<1>>}},{36.,{0.241031,<|81->{10000.},19->{20000.},<<28>>,25->{360000.}|>}}} in NonlinearModelFit is not a list or a rectangular array. >>

Comment: 10.4.1 contains a definition of IndexBy in GeneralUtilities.