# How to stop Nest when the next element is already in the list

Tags: list-manipulation, functional-style, number-theory

```
step[n_] := 
  step[n] = Plus @@ Delete[Divisors[n], Length[Divisors[n]]];

maxLength = 0;
For[n = 220, n < 223, n++,
 chain = NestWhileList[step, n, # > 1 && # < 1000000 &];
 chain = Delete[chain, Length[chain]];
 If[Length[chain] > maxLength,
  maxLength = Length[chain];
  bestN = Min[chain];,
  Nothing[]
  ]
 ]
```

does not work, I guess because n=220 indeed produces an infinite List (am1c4ble cha1n) which ist precisely what I am looking for. But how do I test for that, so how do I add && # is not part of chain already?

Or am I assuming what the problem is incorrectly? Working test for example with n=221, n<223 terminating and having the correct chain

Comment: Have you considered using the fourth argument of `NestWhileList`, `All`? This would supply you with the information you need to check if `#` has appeared previously.

Comment: No, missed that, will try.

Comment: obviously, just did not mention it in order to not index it in search engines - also I beblieve the p0j3ct 3u13r is to sensitive about that. Who wants to cheat ... have at it...

Comment: no, do not get how to use it with All

NestWhileList[step, 222, # > 1 && # < 1000000 &, All]
already seems to be an infinite loop

Comment: A single piece of my solution from six years ago: `NestWhileList[ds, n, Signature@{1, n, ##2} =!= 0 &, All]` where `ds` is similar to your `step`.  I used `Signature` to check for duplicates.  One could also make use of `UnsameQ` or the new-in-10 `DuplicateFreeQ` with different performance profiles.  [(6745)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/6745/121)   I'll leave the rest for you to figure out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C.E.:

> using the fourth argument of `NestWhileList`, `All`

which solves the example with
Mr.Wizard:

> ```
> NestWhileList[step, n, Signature@{1, n, ##2} =!= 0 &, All]
> ```

Comment: if this should still not be appropriate how do I need to proceed to mark the question as answered?

Comment: you deleted my answere, that I put there to mark it as answered refering to the answers provided as comments.

Comment: As I said, your previous post was not an answer in any way. This one is much better. (In any event, see [this meta thread](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/634).)