# Plotting query - same values on Y-axis / viewing data

Tags: plotting, equation-solving

I'm new to Mathematica, and have numerically solved two similar functions with the following code;

```
a = 5.9336*10^-6; ro = 500*10^-6; Do2 = 2*10^-9; f = 
 2.6835*10^-7; po = 100; 

rl = Sqrt[(6*Do2*f*po)/a];
rn = ro (0.5 - Cos[(ArcCos[1 - (2*rl^2)/(ro^2)] - 2*Pi)/3]);
k = 1*10^-6;

sol = NDSolve[{a*C[r] == (C''[r] + (2/r) C'[r]) (C[r] + k), 
    C[ro] == f*po, C'[rn] == 0}, C, {r, rn, ro}];

solreal = NDSolve[{a == (Creal''[r] + (2/r) Creal'[r]), Creal[ro] == f*po, 
    Creal'[rn] == 0}, Creal, {r, rn, ro}];

Plot[Evaluate[{(C[r]/f) /. sol, (Creal[r]/f) /. solreal} ], {r, rn, 
  ro}, PlotRange -> All]
```

However, I have TWO problems; one is that even though the functions are increasing along the x-axis, the values of the Y-axis are all displaying the exact same number (100). Any idea why this is?

Secondly, can I some how open the array of values for these functions to look at what they are at specific points?

Sorry if these are obvious questions!

Comment: the y- axis thing is because your functions vary less than what you have assigned as the accuracy of the y-axis. Replace `PlotRange->All` with `PlotRange->{All , {99.999, 100.001}}` and you'll see what I mean. As for the function values `C[0.00036] /. sol` gives you the value of `C` at `0.00036` and so on.

Comment: If you want to know the value at a certain point in the plot just select the plot and press the period key. You get the plot position of your mouse as a tool tip. If you want to have a list of values you could use the Table function.

Answer (score 2):

Your values, while increasing, are *extremely* close to 100 across the entire range you plot:

```
(C[#]/f) /. sol & /@ {rn, ro} // InputForm
```

> ```
> {{99.99999980718516}, {100.00000000198392}}
> ```

You may need custom plot `Ticks` if you wish to distinguish that scale.

You can easily create a table of values using `Table` or `Array`.  If you want to look inside InterpolatingFunction itself see:

[How to splice together several instances of InterpolatingFunction?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/19042/how-to-splice-together-several-instances-of-interpolatingfunction/19043#19043)

Comment: Thank you! I'll get on that now..

Answer (score 1):

```
$Version

(* "13.1.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (June 16, 2022)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

a = 59336*10^-10; 
ro = 500*10^-6; 
Do2 = 2*10^-9; 
f = 26835*10^-11; 
po = 100;

rl = Sqrt[(6*Do2*f*po)/a];
rn = ro (1/2 - Cos[(ArcCos[1 - (2*rl^2)/(ro^2)] - 2*Pi)/3]);
k = 1*10^-6;
```

`C` is a reserved symbol, use `c` instead

```
sys1 = {a*c[r] == (c''[r] + (2/r) c'[r]) (c[r] + k), c[ro] == f*po, 
    c'[rn] == 0} // FullSimplify;

sol = NDSolve[sys1, c, {r, rn, ro}][[1]];

sys2 = {a == (Creal''[r] + (2/r) Creal'[r]), Creal[ro] == f*po, 
    Creal'[rn] == 0} // Simplify;
```

`sys2` can be solved exactly

```
solreal = DSolve[sys2, Creal[r], r][[1]] // FullSimplify;

Plot[Evaluate@
  {(c[r]/f) /. sol, (Creal[r]/f) /. solreal},
 {r, rn, ro},
 ScalingFunctions -> {Exp, Log},
 PlotLegends -> Placed[{c, Creal}, {.3, .6}],
 ImageSize -> Large,
 WorkingPrecision -> 30]
```

[image]