# What's inside InterpolatingFunction[{{1., 4.}}, <>]?

Tags: finite-element-method, interpolation, implementation-details, undocumented

I'm curious what's inside the `InterpolationFunction` object?

For example:

```
InputForm[Interpolation[{1., 2., 3., 4.}]]
(*
  InterpolatingFunction[
    {{1., 4.}}, 
    {4, 7, 0, {4}, {4}, 0, 0, 0, 0, Automatic}, 
    {{1., 2., 3., 4.}},{Developer`PackedArrayForm, {0, 1, 2, 3, 4}, {1., 2., 3., 4.}}, 
    {Automatic}]
*)
```

What do those arguments mean?

Comment: Related:[(19042)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/19042/121)

Answer (score 65, accepted):

From inspection, some investigation and [ruebenko](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/21/ruebenko)'s help, what I've found so far is that `InterpolatingFunction` has the following underlying structure:

```
InterpolatingFunction[
    domain,                    (* or min/max of grid for each dimension          *)
    List[
        version,               (* 3 in Mathematica 7, 4 from 8 onwards           *)
        bitField,              (* 3 for exact/arbitrary precision
                                  7 for machine numbers, 15 for machine complex,
                                  39 for spline, 4259 for FEM elements. These are 
                                  for version 4, and are different for version 3.*)
        dataDerivatives,       (* Max order of derivatives supplied for input    *)
        domainGridSize,        (* or input sample points in each dimension       *)
        interpolationOrder,    (* actually, order + 1; for each dimension        *)
        nthDerivativeOfIntFun, (* Denotes if the current InterpolatingFunction is 
                                  an nth derivative of an existing Int. Func. and
                                  0 otherwise.                                   *)
        periodicInterpolation, (* 0 for False and {1} for True                   *)
        0, 0,                  (* One of the zeros is a permutation flag for 
                                  time-dependent InterpolatingFunction           *)
        Automatic              (* Extrapolation handler                          *)
    ],

    basicInterpolatingUnit,    (* This is setup such that it agrees with the input
                                   values at the input grid points. You might see 
                                  structures with Developer`PackedArrayForm for 
                                  2D Hermite, BSplineFunction for 2D Spline
                                  NDSolve`FEM`ElementMesh for 3D, or nothing.    *)
    Automatic                  (* Unknown                                        *)
]
```

You can access most of this internal data using the following arguments to any `InterpolatingFunction` object:

```
{"Domain", "Coordinates", "Grid", "ValuesOnGrid", "InterpolationOrder", "DerivativeOrder"}
```

See the contents of the following package for more information on what exactly the above arguments return:

```
SystemOpen@FindFile["DifferentialEquations`InterpolatingFunctionAnatomy`"]
```

Comment: a few more: The fist unknown is the version. The typeInfo is bit field. The first Automatic is an extrapolation handler. One of the zeros before is a permutation flag for time dependent if.

Comment: @ruebenko Thanks! Added to the list. Do you have an example of a time dependent IF? I don't think I've seen it. Also, is there a way one can set the extrapolation handler?

Comment: something like `Interpolation[data, InterpolationOrder -> 1, 
 "ExtrapolationHandler" -> {(Indeterminate &), 
   "WarningMessage" -> False}]` - but this is experimental.

Comment: @ruebenko Thanks! That will be immensely useful and will save me a lot of unnecessary `Piecewise` or `If`s.

Comment: In V10, the version number is now 5 and one can pass the argument `"ElementMesh"` to IFs that interpolate over an `ElementMesh` (e.g. when using FEM in `NDSolve`).  Perhaps the bitfield meanings have changed.

Comment: Following the `List`, third argument seems to be the input grid/mesh and the fourth argument seems to be the output interpolating structure.  Then comes `{Automatic}` as the fifth and final argument.  (In both V9 and V10 -- I've consulted this page so often that I can't believe I didn't notice before.)

Comment: @R.M. One can also find method used to generate IF with `InterpolationMethod` argument.

Comment: @rm-rf The `version` attribute (part 2,2 of the InterpolatingFunction) comes out as 5 on MM v12. Do you know when it switched from 4 to 5?