# Interpolating a ParametricFunction

Tags: differential-equations, interpolation, parametric-functions

Original domain of my independent variable `t` is  0 to 10 nanometers, but in *Mathematica* (as in most numerical software), it's good idea to solve differential equation in the more 'usual' unit scale 0 to 10.

```
pfun = ParametricNDSolveValue[ {x''[
      t] + a x'[t] + b^2 x[t] == 0, x[0] == 1, 
   x'[0] == 0}, x, {t, 0, 10}, {a,b}]
```

How can I scale back `t` in the resulting `ParametricFunction` to nanometers?

Note: With `NDSolve` we used before version 9 (which introduced `ParametricNDSolveValue`), the result was an `InterpolatingFunction`, which was easily scaled back by using

```
Interpolation[{#*10^(-9), pfun[#]} & /@Range[0, 10, 10^(-1)]]
```

Comment: There seems to me be an extra factor of 10 in `NDSolve` example.  If not, my answer is off by a factor of 10.

Comment: The expression {#*10*10^(-9), pfun[#]} was allright, since 10*10^(-9) equals to 10 nm or 1.*^-9 in more compact notation. Therefore I edited your answer to make it compatible.

Comment: Are you sure? `10*10^(-9) == 1.*^-8` returns `True` on my machine.

Comment: Or to put it another way, if `Range` goes from 0 to 10, then the expression `#*10*10^(-9)` goes from 0 to `10*10*10^(-9)` or `100 * 10^-9`.  I assumed you were converting between nm & m (but maybe that's wrong?).  I thought maybe the `10` in `Range` or the factor of `10` might have been meant to be a `1` or left out.

Comment: Sorry, my stupid mistake with `#*10*10^(-9)`. Now I corrected it in the answer. And yes, i was converting nm &m.

Answer (score 3):

In the differential equation `x` is the dependent variable, a function of `t` and which function depends on parameters `a`, `b`.
So we have `x` given by `pfun[a, b][t]`,
and I take it from the example, that  `t` is to be rescaled.  If so, then this seems serviceable (for `a = -2`, `b = 1`):

```
xfn = pfun[-2, 1][Rescale[#, {0, 10^-9}]] &
```

Example:

```
xfn[4.*^-9]
(* -163.794 *)
```

If the output value `x` is to be rescaled then

```
xfn = Rescale[pfun[-2, 1][#], {0, 10^-9}] &
```

and

```
xfn[4.]
(* -1.63794 * 10^11 *)
```

---

Generally, one might define

```
x[a_?NumericQ, b_?NumericQ, t_?NumericQ] := pfun[a, b][Rescale[t, {0, 10^-9}]]
```

---

**Update**

Alternatively, note that `pfun[a, b]` yields an `InterpolatingFunction`, which you can use as you are used to (although I realize that might be inconvenient in many applications).  There is a drawback to the way the function is re-interpolated in the OP that is worth addressing.

The `InterpolatingFunction` has more data, and data that is more precise, at certain points in the domain than at the equally spaced sample points given by `Range[0, 10, 10^(-1)]]`.  `NDSolve` stores the values of the function and its first and second derivatives at input values called a `"Grid"`.

Here's a way to rescale the `InterpolatingFunction` returned by `ParametricNDSolveValue`.  We have to scale the derivatives by different factors. (You can justify it either by the "Chain Rule" or by dimensional analysis of $dx/dt$ and $d^2x/dt^2$.)

If `ifn` is an `InterpolatingFunction1`, you can get the grid of input numbers and the corresponding function values with

```
ifn["Grid"]
ifn["ValuesOnGrid"]

(* {{x1}, {x2}, ... }
   { y1,   y2,  ... } *)
```

and `ifn[{"Grid", "ValuesOnGrid"}]` returns both in a list; `ifn["Coordinates"]` also returns the input numbers in a flat list.  To get the values of the derivative (AFAIK), you need to evaluate `ifn'` and `ifn''` on the grid (`"Coordinates"` is convenient here).

```
rescale = {1*^-9, 1, 1*^9, 1*^18};
solfun[a_?NumericQ, b_?NumericQ] := solfun[a, b] =
  Interpolation[Transpose[
    rescale * Join[
      pfun[a, b][{"Grid", "ValuesOnGrid"}],
      Through[{pfun[a, b]', pfun[a, b]''}[First[pfun[a, b]["Coordinates"]]]]
      ]
    ]]
```

We can compare it to a re-interpolation on a regular grid.

```
ifun = Interpolation[{# * 10^(-9), pfun[-2, 1][#]} & /@ Range[0, 10, 10^(-1)]];
```

The mean relative error of `solfun` is much better:

```
Table[Abs[(ifun[t] - pfun[-2, 1][Rescale[t, {0, 10^-9}]])/
   pfun[-2, 1][Rescale[t, {0, 10^-9}]]], {t, 0, 10^-8, 10^-13}] // Mean
Table[Abs[(solfun[-2, 1][t] - pfun[-2, 1][Rescale[t, {0, 10^-9}]])/
   pfun[-2, 1][Rescale[t, {0, 10^-9}]]], {t, 0, 10^-8, 10^-13}] // Mean

(* 9.03955*10^-6
   6.50966*10^-15 *)
```

The maximum relative error is likewise several orders of magnitude better for `solfun`.  The horizontal axis is just about at the level of `Log10[$MachineEpsilon]`.  (There's something funny going on at `10^-9`.)

```
ListPlot[Log10@
  {Table[Abs[(ifun[t] - pfun[-2, 1][Rescale[t, {0, 10^-9}]])/
          pfun[-2, 1][Rescale[t, {0, 10^-9}]]],
     {t, 0, 10^-8, 10^-13}], 
   Table[Abs[(solfun[-2, 1][t] - pfun[-2, 1][Rescale[t, {0, 10^-9}]])/
          pfun[-2, 1][Rescale[t, {0, 10^-9}]]],
     {t, 0, 10^-8, 10^-13}]}, 
 DataRange -> {0, 10^-8}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Ref.: See [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/28337/whats-inside-interpolatingfunction1-4/28341#28341) for more about `InterpolatingFunction`s.

Comment: Actually, I searched for a solution which would also scale `t` inside `pfun` before knowing the values of `a,b` (mainly for purpose of speeding up subsequent solutions of `ParametricNDSolveValue`. I don't know if that is possible to do, since it certainly has to do with how Mathematica calculates solution internally.

Comment: As far as I can tell, `ParametricNDSolveValue` after checking of arguments, sets up a family of DEs.  When, say, `pfun[-2, 1]` is first called, the DE is solved, via `NDSolve` probably, and stores ("caches") the `InterpolatingFunction` solution, which is reused on subsequent calls.  So for instance `Plot[pfun[-2, 1][t], {t, 0, 10}]` (DE solved once) is about 16 times faster per function call than `Plot3D[pfun[a, b][10.], {a, 0, 1}, {b, 0, 1}]` (DE solved many times, once for each `a, b`).  Btw, `Rescale` might be fast enough.

Comment: For me your `Plot[]` example is 60 (sixty) times faster than `Plot3D` (measured with `Timing[]`).

Comment: I had about 100 times faster in all, but `Plot` had 580 function calls (to `pfun`) and `Plot3D` had `3928` function calls. For brevity, I didn't include the option `EvaluationMonitor :> (cnt++)` in my previous comment.  Set `cnt = 0` before the plot.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question right, you only need to put correct initial conditions. Indeed, your equation

```
eq = x''[t] + a x'[t] + b^2 x[t] == 0
```

is linear. I understand that you mean that x is measured in meters and t in seconds. If I am right, let us make a substitution: x[t] -> 10^m*y[t] with m=9

```
eq /. x -> (10^m*y[#] &)
Map[Expand@Divide[#, 10^m] &, %]
```

The result is:

```
(*
       10^m b^2 y[t] + 10^m a Derivative[1][y][t] + 
  10^m (y^\[Prime]\[Prime])[t] == 0

b^2 y[t] + a Derivative[1][y][t] + (y^\[Prime]\[Prime])[t] == 0
*)
```

So we get the same equation for any m, but now for y=y[t]. This is the general result due to the linearity of the equation in question. Now, if m=9, y is measured in nanometers. You only need to set the initial conditions also in nanometers.

By the way, did you really mean that x[0]==1 meter? Probably you had in mind 1 nanometer? Anyway, it seems more convenient to look for the analytical solution:

```
 DSolve[{y''[t] + a y'[t] + b^2 y[t] == 0, y[0] == 1, y'[0] == 0}, y, t]



(*   {{y -> Function[{t}, (1/(
        2 Sqrt[a^2 - 4 b^2]))(-a E^(1/2 (-a - Sqrt[a^2 - 4 b^2]) t) + 
          Sqrt[a^2 - 4 b^2] E^(1/2 (-a - Sqrt[a^2 - 4 b^2]) t) + 
          a E^(1/2 (-a + Sqrt[a^2 - 4 b^2]) t) + 
          Sqrt[a^2 - 4 b^2] E^(1/2 (-a + Sqrt[a^2 - 4 b^2]) t))]}}
    *)
```

Comment: I just corrected my question that I meant both `t` and `x` in nanometers. Please edit your answer appropriately

Comment: @Cendo Your question is still obscure. I still do not see, where the problem lies. All your unknowns and parameters should have correct dimensions that agree to one another. That is dimensions of both a and b are 1/nm and x[0]==1 nm. You need not to do anything else. Just solve it in Mathematica, and write down dimensions to the right of the solution. Done.