# Transform an InterpolatingFunction

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, numerics, interpolation, nonlinear

I'd like to transform an InterpolatingFunction from NDSolve but can't figure out how.   Here's an example. The equation I want to solve is

```
sol1 = NDSolve[{n'[t] == n[t] (1 - n[t]), n[0] == 10^-5}, n, {t, 0, 20}]
```

but for numerical reasons (not in this toy example), the log transformed equation

```
sol2 = NDSolve[{ln'[t] == (1 - E^ln[t]), ln[0] == Log[10^-5]}, ln, {t, 0, 20}]
```

works better.  How can I transform the result in sol2 to match sol1 by taking E^sol2, without losing any accuracy?

**EDIT: A slightly less minimal example**:

This is in response to @MichaelE2's comment below. It's still a toy example, but illustrates the problem with interpolating only on the original grid.

This is the original model in natural units.  The output is wrong because extra AccuracyGoal is needed.

```
sol3 = NDSolve[{n'[t] == 
  Piecewise[{{n[t] (1 - n[t]), Mod[t, 100] < 60}, {-n[t], Mod[t, 100] >= 60}}],
  n[0] == 10^-15}, n, {t, 0, 100}][[1]];
Plot[n[t] /. sol3, {t, 0, 100}]
```

[image: wrong solution]

Here's a better solution of the model:

```
sol3b = NDSolve[{n'[t] == 
  Piecewise[{{n[t] (1 - n[t]), Mod[t, 100] < 60}, {-n[t], Mod[t, 100] >= 60}}],
  n[0] == 10^-15}, n, {t, 0, 100}, AccuracyGoal -> \[Infinity]][[1]];
Plot[n[t] /. sol3b, {t, 0, 100}]
```

[image: better solution]

Here's a solution of the log-transformed model:

```
sol4 = NDSolve[{ln'[t] == 
  Piecewise[{{(1 - E^ln[t]), Mod[t, 100] < 60}, {-1, Mod[t, 100] >= 60}}],
  ln[0] == Log[10^-15]}, ln, {t, 0, 100}][[1]];
Plot[E^ln[t] /. sol4, {t, 0, 100}]
```

[image: good solution]

Now to try the two different ways to create an exponentiated InterpolatingFunction.  This one uses the original grid and leads to a big artifact.

```
sol5IFN = Interpolation[Transpose[{ln["Grid"], Exp[ln["ValuesOnGrid"]]} /.First@sol4]];
Plot[sol5IFN[t], {t, 0, 100}]
```

[image: bad transformed function]

Looking at the underlying grid makes it obvious what the problem is:

```
ListPlot[Transpose[{ln["Grid"][[All, 1]], Exp[ln["ValuesOnGrid"]]} /. First@sol4]]
```

[image: underlying grid]

The alternative approach of making your own grid suggested by @bbgodfrey works better:

```
sol6 = Interpolation[Table[{t, E^ln[t] /. sol4}, {t, 0, 100, 0.1}], InterpolationOrder -> 1];
Plot[sol6[t], {t, 0, 100}]
```

[image: better interpolatingfunction]

**UPDATE 2: Higher InterpolationOrder**

```
sol5IFN = Interpolation[Transpose[{ln["Grid"], Exp[ln["ValuesOnGrid"]]} /. First@sol4], InterpolationOrder -> 8];
Plot[sol5IFN[t], {t, 0, 100}, PlotRange -> {0, 1}]
```

[image: interpolation disaster]

Comment: @ChrisK After making my last comment on the solution by @MichaelE2, I tried recomputing his `sol3IFN` with `InterpolationOrder -> 8`.  With that change the corresponding relative error plot looks essentially identical to the second plot in my answer.  Perhaps, you could rerun your comparison above with this change.

Comment: @bbgodfrey I added it above -- very wiggly.

Comment: @ChrisK Too bad.  Thanks anyway.  Good luck with your project.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To obtain the solution to each equation as an `InterpolatingFunction`, use

```
sol1 = n /. NDSolve[{n'[t] == n[t] (1 - n[t]), n[0] == 10^-5}, n, {t, 0, 20}][[1]];
sol2 = ln /. NDSolve[{ln'[t] == (1 - E^ln[t]), ln[0] == Log[10^-5]}, ln, {t, 0, 20}][[1]]
```

Unfortunately, simply constructing `Exp[sol2]` to match sol1 does not work, as explained in [Question 67494](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/67494/transform-an-interpolatingfunction).  A solution is to construct a `Table`, apply `Exp` to each element, and construct a new `InterpolatingFunction` from the result:

```
sol3 = Interpolation[Table[{0.1 i, Exp[sol2[0.1 i]]}, {i, 0, 200}]]
```

The relative error is small.

```
Plot[(sol3[t]/sol1[t] - 1), {t, 0, 20}]
```

[image: Relative difference between sol1 and sol3]

The solution posted as this one was being written takes an alternative approach, creating a function that applies `Exp` at each evaluation of `sol2`, rather than creating a new `InterpolatingFunction`.  Both work.

**Update based on my last comment**

Actually, the plot above shows the relative difference between `sol3` and `sol1`, but not necessarily the accuracy of `sol3`.  To obtain a good estimate of its accuracy, we must have a high accuracy result for `sol1`, obtained by reducing the `NDSolve` step size:

```
sol1 = n /. NDSolve[{n'[t] == n[t] (1 - n[t]), n[0] == 10^-5}, n, {t, 0, 20}, MaxStepFraction -> 1/4000][[1]]
```

The value of `MaxStepFraction` is chosen so that `sol1` changes imperceptibly for further decreases.  Using the new `sol1` result yields a comparison plot,

[image: Relative error between sol1 and sol3]

Thus, `sol3` is very accurate indeed.

Comment: This is potentially great, but I need to check my real application to see if the inaccuracy introduced is too much.

Comment: I was careless in my terminology.  The plot above shows the relative difference between `sol3` and `sol1`, not the error in `sol3`.  In fact, the error appears to be in `sol1`.  I just recomputed `sol1` to higher accuracy with `MaxStepFraction -> 1/500`, and the maximum relative difference in the plot dropped to `0.00002`.  Thus, as you originally suggested, computing and exponentiating `sol2` is rather more accurate than computing `sol1` directly.

Comment: This works well in my real application.  Two things that are nice: 1) if you need the transformed InterpolatingFunction to be a better approximation, you can increase the number of points that went into it and 2) the end values seem to be exact.

Answer (score 10):

**Update**-- It turns out that a direct construction from an `InterpolatingFunction` does not satisfy all cases and that what is needed is a more general function interpolation.  It would be nice to have a method that had some sort of automatic precision tracking.  [`FunctionInterpolation`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/FunctionInterpolation.html) is an apparently orphaned system function that seems to make no attempt at tracking accuracy or precision.  The best way I know, which I've discussed with some of the numerics people at WRI, is to use `NDSolve`.

### Function interpolation

Basically there are two way you can proceed to interpolate a function `f[x]`, either solve the equation `y[x] == f[x]` as a differential-algebraic equation with a dummy ODE, or differentiate the equation and solve it as an ODE:

```
NDSolveValue[{y[x] == f[x], t'[x] == 1, t[a] == a}, y, {x, a, b}] (* DAE *)
NDSolveValue[{y'[x] == D[f[x], x], y[a] == f[a]}, y, {x, a, b}]   (* ODE *)
```

The DAE method can be highly accurate but it is currently limited to [`MachinePrecision`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/MachinePrecision.html).  The ODE method may be done at any finite precision, but it also has the error from the integration method.  In the OP's examples, the function being integrated contains a machine-precision interpolating function, and so one would not expect accuracy or precision better than one half of machine precision; perhaps worse in the ODE method, which would contain the derivative of the interpolating function.

I have used both methods several times on the site:

- [Interpolating a ParametricFunction](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/30745/interpolating-a-parametricfunction/30749#30749)
- [How to find an approximate solution in a region when Solve or NSolve does not work?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/41871/how-to-find-an-approximate-solution-in-a-region-when-solve-or-nsolve-does-not-wo/64161#64161)
- [How to use `FindRoot` to solve an equation containing a parameter?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/49131/how-to-use-findroot-to-solve-an-equation-containing-a-parameter/49181#49181)
- [How do I feed data points into an equation to solve NUMERICALLY?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/59158/how-do-i-feed-data-points-into-an-equation-to-solve-numerically/59196#59196)
- [Interpolating an Antiderivative](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/59891/interpolating-an-antiderivative/59892#59892)
- [Solve trigonometric equation](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/27913/solve-trigonometric-equation/27984#27984)
- [automatic processing of numerical results in `Plot`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/34599/automatic-processing-of-numerical-results-in-plot/34609#34609)

Since `FunctionInterpolation` does not work well, here is my version of it.  It does the DAE method for machine precision and the ODE otherwise.

```
ClearAll[functionInterpolation];
SetAttributes[functionInterpolation, HoldAll];
functionInterpolation[f_, {x_, a_, b_}, opts : OptionsPattern[NDSolve]] /; 
   MatchQ[WorkingPrecision /. {opts}, WorkingPrecision | MachinePrecision] :=
  Block[{x},
   NDSolveValue[
    {\[FormalY][x] == f, \[FormalT]'[x] == 1, \[FormalT][a] == a},
    \[FormalY], {x, a, b}, opts]
   ];
functionInterpolation[f_, {x_, a_, b_}, opts : OptionsPattern[NDSolve]] :=
  Block[{x},
   NDSolveValue[
    {\[FormalY]'[x] == D[f, x], \[FormalY][a] == f /. x -> a},
    \[FormalY], {x, a, b}, opts]
   ];
```

OP's second example:

```
sol3nd = functionInterpolation[Exp[ln[t] /. First@sol4], {t, 0, 100}]
Plot[sol3nd[t] - n[t] /. sol3b, {t, 0, 100}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

If high *precision* is needed, then, as in the OP's solution `sol3b`, one needs a higher `AccuracyGoal` (the relative error of the one above exceeds 1, sometimes by a lot, when the value `n[t]` is close to zero):

```
sol3nd = functionInterpolation[Exp[ln[t] /. First@sol4], {t, 0, 100}, AccuracyGoal -> 30];
Plot[(sol3nd[t] - n[t])/n[t] /. sol3b, {t, 0, 100; 61}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

### Direct construction (original solution)

A direct way to construct "`Exp[sol2]`" is to exponentiate the values stored in the interpolating function:

```
sol3IFN = Interpolation[Transpose[{ln["Grid"], Exp[ln["ValuesOnGrid"]]} /. First@sol2]]
```

As for accuracy, the interpolation between the grid points will be cubic, whereas for `Exp[ln[t]] /. sol2`, the interpolation will be the exponential of a cubic.  So this method will yield exactly `Exp[ln[t]]` on the grid points but vary from it in between.

```
Plot[sol3IFN[t] - Exp[ln[t]] /. sol2, {t, 0, 20}, PlotPoints -> 100]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comparing with the exact solution shows it is quite accurate:

```
sol1ex = DSolve[{n'[t] == n[t] (1 - n[t]), n[0] == 10^-5}, n, t];
Plot[sol3IFN[t] - n[t] /. sol1ex, {t, 0, 20}]
```

> Solve::ifun: Inverse functions are being used by Solve, so some solutions may not be found; use Reduce for complete solution information. >>

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I did something similar in my answer to [Interpolating a ParametricFunction](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/30745/interpolating-a-parametricfunction/30749#30749).  In that case it was a rescaling.  It seems a nonlinear transformation can have problems (see OP's update).  Perhaps it is due to changes in convexity.

Comment: Yours is a very elegant approach.  It appears to be based on http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/19042/, but what is the source of that information?  Does Wolfram have some additional documentation on line somewhere?  Thanks.

Comment: This is indeed elegant, but it didn't work so well on my real application.  That's because my real function has a sharp corner and the new InterpolatingFunction has big distortions due to the cubic interpolation between widely spaced exact points.  bbgodfrey's Table approach fixed that issue.  But it might be fine for smooth functions.

Comment: @bbgodfrey Many data structures take an argument `sol3IFN["Properties"]` that shows arguments you can use. There's also http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/28337 and the tutorial
[`InterpolatingFunctionAnatomy`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language
/tutorial/NDSolvePackages.html). With the [Spelunking package](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/15948), you can find out `InterpolatingFunctionAnatomy` is implemented as `ifun["Grid"]` etc. Some users prefer to use `InterpolatingFunctionAnatomy` functions. I've grown used to using `"Properties"` for various data structures.

Comment: @ChrisK Interesting.  That means the corner comes between the computed data points, since the method above has almost zero error on a data point.  It doesn't sound like the usual output of `NDSolve`.  I don't suppose you could post the actual `sol2` you want interpolated, since your real problem seems to have issues not present in the question?

Comment: @MichaelE2 Sure! This comment space it too small to fully describe it, so I'll add it in an edit to my original question.

Comment: @MichaelE2 and @ChrisK, I just ran a relative error plot (like the last plot in my answer) for `sol3IFN` and obtained values as large as `0.001` near `t=2`.  This surprises me.

Comment: @bbgodfrey It's not too surprising for me.  Having high precision with numbers close to zero is difficult.  Between the grid points, one solution is interpolated by a cubic polynomial and the other by the exponential of a cubic.  The transformation by `Exp`, which is concave up, is introducing a little error.  For a number `Exp[ln[t]]` that is about 10^-4, an error of 10^-7 leads to a relative error of 0.001.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Wow, your edited method is clever and works well too.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I would augment your good logarithmic [`NDSolve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NDSolve) call to also produce your desired normal interpolating function:

```
{nIF, lnIF} = NDSolveValue[
    {
    ln'[t] == Piecewise[{{(1 - E^ln[t]), Mod[t, 100] < 60}, {-1, Mod[t, 100] >= 60}}],
    ln[0] == Log[10^-15],
    n'[t] == Exp[ln[t]] ln'[t],
    n[0] == 10^-15
    },
    {n, ln},
    {t, 0, 100}
];
```

This is similar to @MichaelE2's answer, but I think using 1 [`NDSolve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NDSolve) call allows the step size to be adjusted so that both interpolating functions get  the same accuracy and precision goals.

Here is a plot of `nIF`:

```
Plot[nIF[x], {x, 0, 100}]
```

[image]

And `nIF` is indeed an interpolating function:

```
nIF //OutputForm
```

> InterpolatingFunction[{{0., 100.}}, <>]

Answer (score 1):

you can work on the results as follows:

```
f1 = n /. sol1[[1]];
f2 = ln /. sol2[[1]];
f3[x_] := Exp[f2[x]]
```

To check the match between f1 and f3 we can plot:

```
Plot[{f1[x], f2[x], f3[x]}, {x, 0, 20}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Directive[Red, Dashed, Thickness[0.02]], Automatic, 
   Black}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the idea!  This is what I've done myself, but I really want it in InterpolatingFunction form.