# FunctionInterpolation with vector output and scalar input

Tags: interpolation

Apparently it is possible to build and InterpolatingFunction that accepts a vector input and returns a vector output:

```
FunctionInterpolation[
 Evaluate[Table[D[{Sin[x y], Cos[x y]}, {{x, y}, k}], {k, 0, 2}]], {x,
   0., 2. Pi}, {y, 0., 2. Pi}]
%[1, 2]
{Sin[1 2], Cos[1 2]} // N
```

> InterpolatingFunction[{{0., 6.28319}, {0., 6.28319}}, <>]
>
> {0.909518, -0.415989}
>
> {0.909297, -0.416147}

However trying to build an InterpolatingFunction from a scalar input with vector output I get an error and an interpolating function with scalar output:

```
FunctionInterpolation[{Cos[t], Sin[t]}, {t, 0., 2. Pi}]
```

> During evaluation of In[224]:= FunctionInterpolation::ncvb:
>   FunctionInterpolation failed to meet the prescribed accuracy and
>   precision goals after 6 recursive bisections near t = {0.}. Continuing
>   to refine elsewhere. >>
>
> During evaluation of In[224]:= FunctionInterpolation::ncvb:
>   FunctionInterpolation failed to meet the prescribed accuracy and
>   precision goals after 6 recursive bisections near t = {0.019635}.
>   Continuing to refine elsewhere. >>
>
> During evaluation of In[224]:= FunctionInterpolation::ncvb:
>   FunctionInterpolation failed to meet the prescribed accuracy and
>   precision goals after 6 recursive bisections near t = {0.0392699}.
>   Continuing to refine elsewhere. >>
>
> During evaluation of In[224]:= General::stop: Further output of
>   FunctionInterpolation::ncvb will be suppressed during this
>   calculation. >>
>
> Out[224]= InterpolatingFunction[{{0., 6.28319}}, <>]
>
> 0.53844

I'm unsure about the syntax so I tried also:

```
In[227]:= FunctionInterpolation[{{Cos[t], Sin[t]}}, {t, 0., 2. Pi}]
%[1]
```

> During evaluation of In[227]:= Thread::tdlen: Objects of unequal
>   length in {-0.785398,-0.261799,0.261799,0.785398}^{} cannot be
>   combined. >>
>
> During evaluation of In[227]:= Thread::tdlen: Objects of unequal
>   length in {-0.241564+3.14159 I,-1.34018+3.14159 I,-1.34018,-0.241564}
>   {} cannot be combined. >>
>
> During evaluation of In[227]:= Thread::tdlen: Objects of unequal
>   length in {-0.785398,-0.261799,0.261799,0.785398} {} cannot be
>   combined. >>
>
> During evaluation of In[227]:= General::stop: Further output of
>   Thread::tdlen will be suppressed during this calculation. >>
>
> During evaluation of In[227]:= FunctionInterpolation::nreal: Near t =
>   0.7853981633974483`, the function did not evaluate to a real number. >>
>
> During evaluation of In[227]:= FunctionInterpolation::nreal: Near t =
>   0.8342673824532895`, the function did not evaluate to a real number. >>
>
> During evaluation of In[227]:= FunctionInterpolation::nreal: Near t =
>   2.356194490192345`, the function did not evaluate to a real number. >>
>
> During evaluation of In[227]:= General::stop: Further output of
>   FunctionInterpolation::nreal will be suppressed during this
>   calculation. >>
>
> Out[227]= InterpolatingFunction[{{0., 6.28319}}, <>]
>
> Out[228]= {0.539949, 0.841086}

I suppose the task can be accomplished, so What is the proper syntax?

### UPDATE

I'm interested to build a single vector interpolating function of a scalar variable, given a possibly "opaque" vector function of a numerical scalar variable. Say

```
pf[t_?NumericQ] := With[{expensiveCalc=...}, {xof[expensiveCalc], yof[expensiveCalc]}]

pi = FunctionInterpolation[pf[t], {t,t1,t2}]
```

I was trying to use `FunctionInterpolation` in the hope to produce a "smooth" output of an expensive function describing a curve in a parametric form, evaluating the function where is more needed, and to later recognize some feature of the graph of the function(roghly speaking the point of maximal curvature, maybe directly with `FindMaximum` and something like `pi''`).

Other options comes to mind to solve this problem (for example `ParametricPlot`, `Sow/Reap` and hopefully `ListInterpolation`), but I'm still interested to the original question for the sake of knowledge.

Comment: My impression is that `FunctionInterpolation` is a bit of an [orphan](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/67494/transform-an-interpolatingfunction/67642#67642). It might be better to use another approach.

Answer (score 4):

I'd recommend using `NDSolve` instead of `FunctionInterpolation`, as recommended to me by some the of the Wolfram folks.

```
pf[t_?NumericQ] := {Cos[t], Sin[t]};
pi = NDSolveValue[{y[t] == pf[t], y[0] == pf[0], s'[t] == 1, s[0] == 0}, y, {t, 0., 2. Pi}];

pi[2]
(*  {-0.416147, 0.909297}  *)
```

If `pf` is differentiable, then perhaps this:

```
pi = NDSolveValue[{y'[t] == D[{Cos[t], Sin[t]}, t], y[0] == {1, 0}}, y, {t, 0., 2. Pi}]
```

Comment: This is great. But when I apply to my "real" function I get a lot of messages like "NDSolveValue::nbnum1: The function value {0,0}==0 is not True or False when the arguments are {-1.08214,{7.89896,8.72311},0.,{0.,0.},1.}. >>" and "NDSolveValue::ecboo: The value of event condition function at t = -1.08214 was not True or False. The event will be considered inactive. >>"

Comment: @unlikely Thanks.  The "`{0,0}==0`" would seem to be a hint (vector == scalar).  There seems to be a mismatch between the two sides in your code.  It's hard to speculate further without seeing code that produces the error. It's also possible that there's a lurking definition (e.g. `s`).

Comment: I solved and now works, the problem was my function was not really "opaque". I can now try to use this approach to solve my problem. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Kinda kludgy, but:

```
g[x_] = Through[(FunctionInterpolation[#, {t, 0., 2. Pi}] & /@ {Cos[t], Sin[t]})[x]]
```

It works:

```
g[2.0]
(*{-0.416147, 0.909297}*)
```

I'd be interested to see if there was a better way. I'm also surprised your original code doesn't work (although I may just be speaking out of ignorance here).

Comment: Thank but, as better explained now, I'm searching a way to build a single interpolating function at once. Sorry for confusion.