# Interpolation steeply drops to 0 beyond data

Tags: plotting, interpolation

I use Interpolation on unstructured 3-D-Data to visualize different regions via RegionPlot. A problem I run into is that the interpolating function steeply drops to zero beyond my set of data. This is unfortunate, as I with to show the region up to their theoretical boundary (which lies only a little bit beyond the data region).

Is there a way to get Interpolation to perform a proper extrapolation for just a little margin beyond my data?

This image shows the problem pretty well I think. [image: Example for the problem]

The data that produced the image can be found [here](http://pastebin.com/26cKUtE3)

Comment: Please include a sample dataset that reproduces this problem.

Comment: Thanks. I added the data, I hope the spoiler works, it's quite a list...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't know what proper extrapolation you have in mind, but you can specify an extrapolation function, at least in V9, with the option `"ExtrapolationHandler" -> {f}` (which is experimental [according to ruebenko](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/28337/whats-inside-interpolatingfunction1-4/28341#comment88520_28341)).  In this case `f` should be a function of the form `f[x, y]`.

**Examples.**

No extrapolation:

```
ifn = Interpolation[N @ data, 
  "ExtrapolationHandler" -> {(Indeterminate &), "WarningMessage" -> False}];
Plot3D[ifn[x, y], {x, 0.`, 30.`}, {y, 0.`, 20.`}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Nearest data point:

```
nf = Nearest[Most /@ data -> Last /@ data];
ifn1 = Interpolation[N @ data, 
  "ExtrapolationHandler" -> {(First@nf[{##}]) &, "WarningMessage" -> False}];
Show[
 Plot3D[ifn1[x, y], {x, 1.725`, 30.`}, {y, 0.`, 20.`}],
 Graphics3D@Point[data]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

---

I suspect *Mathematica* is doing a proper extrapolation, and it looks wrong because of the limitations of the data.  I would be surprised if it isn't just linear extrapolation.  You might consider the relationship of the features to the distribution of the data points, and perhaps the partial derivatives, especially `Plot3D[Evaluate@D[ifn[x, y], y], {x, 0.`, 30.`}, {y, 0.`, 20.`}]`.  The data has a sort of ragged edge near y = 0.9 for 0 < x < 20.  To make it look nice might be fudging, and the proper thing to do is to not extrapolate.  I'm hedging because I'm probably out of my field here, and there may be special techniques for extrapolating in your case.  If so, perhaps the `"ExtrapolationHandler"` option can be use to solve your problem.

Comment: Thank you for the elegant solution. +1

Comment: big +1 from me, this is the first I hear of `"ExtrapolationHandler"` - when I first saw the answer I thought it was a v9 workaround but it works perfectly in v8!

Answer (score 5):

The following code reproduces your problem minimally I think:

```
grid = RandomReal[{0, 20}, {500, 2}];
trigrid = Select[gr, #[[1]] < #[[2]] &];
vals = {Sequence @@ ##, Sin[ #[[1]]/3 - #[[2]]/2]} & /@ trigrid;
in = Interpolation[vals] // Quiet;
Show[{Plot3D[in[x, y], {x, 0, 20}, {y, 0, 20}, 
    RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, x < y]], 
   Graphics3D[Point[vals]]}] // Quiet
```

[image: interpolation]

And you ask: **"Is there a way to get `Interpolation` to perform a proper extrapolation for just a little margin beyond my data?"**

My guess is no and I would be happily contradicted on this. Regardless, you still have a couple of options.

- Add offsets as part of your `RegionFunction` and manually adjust them to get a satisfactory result:

  ```
  With[{offx = .3, offy = .4}, 
       Show[{Plot3D[in[x, y], {x, 0, 20}, {y, 0, 20}, 
           RegionFunction -> 
            Function[{x, y, z}, x < y && x > offx && 20 - offy > y]], 
          Graphics3D[Point[vals]]}] // Quiet]
  ```

[image: interpolation with offsets]

- Manually extrapolate yourself by adding extra points at the problematic boundaries. You can assign values to these points based on a `Nearest` function. The success of this greatly depends on how far from the data your boundaries are. Here, my problematic boundaries are at $ x=0 $ and at $ y=20 $ so I will create a nearest function that spits out $ z $ coordinates based on nearest values of $ x,y $ coordinates and then I will apply it to values of the $ x-y $ grid where the problems show up. Then I will re-interpolate with the added points:

  ```
  nf = Nearest[Thread[vals[[All, 1 ;; 2]] -> vals[[All, 3]]]];
  bdyX = Flatten[{##, nf@#}] & /@ Array[{0, #} &, 20 ];
  bdyY = Flatten[{##, nf@#}] & /@ Array[{#, 20} &, 20 ];
  in2 = Interpolation[vals~Join~bdyX~Join~bdyY];
  Show[{Plot3D[in2[x, y], {x, 0, 20}, {y, 0, 20}, 
  RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, x < y]], Graphics3D[Point[vals]]}] // Quiet
  ```

[image: interpolation with bdy]

You updated the question by adding data while I was writing this but I suggest that if you are satisfied with the minimal example I constructed, you replace your data with that. Assuming your actual data is stored in `yourdata`, the problem is for $ x = 30 $ and (mostly) for $ y = 0. $ So the nearest function and added boundaries should be

```
nf = Nearest[Thread[N@yourdata[[All, 1 ;; 2]] -> N@yourdata[[All, 3]]]]
bdyX = Flatten[{##, nf@#}] & /@ Array[{30, #} &, 20 ]
bdyY = Flatten[{##, nf@#}] & /@ Array[{#, 0} &, 30 ]
```

Now your data is in red and the added boundary points in blue:

```
ListPointPlot3D[{yourdata, bdyX~Join~bdyY}, PlotStyle -> {Red, Blue}]
```

[image: added boundary]

and your interpolation behaves better at the said boundaries(where I filter through `DeleteDuplicates` because there are overlapping values somewhere):

```
in3 = Interpolation[DeleteDuplicates[yourdata~Join~bdyX~Join~bdyY]]
Plot3D[in3[x, y], {x, 0, 30}, {y, 0, 20}, 
 RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, x > y] ]
```

[image: boundary fixed]

Comment: Thank you for the amazing effort and the interesting solutions you provided. Absolutely +1. The "ExtrapolationHandler" thing works better with other sets of data I have to plot, though.

Answer (score 2):

Another way is with `Nearest`. With `td` set to your data,

```
mnf = Nearest[{#[[1]], #[[2]]} -> #[[3]] & /@ td]

Show[
 ListPointPlot3D[td,PlotRange->All],
 Plot3D[mnf[{x,y}][[1]],{x,0,30},{y,0,20}]
]
```

[image]

You can smooth some of that lumpiness by averaging the nearest handful of points.

```
Show[
 ListPointPlot3D[td,PlotRange->All],
 Plot3D[Mean[mnf[{x,y},4]],{x,0,30},{y,0,20}]
]
```

[image]

Comment: The problem with relying on the nearest function is that it becomes really slow if you increase the plot points. It also, doesn't really go beyond zeroth order. Set the plot points to 60-70 in the plot 3d and you'll see what I mean.