# Difficulty with an initial value problem

Tags: differential-equations

The goal is to draw the solution of $y'(t)=y(t)^2-t,\ y(0)=3$, over the region $\{(t,y): -2\le t\le 10,\ -4\le y\le 4\}$. I've started with:

```
Clear[f, t]
f[t_, y_] := y^2 - t
vp = VectorPlot[{1, f[t, y]}, {t, -2, 10}, {y, -4, 4},
  VectorScale -> {0.03, 0.03, None},
  Frame -> False, Axes -> True, AxesLabel -> {"t", "y"}]
```

Which gives this image:

[image]

Then I tried:

```
sol = DSolveValue[{y'[t] == y[t]^2 - t, y[0] == 3}, y, t]
```

Which gives a weird complex solution. I tried adding it to my direction field.

```
Show[vp, Plot[sol[t], {t, -2, 10}]]
```

Which gives this image:

[image]

Notice that it does not satisfy the initial condition $y(0)=3$. Then I tried:

```
Show[vp, Plot[Re[sol[t]], {t, -2, 10}]]
```

Which produces this image:

[image]

Again, it does not satisfy the initial condition $y(0)=3$. What am I doing wrong? Am I making some type of mistake?

**Update:** I've managed to find an old discussion [How should I deal with messages being produced by my Manipulate?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/91534/how-should-i-deal-with-messages-being-produced-by-my-manipulate) which provides some help.

```
Clear[f, t]
f[t_, y_] := y^2 - t
vp = VectorPlot[{1, f[t, y]}, {t, -2, 10}, {y, -4, 4}, 
  VectorScale -> {0.03, 0.03, None}, Frame -> False, Axes -> True, 
  AxesLabel -> {"t", "y"}];
sol = NDSolveValue[{y'[t] == y[t]^2 - t, y[0] == 3, 
    WhenEvent[Abs[y[t]] > 4, "StopIntegration"]}, y, {t, -2, 2},
   "ExtrapolationHandler" -> {Indeterminate &, 
     "WarningMessage" -> False}];
Show[vp, Plot[sol[t], {t, -2, 10}]]
```

Which produces this image.

[image]

Which is correct. Also, note that

```
sol[0]
```

produces the answer 3.

I was also able to do this:

```
tbl = Table[
   NDSolveValue[{y'[t] == y[t]^2 - t, y[0] == b, 
     WhenEvent[Abs[y[t]] > 4, "StopIntegration"]}, y[t], {t, -2, 10},
    Method -> "StiffnessSwitching",
    "ExtrapolationHandler" -> {Indeterminate &, 
      "WarningMessage" -> False}], {b, -3, 3}];
Show[vp, Plot[tbl, {t, -2, 10}]]
```

Which produced this image.

[image]

However, a good question to still ask is about the ExtrapolationHandler. Could not find it in the documentation. Is it something that will continue to exist?

Comment: I tried it in maple and it gives solution in terms of Airy. $y \left( t \right) =-{\frac {{\it \_C1}\,{{\rm Ai}^{(1)}\left(t
\right)}+{{\rm Bi}^{(1)}\left(t\right)}}{{\it \_C1}\,{{\rm Ai}\left(t
\right)}+{{\rm Bi}\left(t\right)}}}
$. The numerical solution in maple satisfies the initial condition.

Comment: Re `ExtrapolationHandler`, have you tried searching the site??

Comment: @MichaelE2 Yes, there are lots of examples (some too advanced for me) on the site that I found helpful, particularly the one I put in the update to my original post, where you made some really helpful explanation. I just could not find ExtrapolationHandler in the Mathematica documentation helper.

Comment: I [first learned of it](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/30946/) in [this comment](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/28337/whats-inside-interpolatingfunction1-4/28341#comment88520_28341).  But `"ExtrapolationHandler"` seems to have nothing to do with the original question. Whether or not it might be closed as a duplicate, it probably is more viable as a separate question, as discussed on meta [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43478/) and [here](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1808/).

Answer (score 3):

It's a `Plot` peculiarity you can fix by giving an explicit `PlotRange`. For example, try

```
Plot[sol[t], {t, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> {{0, 2}, {-10, 10}}]
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not just use [*StreamPlot*](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StreamPlot.html)?

```
   StreamPlot[{1,y^2-t},{t,-5,10},{y,-4,4},StreamPoints->    
      {{{{0,3},Red},Automatic}},ImageSize->Large]
```

[image]