# How to make use of an interpolating function outside of Mathematica?

Tags: differential-equations, interpolation

I'm currently working on a project where I have to solve some partial differential equations. Initially, I made some approximations so that an analytic solution could be obtained, and my `C++` code is set up using values calculated from the analytic expression.

I've now used *Mathematica* to obtain a numerical solution (using `NDSolve`), and would like to be able to use the values in the `C++` code instead of the analytic expression. What would be the best way to approach this? (I don't want to use a `C++` PDE solver, because even setting up the PDEs took a large amount of algebraic manipulation which I had to do with *Mathematica*).

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT: Thanks for the suggestions. So you think the best route would be to essentially generate a grid and export it? I would need to be able to evaluate for values in between those which are exported though (chosen at random), and so I suppose I would then have to write my own interpolation scheme.

EDIT: Thanks George, that seems a good way of approaching it. I should have mentioned earlier the functions are functions of two variables, but your method should be adaptable.

Comment: You may want to consider looking into `MathLink`. This provides a simple way to send arrays generated in Mathematica to c++. http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/guide/MathLinkAPI.html

Comment: Check `NDSolve[{y'[x] + x == 1, y[0] == 0}, y, {x, 0, 1}] // InputForm`. Would that point list be useful to you?

Comment: Also check the help for `InterpolatingFunctionAnatomy`

Comment: @belisarius nice!. `InterpolatingFunctionValuesOnGrid` returns exactly the data in the `List@@@` mess in my answer.

Comment: one other thing, after all this it seems to me there may be performancwe advantages (on the c end) to generatating your own table data which is *regularly spaced* and sufficienty fine that you can just do linear interpolation.

Answer (score 4):

To get the polynomials, assuming (interpolation order == 3):

```
points = {{0, 0}, {1, 1}, {2, 3}, {3, 4}, {4, 3}, {5, 0}}; 
Needs["DifferentialEquations`InterpolatingFunctionAnatomy`"]
ifun = Interpolation[points]
coords = First[InterpolatingFunctionCoordinates[ifun]];
vals = InterpolatingFunctionValuesOnGrid[ifun];
grid = Transpose[{coords, vals}];
partGrid = Partition[grid, 4, 1];
pw = Piecewise@
     Join[ {{InterpolatingPolynomial[#,x], #[[1, 1]] <= x <  #[[-2, 1]]}} &@partGrid[[1]], 
      Table[{InterpolatingPolynomial[i,x], i[[2, 1]] <= x <  i[[-2, 1]]}, {i, partGrid[[2 ;; -2]]}], 
           {{InterpolatingPolynomial[#,x], #[[2, 1]] <= x <= #[[-1, 1]]}} &@partGrid[[-1]]]
```

[image]

Now replace for example

```
ifun = y /. NDSolve[{y''[x] + Sin[y[x]] y[x] == 0, y[0] == 1, y'[0] == 0}, y, {x, 0, 30}][[1, 1]];
```

And you get the interpolation polys for your diff eq.

**Edit**

`pw[[1, n, 1]]` gives you the poly number `n` and
`pw[[1, n, 2]]` gives you the range for that poly

Answer (score 3):

Sjoerd beat me with the comment, but since I worked it out, here is an example of pulling the data out of an interpolating functiom.

```
intf = y /. 
    First@NDSolve[{y'[x] == y[x] Cos[x + y[x]], y[0] == 1}, 
        y, {x, 0, 30}]
Show[{
    Plot[ intf[x], {x, 0, 30}, PlotStyle -> Red, PlotRange -> All] ,
    ListPlot[
       Transpose@{(List @@@ (intf // InputForm))[[1, 3, 1]],
                  (List @@@ (intf // InputForm))[[1, 4, 3, ;; ;; 2]]}]}, 
    PlotRange -> All]
```

The array positions are just by inspection

You could save that to a table and just do a lookup / linear interpolation in c.
(Really as a practical matter you could just generate a table without worrying about the actual interpolationfunction structure

```
   Table[ {x,intf[x]},  {x,range.._ ]
```

Comment: The standard way to get the data from interpolating functions is `intf["Grid"]` and `intf["ValuesOnGrid"]`.  You'll find these and more if you look in the ``DifferentialEquation`InterpolatingFunctionAnatomy`` package (belisarius's comment).  See all available methods using `intf["Methods"]`.  This is a safe way that's likely to work in future versions.  A direct dissection of the object could easily break in the future.

Comment: `InputForm` is just a wrapper that affects printing.  It's not means to be used this way, and it's unnecessary here.

Comment: Agreed. It is unfortunate that the docs for InterpolatingFunction don't mention any of this..

Comment: I agree.  The function docs should be sprinkled with many links to the relevant sections of the advanced docs.  It's mentioned [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/NDSolveOverview.html).

Comment: @george2079 You can find details on the structure of `InterpolatingFunction` and ways to access the internal data here: [What's inside InterpolatingFunction\[{{1., 4.}}, <>\]?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/28341)