# Solving a transcendental equation with two parameters

Tags: equation-solving

I'm trying to solve an equation for `T` where `T` and two parameters `M` and `S` are all positive.

I tried solving it by evaluating the following expression, but it just gives me the same expression back. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
Solve [M*S + (T/0.755) - (T/0.755)*cosh[M/(2T/0.755)] == 0, T]
```

Comment: First of all, `cosh` should be `Cosh`. Secondly, this is a transcendental equation that likely can't be solved analytically. You will probably need to use `FindRoot` with numbers in place of `M` and `S`.

Comment: can you give an example on how to do that? @march

Comment: Perhaps the following would be useful. Some algebra produces:             S = - (T/0.755)(1 - Cosh[2 T/0.755)/M, allowing S to be determined for any pair of {M,T}.  Then Plot3D could be used to show the values {M,T,S} that satisfy the equation.  e.g. Plot3D[-(T/0.755) ( 1 - Cosh[M/(2 T/0.755)] )/ M, {M, 0, 2}, {T, 0,  2}]

Answer (score 4):

One approach is to turn your equation into an ODE and then use [`NDSolve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NDSolve) to to integrate.

Here is your equation:

```
eqn = M S+(T/0.755)-(T/0.755)*Cosh[M/(2T/0.755)]==0;
```

This can be simplified by replacing `T` with `t M`:

```
seqn = Assuming[M>0, eqn /. T->t M //Simplify];
seqn //TeXForm
```

> $1.` S+1.3245033112582782` t=1.3245033112582782` t \cosh \left(\frac{0.37749999999999995`}{t}\right)$

This transcendental equation doesn't appear to be one that Mathematica can solve. However, we can turn the equation into an ODE and solve that:

```
ode = D[seqn /. t->t[S], S];
ode //TeXForm
```

> $1.3245033112582782` t'(S)+1.`=1.3245033112582782` t'(S) \cosh
>    \left(\frac{0.37749999999999995`}{t(S)}\right)-\frac{0.49999999999999994` t'(S) \sinh
>    \left(\frac{0.37749999999999995`}{t(S)}\right)}{t(S)}$

To use [`NDSolveValue`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NDSolveValue) we will also need an initial condition. For this we can use [`Solve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Solve):

```
t1 = t /. First @ Solve[seqn && 0<t<10 /. S->1, t]
```

> Solve::ratnz: Solve was unable to solve the system with inexact coefficients. The answer was obtained by solving a corresponding exact system and numericizing the result.
>
> 0.153051

Now, we are ready to use [`NDSolveValue`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NDSolveValue):

```
sol = NDSolveValue[{ode, t[1] == t1}, t, {S, 0, 10}];
```

> NDSolveValue::ndsz: At S == 9.521862063632699`*^-7, step size is effectively zero; singularity or stiff system suspected.

Here is a plot:

```
Plot[sol[t], {t, 0, 10}]
```

[image]

The corresponding solution for `T` is:

```
Tsol[s_, m_] := m sol[s]
```

Here is a [`Plot3D`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Plot3D) of the LHS of the equation showing that it is satisfied to less than 10^-4. Using exact inputs and higher accuracy/precision goals can produce a better result:

```
Plot3D[eqn[[1]] /. T->Tsol[S, M], {S, 0, 10}, {M, 0, 10}]
```

[image]

Comment: So what would be the formula for T if I want different values for M and S? @Carl Woll

Comment: The reason I want formula for T is because I want to use it in a android application to calculate value for T given values for M and S. Cheers

Comment: @JafferAlfahdawi You can look at questions like [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/37792/45431) for help in using NDSolve output outside of Mathematica.

Answer (score 3):

You can get a symbolic formula approximating the solution via Chebyshev series, which can be computed as shown in [About multi-root search in Mathematica for transcendental equations](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5663/about-multi-root-search-in-mathematica-for-transcendental-equations/89692#89692).

As @Carl Woll observed, your equation is a function of `m == M/T` and `S`.  If we solve for `m` as a function of `S`, we can then get a formula for `T = M/m`.

From a [comment](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/163009/solving-a-transcendental-equation-with-two-parameters#comment432025_163019), we get the domain for `S` needed to compute the Chebyshev series:

> M can be between 1 and 200 and S can be between 0.01 to 0.07.

Below, we used `FourierDCT` to compute the Chebyshev coefficients.  We have to find the values of `m` as `S` ranges over the Chebyshev nodes.  We use `FindRoot` to do this with high precision, so that we can construct a near machine-precision approximation to `m`, which is given by `m = mFN[S]`.

```
eqn = M S + (T/0.755) - (T/0.755)*Cosh[M/(2 T/0.755)] // Rationalize;
eqn3 = eqn/T /. {M -> m T} // Simplify; (* m == M/T, or T == M/m *)

Block[{n = 32, S1, S2, S, snodes, (*coeffs,*) coeffs2, mvals, m},
  {S1, S2} = Rationalize@{0.01, 0.07};  (* domain for S *)
  snodes = Rescale[Sin[Pi/2 Range[n, -n, -2]/n], {-1, 1}, {S1, S2}];
  mvals = m /. Rest@FoldList[
      FindRoot[eqn3 /. S -> #2, {m, m /. #1, 1/10, 1000}, WorkingPrecision -> 40] &,
      {m -> 10 Sqrt[S1]}, snodes];
  coeffs2 = Sqrt[2/n] FourierDCT[mvals, 1];
  coeffs2[[{1, -1}]] /= 2;
  coeffs = Drop[coeffs2,  (* drop coefficients smaller than machine precision *)
    Module[{sum = 0}, -LengthWhile[
       Reverse@coeffs2, (sum += Abs[#]) < Abs[First@coeffs2] $MachineEpsilon &]]];
  With[{s1 = S1, s2 = S2, cc = coeffs, k = Length@coeffs - 1},
   mFN = Function[{S},       (* solution for m *)
     cc.Cos[Range[0, k] ArcCos[Rescale[S, {s1, s2}, {-1, 1}]]]
     ]]
  ];

tFN = Function[{M, S}, M/mFN[S]];  (* solution for t *)
```

**Answer:**
Here is the double-precision formula for `t` that is an approximate solution to the OP's equation:

```
N[tFN[M, S]]   (* formula for t *)
(*
M/(0.4221956380745171` + 
   0.31559498734947056` (-1.3333333333333333` + 33.333333333333336` S) -
   0.0007452700193212066` Cos[2.` ArcCos[-1.3333333333333333` + 33.333333333333336` S]] -
   0.00008989046047576488` Cos[3.` ArcCos[-1.3333333333333333` + 33.333333333333336` S]] +
   9.349727403445521`*^-7 Cos[4.` ArcCos[-1.3333333333333333` + 33.333333333333336` S]] +
   6.316071780569096`*^-8 Cos[5.` ArcCos[-1.3333333333333333` + 33.333333333333336` S]] -
   1.2738992410763405`*^-9 Cos[6.` ArcCos[-1.3333333333333333` + 33.333333333333336` S]] -
   5.477086714861503`*^-11 Cos[7.` ArcCos[-1.3333333333333333` + 33.333333333333336` S]] +
   1.7873875250882988`*^-12 Cos[8.` ArcCos[-1.3333333333333333` + 33.333333333333336` S]] +
   4.9699383243064014`*^-14 Cos[9.` ArcCos[-1.3333333333333333` + 33.333333333333336` S]] -
   2.529762133661728`*^-15 Cos[10.` ArcCos[-1.3333333333333333` + 33.333333333333336` S]])
```

Simple check of accuracy: is there a small residual?

```
eqn /. T -> tFN[M, S] /. {M -> RandomReal[{1, 200}, 1000], 
    S -> RandomReal[{0.01, 0.07}, 1000]} // Abs // Max
(*  4.54747*10^-13  *)
```

Somewhat more sophisticated look: We compare the residual error with the largest of the three terms in `eqn`, divided by `$MachineEpsilon`:

```
Total[#, {2}]/Max /@ Abs[#] &@Transpose[
    List @@ eqn /. 
      T -> tFN[M, S] /. {M -> RandomReal[{1, 200}, 10000], 
      S -> RandomReal[{0.01, 0.07}, 10000]}
    ]/$MachineEpsilon //
 Histogram[#, Automatic, "LogCount",
   AxesLabel -> {"Error (ϵ)", "Count"},
   PlotLabel -> "Error distibution relative to largest term of eqn ε_mach"] &
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Almost half of the values, `4600` out of `10000`, have zero error. Most of the rest have a 1 ulp error.

**Update: avoiding transcendental functions**

I forgot to mention Clenshaw's recurrence for evaluating a Chebyshev series.  The code used in `mFN` is an efficient way to compute `mFN[S]` in the *Mathematica* computational environment, even with the trigonometric functions.  However, it is just a polynomial and can be computed without a math library.  The best way is to use the Clenshaw recurrence (see `chebeval` [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/108002/4999) for instance).

If desired, one can see the polynomial expression by changing the code for `mFM` to the following:

```
mFN = Function[{S}, cc.ChebyshevT[Range[0, k], Rescale[S, {s1, s2}, {-1, 1}]]]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you divide your equation by T you get an equation which can easily solved for S:

```
gl = M S + (T/0.755) - (T/0.755)*Cosh[M/(2 T/0.755)];
glT = Simplify[gl /T /. M -> mdT T ]
s[mdT_] := Evaluate[S /. Solve[glT == 0, S][[1]]]
Plot[s[mdT ], {mdT, -10, 10}, AxesLabel -> {m/T, S}](-1.3245 + 1.3245 Cosh[0.3775 M/T])/(M/T)
```

S is a function of M/T. There is no need to solve for T.

[image]

If you know the range of M,S you can use InverseSeries[] to get an approximation 
of the InverseFunction:

```
M/Normal[ InverseSeries[Series[s[mdT], {mdT, 0, 3}], S] ](* ~T *)
(* T=M/(10.596 S - 14.128 S^3) *)
```

Comment: M can be between 1 and 200 and S can be between 0.01 to 0.07. M is the span length of conductor between two poles and S is the conductor sag percentage and T is the tension of the conductor if that helps.