# Resonance Curve using NDSolve

Tags: equation-solving, differential-equations

I am trying to make a resonance curve like this one below, using NDSolve.

[image]

I tried to use code as below. Basically I try to hold solution for a w (driving frequency value) using NumericQ and then find the max amplitude using FindMaxValue when t is big enough. But my code returns a lot of error code I don't understand. By the way, I am using NDSolve directly, so I can test the accurateness of NDSolve Method.

```
ClearAll;

f[w_?NumericQ] := 
Block[{sol}, 
  sol = NDSolve[{x''[t] + x'[t] + x[t] == Cos[w*t], x[0] == 0, x'[0] == 0}, 
    x[t], {t, 0, 100}];
 (FindMaxValue[x[t], {t, 50}])[[1]]]

ListLinePlot[Table[f[w], {w, 0, 100, 1}], DataRange -> {0, 100}]
```

Comment: You need to define `sol=x[t] /. First@NDSolve[...]` and then use `sol` (not `x[t]`) subsequently.

The equation is simple enough and can be handled by `DSolve`. This might help your `FindMaxValue`.

Comment: When I attempt to solve your equation using DSolve, I get a decreasing max amplitude with increasing frequency (no real maximum).

Comment: Are you sure that curves aren't for the steady state only?

Comment: It works for me, with b.gatessucks' changes, except there are numerical issues with `FindMaxValue`.  The frequency $\omega_0$ is less than `1`, so the `ListLinePlot` doesn't show the peak.  `ParametricNDSolve` might be a good tool to use here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Given the nature of a forced, damped oscillator, an efficient way to approximate the resonance curve is to use [`WhenEvent`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/WhenEvent.html) (or [`EventLocator`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/NDSolveEventLocator.html)) to locate a maximum after the transient solution effectively vanishes.

```
Clear[amp];
amp[w_] /; w == 0 = 1.;
amp[w_?NumericQ] :=
 Block[{x},
  #[#["Domain"][[1, -1]]] &[
   x /. First@NDSolve[{
       x''[t] + x'[t] + x[t] == Cos[w*t], x[0] == 0, x'[0] == 0, 
       WhenEvent[x'[t] < 0 && t > 100, "StopIntegration"]}, 
      x, {t, 0, 100 + 3 Pi/w}]
   ]
  ];

Plot[amp[w], {w, 0, 2}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

We can extend it to a more general DE:

```
amp[w_, w0_?NumericQ, damping_?NumericQ] /; w == 0 = 1.;
amp[w_?NumericQ, w0_?NumericQ, damping_?NumericQ] :=
 Block[{x},
  #[#["Domain"][[1, -1]]] &[
   x /. First@NDSolve[{
       x''[t] + 2 damping w0 x'[t] + w0^2 x[t] == Cos[w*t],
       x[0] == 0, x'[0] == 0, 
       WhenEvent[x'[t] < 0 && t > 40/damping, "StopIntegration"]}, 
      x, {t, 0, 50/damping + 3 Pi/w}]
   ]
  ];

Plot[Evaluate[Table[amp[w, 1, z], {z, {1/2, 1/4, 1/8}}]], {w, 0, 2}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

---

**On the # and "Domain"**

The [`#`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users/25616#25616) is a `Slot`.  It represents the (first) argument of a [`Function`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Function.html) usually constructed with a `&` (often called a "pure function").  The argument is the solution `x /. First@NDSolve[..]`, which is an [`InterpolatingFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/InterpolatingFunction.html).

The `#[#["Domain"][[1, -1]]] &[ifn]` evaluates an `InterpolatingFunction` solution `ifn` at the end point of its domain (explained below).  In this case, the end point is the point at which the integration stopped, and it yields the maximum value of the solution to the differential equation. (Technically, it is a local maximum, which approximates the amplitude of the steady-state solution.)  An `InterpolatingFunction` might look something like this in a notebook:

```
ifn = x /. First@NDSolve[{
     x''[t] + x'[t] + x[t] == Cos[1.3 t], x[0] == 0, x'[0] == 0, 
     WhenEvent[x'[t] < 0 && t > 80, "StopIntegration"]}, 
    x, {t, 0, 100 + 3 Pi}]

(* InterpolatingFunction[{{0., 83.7484}}, <>] *)
```

Note that the domain is displayed.  Others have wondered what properties are inside `ifn` here: [What's inside InterpolatingFunction[{{1., 4.}}, <>]?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/28337/whats-inside-interpolatingfunction1-4) 
There are methods for accessing these properties through the `` "DifferentialEquations`InterpolatingFunctionAnatomy`" `` package, described in
[tutorial/NDSolvePackages](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/NDSolvePackages.html).  There are some shortcuts to these methods.  If `ifn` is an `InterpolatingFunction`, then the following lists them:

```
ifn["Methods"]

(* {"Coordinates", "DerivativeOrder", "Domain", "ElementMesh", 
    "Evaluate", "Grid", "InterpolationOrder", "MethodInformation", 
    "Methods", "Periodicity", "Properties", "QuantityUnits", 
    "ValuesOnGrid"} *)
```

They may be invoked by `ifn[method]`:

```
ifn["Domain"]
(* {{0., 83.7484}} *)
```

The point at which the maximum occurs is the end point of the domain, given by

```
ifn["Domain"][[1, -1]]
(* 83.7484 *)
```

To summarize, `#[#["Domain"][[1, -1]]] &[x /. First@NDSolve[..]]` is short for

```
ifn = x /. First@NDSolve[..];
ifn[ifn["Domain"][[1, -1]]]
```

which may be broken down further as

```
ifn = x /. First@NDSolve[..];
domains = ifn["Domain"];  (* domains of each independent variable *)
tdomain = First[domains]; (* the first domain *)
tfinal = Last[tdomain];   (* right end point of domain *)
ifn[tfinal]
```

**A note on the NDSolve parameters**

The amplitude of the transient solution decays as `Exp[-damping t]`.  The `40/damping` was chosen so that the amplitude would be extremely small, less than `10.^-16`, or equivalently, so that `t > 36.8414/damping`.  It was rounded up to `40`.  A slight gain in speed may be obtained by increasing this tolerance.  (For example, plotting was about 15-25% faster if the integration stops when `t > 20/damping` and the transient amplitude is less than `10^-8`.)

The interval of integration `{t, 0, 50/damping + 3 Pi/w}` has to extend at least one period beyond `40 / damping` when we start looking for a maximum.  The time `50/damping + 3 Pi/w` should be sufficiently large since `50/damping > 40/damping` and `3 Pi/w > 2 Pi/w`.  Since the integration stops before this, it doesn't really matter if a little extra is thrown in.

Comment: Thank you! But I am wondering what #[#["Domain"][[-1, -1]]] line means in the code..

Comment: @DadanAriWibowo You're welcome!  See update for further explanation

Comment: @MichaelE2 is there any way to plot steady state phase vs.  frequency curve without using direct formula?