# How to Plot the Steady State Phase Response Curve?

Tags: differential-equations, nonlinear

I have a code to plot the steady state frequency response curve (provided by @ Michael E2), How can I plot the steady state phase response with the help of this code same as shown in the figure:

[image: Steady state phase response obtained analytically].

```
\[Kappa]=1.4;
WE = 0.2;
\[Omega] = Sqrt[3*\[Kappa]*(1 + WE) - WE];
f = 0.2;
\[Epsilon] = 0.2;

amp[w_, w0_?NumericQ, damping_?NumericQ] /; w == 0 = 1.;
amp[w_?NumericQ, w0_?NumericQ, damping_?NumericQ] := 
  Block[{x}, #[#["Domain"][[1, -1]]] &[
    x /. First@
      NDSolve[{x''[
          T] == (1/\[Epsilon])*((((1 + 
                 WE)*(1 + \[Epsilon]*x[T])^(-3*\[Kappa] - 
                  1))) - ((1 + \[Epsilon]*
                 x[T])^-1) - (WE*(1 + \[Epsilon]*x[T])^-2) - (4*
              damping*\[Epsilon]^2*(x'[
                T])*(1 + (\[Epsilon]*
                   x[T]))^-2) - ((3*\[Epsilon]^2*(x'[
                   T]^2)*(1 + \[Epsilon]*x[T])^-1)/2) - \[Epsilon]^3*
             f*Sin[T* (w0 + \[Epsilon]^2 w)]), x[0] == 1, x'[0] == 0, 
        WhenEvent[x'[T] < 0 && T > 5000, "StopIntegration"]}, 
       x, {T, 0, 5010}]]];
 Off[NDSolve::ndsz]
pltNum = Plot[
  Evaluate[Table[
    amp[w, \[Omega], z], {z, {\[Epsilon]*0.04}}]], {w, -5, 5}, 
  PlotStyle -> {Thick, Dashed, Red}, 
  PlotLegends -> Placed[{"Numerical"}, {0.8, 0.8}], PlotRange -> All]
```

Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

The provided graph and the variables in the code are different. It is difficult to know what exactly you want to plot here.

[image]

If possible please share the link where you get the graph or the code. just sharing the author's name is not enough.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The plot you have shown here is correct (which I am getting from the code), but it is steady state amplitude vs frequency. I just want to plot steady state phase response. Is there any way (modification) that I could use the above code to plot the phase response curve.

Comment: I am sharing the [link](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/39011/resonance-curve-using-ndsolve) from where I got the code.