# I know the lower limit of an integration as well as the integral. How to find the upper limit of the integration?

Tags: numerical-integration

I used the following code.

```
NV[x1_, x2_] := NIntegrate[3 x^2, {x, x1, x2}]

FindRoot[NV[0, t] == 3, {t, .001}, PrecisionGoal -> 20]
```

Output:

> NIntegrate::nlim: x = t is not a valid limit of integration. >> {t ->
>   1.44225}

The output is correct.

However, I want to remove the comment: "x = t is not a valid limit of integration. >>" from the output.

Comment: Use `NV[x1_?NumericQ, x2_?NumericQ] := ...` instead of `NV[x1_,x2_]`.

Comment: You can take a look at `Quiet` if you have faith in the solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nasser gave a fine and simple enough approach. I will propose a different, not that it is better, but just to give another view.

So, if in general you have an integral `y[t]==Integrate[f[x],{x,0,t}]`, it is equivalent to the differential equation: `y'[t]=f[t]` with the initial condition `y[0]==0`. You might solve it numerically and then find the solution of the equation `y[t]==J`, where `J`is the integral value you are assumed to know. Its solution yields the upper integral limit being looked for.

Let `f[x]=x^2`. Then the solution of the differential equation is

```
nds = NDSolve[{y'[t] == t^2, y[0] == 0}, y, {t, 0, 3}][[1, 1]];
```

and the upper integral limit is given by the following:

```
    FindRoot[(y[t] /. nds) == 1, {t, 0.01}] // Quiet

(*  {t -> 1.44225}   *)
```

I do not see any advantage with respect to the approach of Nasser, but it was interesting to me that one may operate also this way.

Have fun!

Answer (score 3):

If a highly accurate solution is desired, I would follow kguler's comment; otherwise, here is a variation on Alexei Boulbitch's approach:

```
sol = NDSolveValue[{y'[x] == 3 x^2, y[0] == 0, WhenEvent[y[x] == 3, "StopIntegration"]},
   y, {x, 0, 3}];
sol["Domain"][[1, -1]]
(*  1.44225  *)
```

Or somewhat more directly:

```
Catch @ NDSolve[{y'[x] == 3 x^2, y[0] == 0, WhenEvent[y[x] == 3, Throw[x]]}, {}, {x, 0, 3}]
(*  1.44225  *)
```

Comment: Please comment what is "Domain". I like your approach very much.

Comment: @AlexeiBoulbitch Please see [this answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/28337/whats-inside-interpolatingfunction1-4/28341#28341) for information about `"Domain"` and other properties of `InterpolatingFunction`.  Briefly, `"Domain"` returns a list of intervals, one for each input to the I-Fn specifying its domain.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do numerical integration with upper limit being symbol. Just use Integrate instead

```
ClearAll[t, x, x1, x2, nv]
nv[x1_, x2_] := Integrate[3 x^2, {x, x1, x2}]
FindRoot[nv[0, t] == 3, {t, .001}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: But i have some integration where I must have to use NIntegrate. Otherwise it cant be solved