# Compute integral range given integral value

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration

Is there an easy way in mathematica to approximate $x$ such that $A = \int^{x}_0 f(x) dx$? (where $A$ and $f$ are given)

I am sorry if it is trivial.

Comment: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/121986/numerically-solving-an-equation-in-which-variable-is-the-upper-limit-of-an-integ or https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/75782/i-know-the-lower-limit-of-an-integration-as-well-as-the-integral-how-to-find-th

Answer (score 1):

You can do the integration, then use `Solve` to solve for `x`

```
f[x_] := 1 + x + x^2;
A = 10;
int = Integrate[f[t], {t, 0, x}];
eq = A == int
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
sol = Solve[eq, x]//N
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Check:

```
Integrate[f[t], {t, 0, x /. #}] & /@ sol // Chop
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: I was actually looking for the numerical way of doing this, adding an N to solve and integrate doesn't work. However, @Moo linked the answer above.