# Build an InterpolatingFunction with ElementMeshInterpolation

Tags: interpolation, finite-element-method

Suppose you have a function

```
f[t_, x_, y_] := t (1 - x^2 - y^2)
```

defined for `{x,y}` in  `Disk[]` and an `ElementMesh` of that Region

```
<< NDSolve`FEM`
mesh = ToElementMesh[Disk[]]
```

You can evaluate the function for some `t` at the vertices and nodes of the mesh:

```
coords = mesh["Coordinates"];
values = f[0, Sequence@@#]& /@ coords;
```

and then build an InterpolatingFunction with:

```
ElementMeshInterpolation[{mesh}, values]
```

Now suppose you have a list of times:

```
tl = Range[0, 1, 0.05];
```

you can evaluate the function for all times and all mesh nodes:

```
values = Table[f[t, Sequence @@ ##] & /@ coords, {t, tl}];
```

But it is possible to build a **single** `InterpolatingFunction` from these data, accepting `x,y,t` as arguments?

I know I can do somethiong like

```
Interpolation@Flatten[Table[{t, Sequence @@ xy, f[t, Sequence @@ xy]}, {t, 
   tl}, {xy, coords}], 1]
```

ignoring some warning, but I don't think this method can take advantage of a previously built 2nd order `ElementMesh`, so I'm searching another way, basically the same way used when NDSolve handle a transient equation.

Comment: I guess you could build a list of 2D interpolating functions using `ElementMeshInterpolation`, and then interpolate between their values in `t`?

Comment: I tried to look at the documentation for the `ElementMeshInterpolation `and failed. Could you kindly give a hint, where and how can I get it?

Comment: @AlexeiBoulbitch You can find some sample [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/FEMDocumentation/tutorial/FiniteElementProgramming.html) but unfortunately all the samples are only for stationary problems (search for "post-process"). A time-dependent case is missing.

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't want to build a 3D mesh of the whole region directly at the start and then interpolate over that? Otherwise, doing that seems like the simplest option.

Comment: @Virgil What if you want to extend to a `f[t, x, y, z]`?

Comment: Out of curiosity, what do you use as the time integrator, 'NDSolve`?

Comment: @user21 At present I want to use this feature to represent the 3 components of a time-dependent 3D vector field with unknown analytical form, in a way consistent with the `ElementMesh` I will later use to solve a PDE, of wich the field is a source term, with `NDSolve` and FEM. Maybe I also need to use the feature to represent the solution obtained with a custom, simple, non-standard time integration method, but I still need to do some test.

Comment: @unlikely, thanks. Good to know what the application is.

Answer (score 6):

Somewhat manual construction:

```
<< NDSolve`FEM`
mesh = ToElementMesh[Disk[], MaxCellMeasure -> Infinity];
tl = Range[0, 1, 0.2];
mesh3 = MeshOrderAlteration[
   With[{gc = ElementMeshToGraphicsComplex@MeshOrderAlteration[mesh, 1]},
    gc /. GraphicsComplex[pts_, g_, o___] :>
      ToElementMesh[
       "Coordinates" -> Flatten[
         PadLeft[pts, {Automatic, 3}, #] & /@ tl,
         1],
       "MeshElements" -> {TetrahedronElement[
          Flatten[
           Table[
             Cases[g, 
              Polygon[
                lis_] :> (lis /. 
                 tri : {_Integer, _Integer, _Integer} :>
                  With[{p = Join[tri + (n - 1) Length@pts, tri + n Length@pts]},
                   {p[[{1, 4, 5, 6}]], p[[{1, 5, 2, 6}]], p[[{2, 3, 1, 6}]]}
                   ]),
              Infinity],
             {n, Length[tl] - 1}],
           3]
          ]}
       ]
    ], 2];

mesh3["Wireframe"]
```

[image]
[image]

```
f[t_, x_, y_] := t (1 - x^2 - y^2)
values = f @@ Transpose[mesh3["Coordinates"]];
emifn = ElementMeshInterpolation[{mesh3}, values];

ContourPlot3D[f[t, x, y] == 0.1, {t, 0.`, 1.`}, {x, -1., 1.}, {y, -1., 1.}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

*Notes*

The ordering for the tetrahedra was deduced from this decomposition of a prism on a triangular base:

```
foo = ToElementMesh[
   DiscretizeGraphics[
    gc = GraphicsComplex[
      {{0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 1}},
      Polygon[{{1, 2, 3}, {6, 5, 4}, {1, 2, 5, 4}, {2, 3, 6, 5}, {3, 1, 4, 6}}]]
    ],
   MaxCellMeasure -> Infinity, "MeshOrder" -> 1];
foo["Coordinates"]
foo["MeshElements"]
(*
  {{0., 0., 0.}, {1., 0., 0.}, {0., 1., 0.}, {0., 1., 1.}, {1., 0., 1.}, {0., 0., 1.}}

  {TetrahedronElement[{{1, 6, 5, 4}, {1, 5, 2, 4}, {2, 3, 1, 4}}]}
*)
```

I tried `RegionProduct` but I either got errors or could not make the resulting mesh be the product of the meshes.

Reducing the mesh order to 1, forming the product, then bumping back up to 2 was easier than figuring out how to order the vertices of an order-2 tetrahedron.  Surely it can be done, but this seemed easier/lazier.

Answer (score 6):

I like the answer of @Michael E2 but I'm still searching, if available, a simpler way. Experimenting I found this way. My way probably can be applied also for a 3D mesh/region.

The data to interpolate:

```
<< NDSolve`FEM`
f[t_, x_, y_] := t (1 - x^2 - y^2);
mesh = ToElementMesh[Disk[]];
coords = mesh["Coordinates"];
tl = Range[0, 1, .05];
values = Table[f[t, Sequence @@ ##] & /@ coords, {t, tl}];
```

Building the interpolating function:

```
if = NDSolveValue[{D[u[t, x, y], t] == 0, u[0, x, y] == 0}, u, 
     Element[{x, y}, mesh], {t, tl[[1]], tl[[-1]]}, 
     Method -> "FiniteElement"]

if = If[if[[2, 1]] != 5, $Failed, 
  ReplacePart[if, {
    {2, 3} -> 0, (* no derivatives provided *)
    {2, 4, 1} -> Length@tl,(* actual grid points along t *)
    {3, 1} -> tl, (* actual grid along t *)
    {4} -> List /@ values (* values to interpolate *)
    }]]
```

Apprently this works:

```
Manipulate[
 Plot3D[if[t, x, y], {x, y} \[Element] mesh, 
  PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}, {0, 1}}], {t, 0, 1}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I'm not completely satisfied with this approach because it relies on the undocumented internal structure of the `InterpolatingFunction` (partially revealed by [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/28337/whats-inside-interpolatingfunction1-4), thanks!) and I completely ignore if it's "safe" to "tamper" with this internal structure (maybe `Interpolation` or `NDSolve` build also some private data accompaining the returned `InterpolatingFunction`?).

## NOTE

I'm more confident with the the time variable after the space variables x,y so I also tried with:

```
NDSolveValue[{D[u[x, y, t], t] == 0, u[x, y, 0] == 0}, u, 
  Element[{x, y}, mesh], {t, tl[[1]], tl[[-1]]}, 
  Method -> "FiniteElement"]
```

Unfortunately I get this message

```
Drop::drop: Cannot drop positions 3 through 3 in {ElementMesh[{{1.,5.26062*10^-22},{0.990147,0.14003},{0.960783,0.2773},{0.91339,0.407085},<<43>>,{0.990147,-0.14003},{-0.601496,-0.540192},{-0.725006,-0.512798},<<951>>},<<2>>,{PointElement[{{1},<<49>>,<<46>>}]}],{<<1>>}}. >>
```

and soon the Kernel crahes. I think in the past I successfully used this standard...

## UPDATE

Thanks to @user21 comment the following approach **will** be available with the next release.

```
values = Partition[values, 1];
Dimensions[values] == {Length@tl, 1, Length@mesh["Coordinates"]}
if = ElementMeshInterpolation[{tl, mesh}, values]
```

Comment: Clearly something like this is done for solutions to transient PDEs.  I kept thinking I could hit on the right combinations of arguments to `ElementMeshInterpolation` to achieve it; but I'm thinking now it is done internally on such a low level as you've done, and there is no ``FEM` `` function that we can use.

Comment: @MichaelE2, I added an example to the FiniteElementProgramming tutorial that shows how to do it. That will be available in the next release. If you do have  FEM related questions, feel free to @ me.

Comment: @user21 Good news!

Comment: @user21 Thank you very much.

Comment: @user21 It is possible to have even a vague and short idea of how to do that even before the release of the new Mathematica version?

Comment: @unlikely, `ElementMeshInterpolation[{tRange, mesh}, data]` will work, Where `Length[mesh["Coordinates"]]` is `A` and `Length[tRange]` `B` and `Dimensions[data]` is `{B,1,A}`

Comment: @user21 Thanks you very much.

Comment: @user21 Following your last comment, I tried to do what I wrote in the "Update" section, but the Kernel crashes. I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: @unlikely, the comment says this *will* be supported in the next update but it is not right supported right now (V10.1)

Comment: @unlikely, here is what I'd do: write a small function `MakeElementInterpolation` that for now uses one of the techniques of the answers and then replace that with the up coming solution.

Comment: @user21 Sorry, my understanding was that it was already supported but not yet documented and that the documentation will be updated for the next release.

Comment: @user21 I tried to apply my own answer to my real scenario, waiting for a suppoerted way. Unfortunately the resulting `InterpolatingFunction` show some strange behavior. Calling some property like `"ValuesOnGrid"` causes the Kernel to crash. Maybe this is related with a similar Kernel crash as reported in my question http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/85309/kernel-crash-while-using-valuesongrid-method-of-interpolatingfunction?noredirect=1#comment231689_85309...

Comment: @unlikely, I am sorry to hear that and apploogize for the trouble that this causes you. I'll file this as a bug.