# Kernel Crash while using "ValuesOnGrid" method of InterpolatingFunction

Tags: differential-equations, bugs, interpolation, crash, finite-element-method

**Bug introduced in 10.0.0 and fixed in 10.2.0**

---

I was experiencing some kernel crash while using `"ValuesOnGrid"` method of an `InterpolatingFunction` returned by `NDSolve` as a solution of a 3D time-dependent problem.

After some research I discovered this is related with my need of persisting the solution of `NDSolve`. Because I need to exchange the solution between different platforms, and because the solution is really part of an `Association` which contains also several aspects and statistics about solution process, the most natural way to serialize this `Association` was the `WDX` format.

The minimal code to reproduce the kernel crash (on Windows 8.1 x64 with Mathematica 10.1) is the following:

```
if = NDSolveValue[{D[u[t, x, y, z], t] == 0, u[0, x, y, z] == 0}, 
  u, {x, y, z} \[Element] Ball[], {t, 0, 1}, 
  Method -> "FiniteElement"] 
if["ValuesOnGrid"] // Dimensions (* OK *)
Export["if.wdx", if];

if = Import["if.wdx"];
if["ValuesOnGrid"] (* Kernel crash *)
```

What is the proper way to cross-platform serialize an `Association` containg some `InterpolatingFunction` returned by `NDSolve` FiniteElement method for ad 3D time-dependent problem?

Comment: What if you `Compress[]` your `InterpolatingFunction[]`?

Comment: @Guesswhoitis.Unfortunately the problem persists.

Comment: looks like a bug in the relatively new code for interpolating functions on unstructured grids (you might want to report to WRI). You could see whether saving and storing to .mx format would work, that seems to work for me (and would even be faster). AFAIK .mx is nowadays only different on 32bit and 64bit machines so chances should be large that you can load them on another machine. If that wouldn't work you'd probably have to store the pure data (Grid and ValuesOnGrid and probably some derivative info) and reconstruct the interpolating function...

Comment: @AlbertRetey MX is shareable between 64bit Linux and Windows machines?

Comment: @AlbertRetey About storing "pure data". I tried `Export["if.wdx",List@@if]` and later `InterpolatingFunction@@Import["if.wdx"]` without success

Comment: Yes, as of V10 only 32-bit vs 64-bit matters for `.mx` files, so they would be compatible between 64-bit Linux, Windows and MacOS X.

Comment: as ilian said the documentation sais yes, this should work if both are 64bit. I would try that before relying on that feature, though, especially as you  have seen problems with .wdx for this specific case...

Comment: @AlbertRetey Still about pure data... The strange is `Export["if.wdx",if]; if2=Import["if.wdx"]; SameQ[if,if2]` gives `True` but `if2["ValuesOnGrid"]` crashes. How can be possible? So frustrating these crashes...

Comment: my suspection is that there is some internal state behind the scenes which is not transfered correctly to the exported expression or not correctly reestablished when importing. I don't know if any of this is documented or meant to be seen by users at all.

Comment: Unfortunately persisting in MX format is not a solution in my real, more complex problem. The Kernel crashes still persist.

Comment: @unlikely A bug report has already been opened for the wdx issue, but could you perhaps also forward the larger mx crashing example to support?

Comment: @unlikely, yes, please forward the mx file crash to support.

Answer (score 9):

This crash has been fixed in version 10.2.

```
In[1]:= if = NDSolveValue[{D[u[t, x, y, z], t] == 0, u[0, x, y, z] == 0},       
           u, {x, y, z} \[Element] Ball[], {t, 0, 1},                           
           Method -> "FiniteElement"];                                          

In[2]:= Export["if.wdx", if];                                                   

In[3]:= if = Import["if.wdx"];                                                  

In[4]:= if["ValuesOnGrid"] // Dimensions                                        

Out[4]= {21, 11054}
```