# Export NDSolve results

Tags: plotting, export

I can see the correct result of my `NDSolve` when I plot them with large `PlotPoints`.

```
Plot[sol[[1, 14]], {t, 19, 20}, PlotPoints -> 2500, PlotRange -> All]
Plot[sol[[1, 14]], {t, 19, 20}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

I want to export the result as .mat or .xlsx but by using `Table` even with a very very small step I cannot get the correct results.

```
dt = 1/15000;
Export["Asun.mat", Table[sol[[1, 14]], {t, 19, 20, dt}]]
```

[image]

Comment: How could you ? Aren't you supposed to use `sol[[1, 14]]` instead of `sol[[1, 19]]` ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If `s` is produced by something like

```
s = NDSolveValue[sys, x, {t, 0, tf}]
```

producing

```
(*InterpolatingFunction[{{0., 20.}}, <>] *)
```

the raw data used by `InterpolatingFunction` can be extracted by

```
{s["Grid"], s["ValuesOnGrid"]}
```

and exported.  (See [28337](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/28337/whats-inside-interpolatingfunction1-4) for more data that can be extracted.)

Answer (score 3):

### Exporting the points used by `Plot`

```
Export["Asun.mat", 
 InputForm[
   Plot[sol[[1, 14]], {t, 19, 20}, PlotPoints -> 2500, 
    PlotRange -> All]][[1, 1, 1, 3, 2, 1]]]
```

should export all the points shown in your first plot.

---

### Finding a suitable fixed interval

`Plot` is using an adaptive algorithm to find determine the sample points.
You should check the *Details and Options* section of the [documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Plot.html?q=Plot) about this. Here I just want to point out that one should also try to increase the settings for [`MaxRecursion`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MaxRecursion.html) and that the resulting sampling is not equidistant, as the interval length is reduced around rapid oscillations.

If you want to get an `Export` with fixed interval while making sure no details get lost, you can set you `dt` to the smallest interval used by `Plot`

```
dt = Min @ Differences[
      FullForm[Plot[sol[[1, 14]], {t, 19, 20}, PlotPoints -> 2500, 
          PlotRange -> All]][[1, 1, 1, 3, 2, 1]][[All, 1]]]
```

and then use your

```
Export["Asun.mat", Table[sol[[1, 14]], {t, 19, 20, dt}]]
```

Comment: Thank you. It is working.
 is there any way to do it with a fixed interval?

Comment: @Ali I extended my answer in order to address your fixed interval question. You should note, that for a very small interval using a rational number is advised. In such a situation you can get a rational interval with `dt = Rationalize[dt, 0]`.

Answer (score 1):

```
Needs["DifferentialEquations`InterpolatingFunctionAnatomy`"];
iii = sol[[1, 14, 0]];
coords = InterpolatingFunctionCoordinates[iii];
valus = InterpolatingFunctionValuesOnGrid[iii];
```

Comment: If you'll take a look at the package's source, you'll see that it's doing the same thing as bb's answer.

Comment: @J.M. I checked his answer as the correct one.
I just added this as a straight forward solution before being confused with the whole package.