# What is a good way to import interpolating functions of large size?

Tags: export, import

I was generating a set of eigenfunctions from a differential equation using `NDEigensystem`. Because of the computer time cost is too high, I thought it'd be better if I exported the data (which means the interpolating functions) to a file so I can import it anytime later without extra calculation.

Here is my code;

```
V[r_] = -(1/r) - (1.0415223038416566` E^(-0.9990999998788636` r))/r; 
α = 2.;
Module[{shift = 10, d = 2000, n = 20, ev, evShifted}, 
  {ev, ef} = 
    NDEigensystem[
     {shift f[r] + V[r] f[r] - 1/α f''[r], 
      DirichletCondition[f[r] == 0, True]}, 
     f, {r, 0, d}, n, 
     Method -> 
       {"SpatialDiscretization" -> 
          {"FiniteElement", {"MeshOptions" -> {"MaxCellMeasure" -> 0.001}}}, 
        "Eigensystem" -> {"Arnoldi", MaxIterations -> Infinity}}];
  evShifted = ev - shift]
Export["C:\\Users\\ASUS\\Documents\\TestDATA_efHQ.dat", ef, "Table"];
```

The total size of my exported file `"TestDATA_efHQ.dat"` is up to 4GB. When I tried to import it back, it drained my 12GB memory instantly and cost me almost 3 hours before the kernel failed.

I did try `ReadList` once, but it generated a stream which I don't know how to convert to an `InterpolatingFunction`, so I cut it before it's finished.

If anyone knows how to speed up this process or has suggestions about exporting and importing `InterpolatingFunction` objects, I'd be very grateful to hear what they have to say. I haven't try to export my data into some different format, such as binary, so if that would make this quicker, please let me know.

BTW, while I was using this method to do some integrations and calculate some function values, I found that for eigenfunctions with higher resolution, the method has better convergence and also gives higher accuracy than other methods I have tried.

Comment: Try [`DumpSave`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DumpSave.html) perhaps. The results may not be portable across platforms, but since you only need to save your result for your own later use on your system, it should be fine.

Comment: Also related: [How do I save a variable or function definition to a file?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1959/how-do-i-save-a-variable-or-function-definition-to-a-file) and [Export NDSolve results](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/87218/27951).

Comment: The structure InterpolatingFunctions are not documented and are subject to change between versions.

Comment: @MarcoB It's very helpful,thank you.`DumpSave` slightly increase the exporting time but significantly reduce the size and the import time.

Comment: @hys.0515 I'm glad that it helped!

Comment: @Searke My MMA version is 10.3.1.BTW,`NDEigensystem` is a new function only appearing in MMA 10 and higher version.