# Getting numerical values from integrated interpolating function

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, interpolation, list-manipulation

I have a list of data. I integrate them with interpolation. Lets say is the following:

```
  InterpolatingFunction[{{0.01, 4.82}}, <>][x]
```

However, is that anyway for me to get an array of coordinates of the function after integration?

Thank you

Comment: See http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/28337/whats-inside-interpolatingfunction1-4 -- And there are examples in most of the answers found in this search: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/search?q=InterpolatingFunction+coordinates

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not quite sure what you want but this may help.
First I generate some data

```
data = Table[{x, x + Sin[2 \[Pi] x]}, {x, 0.01, 4.82, 0.1}];
```

This plots as

```
ListPlot[data, Frame -> True, PlotTheme -> "Scientific"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Now we make an interpolation function and then integrate

```
f = Interpolation[data];
g = Integrate[f[x], x]
```

Interestingly the x from the integration gets built in to the new fuction. Someone might like to explain this

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I remove the [x] at the end by taking the head

```
g1 = Head[g];
```

Now we can plot the integrated function

```
p1 = Plot[g1[x], {x, 0.01, 4.82}, Frame -> True, 
  PlotTheme -> "Scientific"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

If we want to go back to coordinates then there are several ways. If we wish to use the same x values as before then can do the following

```
cc = Transpose[{data[[All, 1]], g1[#] & /@ data[[All, 1]]}];
```

and plot

```
Show[p1, ListPlot[cc, PlotStyle -> {Green}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Is this what you are after?

Comment: Yes! thank you very much!!!:)

Comment: @YinchengLiu I am glad I could help. The usual procedure is for you to accept the answer by applying the tick and thus closing the discussion.