# Using FindMaximum on one component of a vector-valued function

Tags: differential-equations, mathematical-optimization, interpolation

I've got a physics simulation that uses `NDSolve` and returns a vector-valued `InterpolationFunction`, by which I mean that the `InterpolationFunction` takes one scalar variable representing time and returns a list of two scalar numbers representing x and y coordinates:

```
r[0.1]
(* ==> {0.809018, 0.587785} *)
```

It's easy to extract just one component of the function's return value:

```
r[0.1][[1]]
(* ==> 0.809018 *)
```

Now, the problem. I'm trying to find the time at which one particular coordinate is maximal. If I had a normal, single-valued function for the x-coordinate, I'd just do this:

```
FindMaximum[x[t],{t,0.95}]
(* ==> {6.28315, {t -> 1.00003}} *)
```

However, I can't figure out how to make `FindMaximum` pay attention to just one component of the vector function. This fails:

```
FindMaximum[v[t][[2]], {t, 0.95}]
(* ==> Part 2 of InterpolatingFunction[...][t] does not exist. *)
```

So does this, and every similar variant I've tried:

```
FindMaximum[v[#][[2]] &, {t, 0.95}]
(* ==> FindMaximum::nrnum: The function value -(v[#1][[2]]&) is not a real number at {t} = {0.95}. *)

FindMaximum[(v[#] &)[[2]], {t, 0.95}]
(* ==> Part 2 of v[#1]& does not exist. *)
```

It seems that `Part` is being applied before the function is evaluated, no matter what I do. Can I change that?

**Update:** A more general, and probably more useful question, is: How can I separate a vector-valued (list-returning) `InterpolationFunction` into separate single-valued functions, which I could then use with `FindMaximum` or other *Mathematica* functions that require a single-valued function for an argument?

Comment: Maybe `Evaluate[v[t][[2]]]`?

Comment: Why not define `x[t_?NumericQ] := r[t][[1]]` and maximize that? Or... since you're using `NDSolve[]`, why not use event detection to get the maximum    as a side effect of solving your DE?

Comment: I don't use event detection because I'm generating some solution trajectories and then doing a whole range of after-the-fact exploratory investigation of the solutions, of which finding minima and maxima are only one small part.

Comment: @J.M. your `x[t_?NumericQ]` fixes the error. Can you please explain why is it needed at all? The  `_NumericQ` is essential.

Comment: I also thought of defining `x[t_] := r[t][[1]]` and maximize that, but it also fails for a reason I don't fully understand. I'll post that as an update to the original question. Including `?NumericQ` doesn't make it work for me.

Comment: @BlacKow, see [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/26037).

Comment: @ibeatty, can you come up with a (hopefully minimal) example where the inclusion of `?NumericQ` does not work?

Comment: @J.M. Thank you!

Comment: @J.M. Okay, `x[t_?NumericQ]` does in fact work for me. Apparently I had a stale definition of `x[t_]` hanging around mucking things up, but when I did `Clear[x]`, your solution started working for me. (Thanks!) I'll read up on why `NumericQ` does what it does...

Comment: For anybody interested in the question of how to fillet a vector-valued `InterpolatingFunction[]` into its components, [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/28337) might be useful.