# Adams predictor-corrector method default order

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, implementation-details

When I select the `"Adams"` method in `NDSolve` what is the default order? And how may I change the order?

Comment: Have you seen this: https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolvePlugIns.html ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The order is variable. Based on [What's inside InterpolatingFunction[{{1., 4.}}, <>]?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/28337/whats-inside-interpolatingfunction1-4), the following shows the order at each step.  Note that the first few steps are `NDSolve` getting its bearings before the first Adams steps (order 4).  With `InterpolationOrder -> All`, the solution is returned with local series for the Adams steps. Their length should be one more than the order of the step, I think.  The documentation says it should be the "same order as the underlying method used."

```
adamssol = NDSolve[{x''[t] + x[t]^3 == t, x[0] == 1, x'[0] == 0}, 
   x, {t, 0, 3 π}, Method -> "Adams", InterpolationOrder -> All];
adamsifn = x /. First@adamssol

ListPlot[
 {Transpose@{Flatten@adamsifn["Grid"],
    Map[Length, adamsifn[[4]]] - 1},    (* ifn[[4]] = local series coefficients *)
  Transpose@{Flatten@adamsifn["Grid"], 
    Rescale[#, MinMax[#], {0, 12}] &@adamsifn["ValuesOnGrid"]}
  },
 Joined -> {False, True},
 Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {"t", "order"}, 
 FrameTicks -> {Automatic, Range@12}, GridLines -> {None, Automatic}
 ]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]
>
> *The order of each step (in blue), with the rescaled solution plotted over it (in gold).*

The maximum order may be limited with the submethod option `"MaxDifferenceOrder"`, which must be set to an integer from 1 through 12; 
the minimum order cannot be set:

```
NDSolve[{x''[t] + x[t]^3 == t, x[0] == 1, x'[0] == 0}, x,
 {t, 0, 3 π}, Method -> {"Adams", "MaxDifferenceOrder" -> 6}, 
 InterpolationOrder -> All]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]
>
> *The order of each step with `"MaxDifferenceOrder" -> 6` (in blue), with the rescaled solution plotted over it (in gold).*