# How can I get a discrete result from NDSolve?

Tags: differential-equations, interpolation, fourier-analysis

When I use `NDsolve` to solve a differential equations, it returns an interpolation function of the discrete result. Because I haven't found another way to do Fourier analysis with an interpolation function, it seems I have to do the Fourier transform with `Fourier`. In my opinion, the process

$\qquad$ discrete result$\rightarrow$ iterpolation function$\rightarrow$ discrete result

will cause severe loss or distortion of the information. So I want to find a way to directly get the discrete result of a differential equations.

My differential equations is like this:

```
H = {{1, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 2, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 3, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 4}};
Rho[t_] := Array[Subscript[rho, #1] &, {4}]
t0 = Table[j/10, {j, 1, 10}];
tf[t_] = t + 0.5;
solutionvec = 
 Table[s = 
   NDSolve[LogicalExpand[
     D[Rho[t], t] == H.Rho[t] && Rho[t0[[j + 1]]] == {1, 0, 0, 0}], 
    Flatten[Table[Subscript[rho, i], {i, 1, 4}]], {t, t0[[j + 1]], 
     tf[t0[[j + 1]]]}, MaxStepSize -> 1/100, MaxSteps -> Infinity, 
    PrecisionGoal -> Infinity, WorkingPrecision -> 30];
   {Evaluate[Rho[tf[t0[[j + 1]]]] /. s]}, {j, 0, 9}]
```

This equations doesn't work, but it can show the thing I'm deal with.

Please help me.

Comment: You are much more likely to get help if you give a simple example of the sort of differential equation you are using.

Comment: Your example doesn't work properly, please recheck it. Also, notice `NDSolve` doesn't usually use constant step size for solving ODE, while `Fourier` assumes uniform sampling, so I don't think directly extracting discrete from `NDSolve` is suitable for solving your problem.

Comment: Bettertomo,  welcome to mma.se. We suggest, as you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. Please take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)  and check the [faqs!](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)  Please remember, when you see good questions and answers, to vote them up by clicking the [gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), and to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem by clicking the [checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t).

Comment: @xzczd, thank you for reminding me about the nonuniform sampling behavior of the `NDSolve` or it will make me suffer!

Comment: @kglr, thank you for reminding me, I am not very familiar about this excellent forum, I'll try my best!

Comment: Side note: now there's a [`ResourceFunction["IrregularPeriodogram"]`](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/IrregularPeriodogram) in Wolfram function repository.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem the OP outlines is to get ***accurate*** discrete sample values of the solution (on a uniform grid).  The OP is correct that there is error in the discretization by `NDSolve` (truncation error) and in interpolation (though perhaps not "severe").  The question is whether we can avoid the interpolation error. (1) Just taking the `"ValuesOnGrid"` either from the interpolating function constructed by `NDSolve` or by using `EvaluationMonitor` will get the values of the solution on the grid constructed by `NDSolve`, which will not be uniform unless a fixed-step method is employed.  (2) Using `Table` to get the values on a regular grid from the solution will introduce interpolation error.

One way to get accurate, regular steps over an interval is to use [`` NDSolve`Iterate[] ``](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolveStateData.html) and its helpers.  (See also [`Subdivide`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Subdivide.html) for subdividing an interval into a specified number of steps.)  The code below creates steps at specified regular intervals.  (`NDSolve` will create others, but they are not used.)

```
ivp = {y'[x] == y[x] Cos[x + y[x]], y[0] == 1};
{state} = NDSolve`ProcessEquations[ivp, y, {x, 0, 30}];           (* initialize NDSolve *)
samples = 512;                                                    (* number of steps)
Do[NDSolve`Iterate[state, x], {x, Subdivide[0., 30., samples]}];  (* make steps *)
sol = NDSolve`ProcessSolutions[state];                            (* get solution *)
yvalues = Table[y[x] /. sol, {x, Subdivide[0., 30., samples]}];   (* get values at steps *)
Fourier[yvalues]
(* etc. *)
```

The other way, to use a fixed-step method and use `if["ValuesOnGrid"]` for the input to `Fourier[]`, is also possible, although it can be difficult to get an error estimate to verify that the `NDSolve[]` solution is accurate.  One could solve the system with a high `WorkingPrecision` and use that as a reference for the exact solution (but that's more than double the work).  In any case, let's say you want `137` sample values (or `136` steps).  But it turns out that you need at least ~250 steps to get a result accurate to machine precision.  So we double the number of steps and downsample the `NDSolve[]` result:

```
ivp = {y'[x] == y[x] Cos[x + y[x]], y[0] == 1};
steps = 136;  (* desired number *)
{solIMP} = 
  NDSolve[ivp, y, {x, 0, 30}, 
   Method -> {"FixedStep", 
     Method -> {"ImplicitRungeKutta", "DifferenceOrder" -> 15, 
       "ImplicitSolver" -> {"Newton", 
         AccuracyGoal -> MachinePrecision, 
         PrecisionGoal -> MachinePrecision, 
         "IterationSafetyFactor" -> 1}}}, 
   StartingStepSize -> (30 - 0)/(2*steps)];          (* double the number of steps *)
fvalues = (y["ValuesOnGrid"] /. solIMP)[[;; ;; 2]];  (* downsample *)
Fourier[fvalues]
```

You can check that `Length[fvalues]` is `137`.

Comment: Thanks, it's very helpful.

Comment: @Bettertomo I was adding some explanation while you upvoted & commented (thanks!).  I think my interpretation of what you needed was slightly different than the others.

Comment: Thanks for your summary !

Answer (score 6):

Since you don't give any particular differential equation, I am using the 1st one from ref/NDSolve > Basic Examples.

```
xyPairs = {};
NDSolve[{y'[x] == y[x] Cos[x + y[x]], y[0] == 1}, y, {x, 0, 30},
  EvaluationMonitor :> (xyPairs = Join[xyPairs, {{x, y[x]}}])];
ListPlot[xyPairs]
```

plot[image]

Comment: Thanks, I think your method is great. But I fail to suit it into my problem for a simple reason: I can't suit  $xyPairs = Join[xyPairs, {{x, y[x]}}]$ into my problem...

Comment: I don't know how to express y[x] in your example when I'm dealing my problem, i.e. I don't know the specific way to suit $Evaluate[Rho[tf[t0[[j + 1]]]] /. s]$ in your method, I have give out my case in the question.

Comment: A nice additional trick is to use `{x,30,30}` for the x-range in these cases: `NDSolve` it will then only return a result for the endpoint in the form of a (degenerate) interpolating function, which might be much faster and need less memory then building the full interpolating function. As it has to solve for the whole x-range you will still get the same data in `xyPairs`. The effect is probably neglectable for a single ode but can be quite relevant for a larger system of odes or pdes...

Comment: It's a good way and I will try it . But I still think your first method is really great, so can you help me about it?

Comment: I'm not just curious about it. I just find a severe problem of my program, it's for calculation of absorption spectrum of a two level system. The correction of it will need the first method!

Answer (score 4):

Another way is to use `Table`

```
ode = y'[x] == y[x] Cos[x + y[x]];

sol = NDSolve[{ode, y[0] == 1}, {y}, {x, 0, 30}];

xy = Table[{x, y[x]} /. First@sol, {x, 0, 30, 2}];

% // TableForm
```

[image]

```
ListPlot[xy, PlotRange -> All];
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I know your method is great, but I just can't suit it into my problem cause I know too little about mathematica. I don't know how to express y[x] in your example when I'm dealing my problem, I have give out my case in the question.

Comment: @Bettertomo Your code doesn't work.

Comment: Yes, I fail to find a good simplification, so it just can show what I'm dealing with. The different with the original code is the Matrix H.

Answer (score 4):

Using the same example as in @m_goldberg's and @zhk's answers:

```
iF = NDSolve[{y'[x] == y[x] Cos[x + y[x]], y[0] == 1}, y, {x, 0, 30}][[1, 1, 2]];

ListPlot @ iF["ValuesOnGrid"]
```

[image]

**See also:** [R.M.'s answer to What's inside InterpolatingFunction[{{1., 4.}}, <>]?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/28341/125)

Comment: Thank you very much, I've made it!

Comment: @Bettertomo, my pleasure. If you haven't already, please consider to check the links in the welcome comment below your post.

Answer (score 4):

A lot of the answers here are reaching into the InterpolatingFunction, to get at the raw output of NDSolve.  There are certainly times where that is useful -- but this does not seem to be one of them.  I think the original problem of the poster has to do with syntax in NDSolve.  In particular, how to deal with vectors.

Here is a stripped down version of the problem in the original post:

```
H = {{1, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 2, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 3, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 4}};
eqns = D[rho[t], t] == H.rho[t]
boundary = rho[0] == {1, 0, 0, 0}
sol = NDSolve[{eqns, boundary}, rho, {t, 0, 1}]
```

To get discrete points, one would write

```
discrete = Table[{t, #} & /@ (rho[t] /. sol[[1]]), {t, 0, 1, 0.1}]
ListPlot[Transpose@discrete, PlotRange -> All]
```

Alternatively, he/she could use spectral methods (solving the ODE in Fourier space).

Comment: Thanks, my original problem is trying to avoid the process "raw discrete data in `NDsolve` $\rightarrow$ interpolation function from `NDsolve` $\rightarrow$ discrete to suit `Fourier`". My problem and target change with my knowledge about mathematica in the past ten hours thanks for help from people like you.

Comment: How to deal with vectors is actually my another problems!